# Is there a sandbox page to test Stack Overflow features?

Tags: support, sandbox

I wonder if there exists a sandbox page on Stack Overflow where one can test the formatting syntax in posts (Q/A) and comments?

Answer (score 23):

Using a Google search, I found out that question on SE, that is dedicated to be a sandbox page:
[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

I think that page should be linked in the UI of the web site, or at least in the help center.

Comment: I didn't realize that it wasn't. Looking into that, because I'm certain that it _used_ to be.

Comment: @TimPost The query [links:meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox](http://www.google.com/search?q=links%3Ameta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F3122%2Fformatting-sandbox) in Google seems to only return other questions (that have comments pointing to the sandbox page).

Comment: @TimPost it was in the faq.