# Is there a better name for Stack Snippets?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

You'll all be aware of the following posts no doubt:

- [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)
- [Stack Snippets Sandbox - Try It Out Here!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here)

I'm not a massive fan of the name if I'm honest. To me it just doesn't have the same ring to it as **JSFiddle/fiddle** when used on SO. For example:

- take a look at my JSFiddle
- here's a demo fiddle
- plz create a JSFiddle with the codez
- let me fiddle it

Now replace the terms with **stack snippets** and perhaps you might agree it's not as catchy.

### Could we do better?

I'm not assuming in any way that any suggestions will be taken on board and used, but what the fiddle.

My lame suggestions to be used in the previous examples:

- StackHack (or Hack for short)
- SOHack (pronounced S-O-Hack)
- stHack (pronounced stack, like it but could confuse)
- SOFiddle (too close to JSFiddle perhaps)
- OverFiddle (ditto)
- OverHack
- MinifHack (ha, sounds like a curse, love it)

Not entirely sure about using *Over* in the name as we're after minimal complete code samples, hence the minify themed one.

I'm not suggesting that my ideas are any better, but you guys might come up with something, so please answer with your suggestions or just down vote if you like it as it is.

If you like any of my suggestions, please state which one with a simple short comment so others can use it to vote. Please do the same on any answers that post multiple suggestions so we can see the people's choice.

Comment: I recommend **stack.it** Example: "what have you tried? stack.it please!"

Comment: @iStimple like it, perhaps add it as an answer to allow voting as an answer and make it more visible

Comment: @iStimple: I like it, but would it be clear what it means to a beginner? (is there a possibility of a quick-link?)

Comment: I'm assuming it would be covered in the tour and the button would still say "run code snippets", it's just a code name of sorts I guess, unless they're going to change the button in the future.

Comment: Stack Snacks. Flippets. Fuddles. Tinkers. Twiddles.

Comment: @iStimple, yes please add as an answer!

Comment: jsFiddle could do with a better name than buzzing one out

Comment: Why would you even use the term "stack snippet" when talking about them in the context of a SO question? The simplest, most obvious choice is simply using the word "snippet" or "code snippet" or maybe "runnable snippet" - without any reference to the "stack" part. Any other term you could use for such a snippet would only obfuscate the meaning.

Comment: "Stack Snippet" sounds like it's part of a stack. I know I'm reading "stack" too literally, but that's the first thing that came to mind when I saw the name. The name didn't tell me that it was a piece of code until I read the explanation. I would have guessed that it was a stack trace, or something like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see any reason. Snippet makes a lot of sense as a name. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_(programming)):

> Snippet is a programming term for a small region of re-usable source
>   code, machine code, or text.

The point is - a snippet is a small piece of code **that works on its own** and can be easily **copied and reused**. And that's the entire idea of the SO snippets - that you can run them in the answer and see it in action.

That's different from JSFiddle, which is more about *sharing* your code with other people (either because you need their help debugging it, or you want to create a playground for some library or whatever). Think about it this way - when you share a snippet in the answer, the OP can copy and paste the code - but that's about it. When you share a fiddle, he can also edit the code and extend it even more. Each method achieves something a little different.

So no, there's no reason to rename the "snippets" to "fiddles" or anything similar - both because it isn't the same as jsfiddle and also because the name makes sense on its own (we don't need to invent our own name either, so "stack.it" is also out the window, even though it would make for some hilarious comments).

And all that's without mentioning the ensuing unnecessary confusion about such a change happening a short time after the feature has been introduced.