# Should it be more obvious that stack snippets are only meant for HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-snippets

Sometimes I see questions like [one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27070826/1), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26766830/1) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26786404/4) where a user unfamiliar with stack snippets pastes their C or C++ code into the stack snippet box. Now admittedly this doesn't happen very often, but it seems to indicate that they are confusing "Code Samples" with "Code Snippets". I've taken a look at [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused) but the issue being addressed is a form of JavaScript not runnable in the browser. [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271649/3920237)'s response says:

> There are probably things we can do to improve the guidance here, and
>   I expect they'll become more obvious as more people find and use it.
>   We're open to all suggestions.
>
> That said... This isn't the end of the world. In fact,
>   properly-formatted code with a useless "run" button on it may be an
>   *improvement* over the status quo in cases where folks were previously struggling to format their code properly. Particularly for HTML, which
>   could result in a big chunk of a post that wasn't even *visible* if
>   the author forgot to indent it.

This doesn't seem to address the OP's main inquiry:

> Is there anything that can be done to teach users when to use
>   stack-snippets? ...

...which I think is the root of the problem.

The users in the initial linked questions seem to be brute-forcing their way by pasting their code dump into the first box they see. Currently, AFAIK, there is nothing that covers stack snippets in the markdown help or the help center.

I like [Gas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274349/3920237)' suggestion:

> Could the tooltip of the `Code snippet` be extended to something like
>   `Code snippet - only for JavaScript and Html` or `Code snippet - only
>   for browser runnable code`?   As users put everything there Java, C++,
>   even SQL queries... Such tooltip would prevent at least some of this
>   rubbish.

A [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I like is [Replace code snippets by normal code block if JavaScript tag is absent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent) in which [assylias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent) proposes:

> Some users (probably mostly new users) tend to use the "code snippet"
>   tool for code in languages that aren't supported by Stack Snippets.
>
> Would it not make sense to disable the code snippets if the
>   [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), or [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tags are not present in the
>   question or at least show a warning?
>
> > You have used the "code snippet" feature which is supposed to be used for HTML/CSS/JavaScript only. Should this be replaced with a
> >     normal code block?
> >
> > Yes/No

...but the comments seem to indicate that this solution is not so clear-cut.  Two flaws I see: 1) disabling the feature is not very good UX and 2) the question asker may mistag the question.

I'm not familiar with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) questions but [BradleyDotNET](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent#comment116133_276409)'s comment seems to suggest that this is a widespread problem:

> Yes! Please just don't allow it; way too many "Runnable" C# snippets
>   that just add noise to the code block.

### Call to action

There are a couple of reasons why this isn't a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

- Editing the comments out which make it a stack snippet take literally 2 seconds.
- There's a possibility it isn't a widespread problem and people are complaining about a hypothetical/strawman.

If people agree that this is something that needs to be solved sometime in the near future, then please improve the tool-tips or add help to the markdown help (since this is what is brought up when you click on the question mark.)

In the meanwhile, [Tanner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277747/3920237) has provided an excellent SEDE query which provides a rough estimate for questions tagged incorrectly using stack snippets. Please go through and see if the questions need to be edited. Please make sure that your edits are substantial or otherwise improve the question as well. The base query is <kbd>[`here`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/250240/usage-of-stack-snippets-in-incorrect-tags-examples)</kbd>.

You can modify it to show only questions for your tag, i.e.,

```
SELECT Id as [Post Link], Tags
FROM #tmp
WHERE tags like('%c++%')
```

### Related discussion

Previous [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s:

- Add documentation to the help center. [Add information on Stack Snippets to Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277340/add-information-on-stack-snippets-to-help-center)
- Disable code snippet feature based on tags, or convert it to a code block. [Replace code snippets by normal code block if JavaScript tag is absent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276409/replace-code-snippets-by-normal-code-block-if-javascript-tag-is-absent)
- Allow code snippets to format code (this assumes that [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused)). [Code Snippet as a formatting tool](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274636/code-snippet-as-a-formatting-tool)

Comment: lol; Thanks for including a previous comment of mine (I was about to repost :) ). Yes, please implement this! Side note; this has seemed to be a bit better as of late (in C#), perhaps people actually *are* learning

Comment: It was a pretty good question quality indicator, didn't last that long.

Comment: Saw this happening also in Python tag, can't recall where was it though.

Comment: @BartoszKP I was hoping for more proof rather than anecdote. Having to wait for someone to come up with a SEDE data.

Comment: See [Clean up editing button tooltips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243002/clean-up-editing-button-tooltips) where I mention the problem with the snippet tooltip also.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen this a few times in the `java` tag as well. It's fairly harmless, but increases the noise in a question. It's easy to edit out, though, which is what I do. Would definitely like to see something, probably just a confirmation with the user.

Comment: Just as an aside, I was answering an Excel question the other day and in the comments asked the OP to provide sample data in a table and he edited the question to include a snippet with a HTML table which was actually pretty useful. I considered editing it out for an ASCII table because it seemed wrong but left it it in the end

Comment: Why can't we search for `begin snippet`? (I mean, of course we *can* -- but it does not list posts containing Stack Snippets.)

Comment: @Jongware `<!-- begin snippet:` or `<!-- end snippet -->` or what have you, I've tried all variations and sucking at T-SQL I can't get a proper query. What I meant was, a field in the data schema that specifically says "this post has a stack snippet in it".

Comment: Got it. I tried `begin snippet` only, but this must be related to that weird featurebug/bugfeature of SO's search box, where text tied to punctuation cannot  be found.

Comment: @Jongware It would be a great incentive for a bounty. But google and SO's search seem to be equally useless.

Comment: 'it seems to indicate that they are confusing "Code Samples" with "Code Snippets"' - what's the difference? Aren’t they the same thing :o

Comment: @jww No, "Code Samples" is what you get when you hover over the code formatting button (CTRL+K). "Code Snippets" is what you get when you hover over the stack snippets button.

Comment: Also note it's not for all JS questions, e.g. For [jQuery Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/info) it's useless to have code snippet. I usually remove them when added to questions/answers.

Comment: @Omar Yeah, that's covered in [Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused). In particular, the question asker is talking about CasperJS. The answers don't really address the issue of external javascript libraries though.

Comment: Perhaps the option to insert a snippet could be disabled if relevant tags are not used? This could be a rather large task though as you would need to include Javascript frameworks, Bootstrap etc.

Comment: @DavidG If a question doesn't have a master language tag, and is only tagged [tag:twitter-bootstrap] or something, I would most likely edit in [tag:html] or [tag:css] although I can't speak for others. I might reconsider the idea of disabling the feature as it doesn't prevent them from submitting the question. They can't abuse a feature they don't know about.

Comment: @remyabel Maybe a warning message would be more appropriate? It could nudge people to add in [tag:HTML]/[tag:CSS]/whatever when only specifying [tag:twitter-bootstrap]. Thinking about it, I find many questions tagged with [tag:twitter-bootstrap] are really only CSS of JS issues.

Answer (score 26):

I've managed to create a data explorer query, which I believe shows **questions** with stack snippets included based on the body containing: `'%div class="snippet"%'`, which is the markup used to surround a stack snippet. I've then filtered the results to those in appropriate and inappropriate tags.

<kbd>[Data Explorer Query: Usage of Stack Snippets in Correct Tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/250232/usage-of-stack-snippets-in-correct-tags)</kbd>

**Results Show: (Updated July 2015)**

```
TotalSnippets | TotalSnippetsInTags | TotalSnippetsBadTags
----------------------------------------------------------
        20926 |               14545 |                 6381
```

Based on these figures, 30% of stack snippets added to the site are not using the correct tags, based on the filters I've selected below. This is only looking at **questions**, I'm sure there are many other cases where **answers** are doing the same.

Here's a data explorer query showing the posts that my query identifies as using snippets without the correct tags:

<kbd>[Usage of Stack Snippets in Incorrect Tags (Examples)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/250240/usage-of-stack-snippets-in-incorrect-tags-examples)</kbd>

**Filters Used:**

- `CreationDate > '2014-06-01'` as stack snippets are relatively new
- `Body LIKE('%div class="snippet"%')`

**Correct Tag Usage:**

```html
WHERE tags like('%javascript%') or 
      tags like('%html%') or 
      tags like('%css%') or
      tags like('%js%') or <!-- cover things like angularjs, knockout.js etc -->
      tags like('%jquery%')
```

**Incorrect Tag Usage:**

```html
WHERE tags not like('%javascript%') and 
      tags not like('%html%') and 
      tags not like('%css%') and
      tags not like('%js%') and 
      tags not like('%jquery%')
```

<sup>Sorry, couldn't resist using stack snippets incorrectly!</sup>

Comment: Even with the correct tags of [Javascript], [HTML], [CSS] etc.. there is this problem of users confusing a *"Stack Snippet"* with a *"Code Sample"*! And there are many. So while this does give a good picture for *incorrect tags*, but not so much for *incorrect usage* within the *correct tags* which is an equally big problem. But that's not what the question is for... so, just sayin'.

Comment: Can you modify the query to add post links for easy clicking? If there really aren't that many offending questions, it should be relatively easy to clean up.

Comment: @remyabel I've already edited the second query to add the links to questions if you reload it

Comment: @abhitalks I see what you're saying, I was just looking to provide high level figures.

Comment: @Tanner I think given the context of this question, [your question about the naming](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270131/is-there-a-better-name-for-stack-snippets) might have a lot more merit.

Comment: @gitsitgo I think that ship has sailed and the name is here to stay. I've gotten used to it now :-)

Comment: @Tanner =/ yeah I guess I'm still stuck at the harbour, but I'll catch up.