# Hidden Stack Snippets gets the code formatting when inserted next to code

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

If you insert a stack snippet next to a code block, it gets the formatting of code.

Example:

```
font-family: tahoma, verdana, ubuntu, 'sans serif';

* {
  font-family: tahoma, verdana, ubuntu, 'sans serif';
}
<p>
  Unicorns I love them.
  <br />Unicorns I love them.
  <br />Unicorns I love them.
  <br />Unicorns I love them.
  <br />Uni uni unicorns, I love them!
</p>
```

In edit mode, this is somewhat different, but still formatting is screwed:

> [image]

This is probably because the `begin snippet` is in the same line as the preceding code block:

```
font-family: tahoma, verdana, ubuntu, 'sans serif';<!-- begin snippet: ...
```

But inserting the `begin snippet` to the same line is done by the snippet editor, not the user.

---

Here is the bug [misterManSam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) describes in the comments:

> [image]

Comment: Yeah, we should be smarter about where the snippet is inserted, since Markdown parsing requires a blank line between different "blocks" to be styled correctly.

Comment: @AnnaLear's right. Let me see what I can cook up for this.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Also, if you add a Stack Snippet to your post that has a link, the closing snippet tag is lined up with the `[1]:Link` and screws up the formatting. Looks like this: `<!-- end snippet -->  [1]: link`

Comment: Holy stack, snipception!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I've corrected the Markdown insertion of Stack Snippets so that they will be properly inserted as their own block (separated by white space above and below). This will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.26.2606`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.26.1893`).