# Code Snippet execution window returns Server Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I discovered that executing the code snippet in [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27492540/1812515) displays an error page.
[image: Snippet Error]

I get the same results in IE10, Chrome, and Chrome Canary. I also tried this in Meta StackOverflow on the [code snippet sandbox page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269844/1812515) with the same results. Is this isolated to my computer or are others experiencing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Are you on a proxy?

Comment: Check that you aren't running some kind of blocking software (such as AdBlock). If you are, make an exception for http://stacksnippets.net - also, can you navigate to that page?

Comment: I'm not running any ad blocking software. stacksnippets.net returns the same "500" error page. I am on a work network, so perhaps the page is being blocked, but I've never had problems before.

Comment: Confirmed that this is isolated to my laptop. My phone renders the stacksnippets page without error. Hopefully a reboot will solve the issue.

Comment: http://stacksnippets.net/ gives a "500 Internal server error" for me (Chrome, IE) too, as well as the snippet in the linked answer.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue.  However, it cannot be isolated to your laptop... it's a server error.  It might be isolated to certain regions or ISPs though... not sure.

Comment: And it just cleared up.  Apparently something is flaking out on SO.

Comment: And it came back.  lol... I cannot believe nobody else is seeing it.

Comment: same error for me

Comment: Got the error here as well.

Comment: Wondering if there are multiple stacksnippet servers and only one has a problem. I get errors when I hit 198.252.206.148

Comment: @Haney: Is this getting fixed/being looked into? Presently it's making css quesions pretty difficult?

Comment: @jbutler483 the site ran fine for a few years before snippets were introduced.

Comment: I get this error on all the code snippets. I think there is a problem with the service globally? Try it out here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: @CodeCaster: SO, they were introduced because?... I'm not saying it's 'impossible' to answer the questions, it's just meaning a load of extra work to answer them!

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I've never had the problem before. The 500 Internal Server error is being thrown on http://stacksnippets.net.

Comment: confirming the problem exists right now.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this for ALL snippets and stacksnippets.net. How do we find out if anyone is looking in to it?

Comment: Also broken for me. No adblocker.

Comment: Now it's working for me, but obviously this is still an issue for others. I have to wonder if this has something to do with SO's huge data-center upgrade.

Comment: Still breaking for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26519365/402706

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about this folks. We're doing some server upgrades this week (see: [#SnowOps](http://www.twitter.com/#SnowOps) hashtag on Twitter) and we're pretty sure we accidentally took down the Stack Snippets server temporarily. The odd part is that, while we *had* monitoring on it, nothing was fired or triggered so we didn't know it was down. It *should* be back now, and you'd guess correctly if your assumption is that I'm double checking the error monitoring on it now. ;)

Sorry again!

Comment: Still down. Caching?

Comment: @ShadowWizard checking it out. Can't catch it in the act, as it were.

Comment: This should return to normal rather soon. @NickCraver is working his magic as we speak.

Comment: When Nick is around, no bug can hide! ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard especially when they're related to server work. :) Should be all set now.

Comment: True, works like magic for me. :-)