# Code snippets don't seem to work for me

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

In an example there is a question

[Return value from last ajax request in ajax chain, that is inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108767/return-value-from-last-ajax-request-in-ajax-chain-that-is-inside-for-loop)

with a code snippet but when I click to run there is only blank box and nothing else to see and this seems to happen all the time for me

Comment: Oh :'(. Is there another one I can look at to see if it works on other ones please :)?

Comment: They do work! Thank you! :`DDDDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that particular code snippet is broken beyond repair. It doesn't look like the OP fully understood what a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) meant, although their code relies on jQuery and fetching of data so it might be a bit more difficult to get that running.

Leaving syntax errors in the code is never a good idea though and warrants down votes to signal to the OP that their post needs attention.

You can diagnose yourself if a snippet runs without errors by opening the Developer Console in your browser. Any errors raised by the StackSnippet show up there.

Visit the [StackSnippet Sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) to find some nice working examples of Snippets.

Comment: Ok :/. I will look and maybe post some code I think