# What is the limit of size to JavaScript and CSS files included in a Stack Snippet?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

While asking questions we can link to external CSS and JavaScript plugins or scripts using the Stack Snippet feature. What is the size limit for this? Could I link to a 100 GB file?

Comment: Why would you want to attach a 100GB file?

Comment: @Tunaki Not me. I am afraid if I open a question on stakoverflow where someone has a huge plugin attached and then I  `Run code snippet` and then browser start download a large file.

Comment: So you want to know if the Stack Snippet is checking the size of the external libraries people add?

Comment: @BSMP Exactly. I want to know if it has a limit for that. E.g. can I not add an external js file greater than 2MB in size?

Comment: I supposed you could [try it out in the sandbox](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) if you have a file large enough to test with.

Comment: Even with a size limit, there are still possibilities for malicious code snippets that try to eat up your bandwidth. I suppose that SO relies on user votes to sniff those out.

Comment: A large file of 200K would download in a second or two, what's the problem again?

Comment: Note that you can see all the external libraries in a snippet in the HTML section (and they'd be at the top unless they manually add that line to the code). You can always choose not to run a snippet with external files you don't recognize if you're really worried about someone linking to something 100GB. Common libraries coming from CDNs should be safe.

Answer (score 2):

Stack snippets don't handle the download of external resources. Stack snippets are just HTML, CSS and JS which run inside a sandboxed iframe, so they can't send forms, use AJAX and things like that.

However, they can use a `<script>` or `<video>` or some element which loads an external resource. This is handled by the browser, not by the stack snippet.

If you want to avoid huge downloads, you will need to configure your browser as such. You might be able to set a policy only for the stacksnippets.net domain.

Comment: Thanks. So I take it as that there is no limit to size of external sources.