# Need beautify button for this Stack Overflow site

Tags: discussion

This site needs a beautify button when asking a question.

When new programmers don't have properly indented code when asking their questions, people trash their indenting instead of answering their question. It's very difficult and time consuming to correctly indent software using the provided HTML GUI. If there was a beautify button, it would save them a lot of time. It would have to work in JavaScript and follow the "insert code" guidelines.

Comment: Copy-pasting the code into a snippet and hitting the “Tidy” button doesn’t seem very time-consuming to me. You do know about stack snippets, don’t you?

Comment: Push the "Ask a Question" button and show me the "Tidy" button.

Comment: Auto-indenters get complicated really fast, because every language has its own small differences that can make indenting in that language completely different or even buggy if it's just based on default rules. You're talking about essentially having a second Prettify script running on the site at all times, just for indenting instead of syntax highlighting. Even then, languages that can't be detected will still go back to default which will probably break quite a few languages and not be helpful at all.

Comment: [It’s right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apUhI.png).

Comment: [Stack Snippets Sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) - You can try it out here. You have to actually create a snippet to get the Tidy option, it's not on question toolbar directly.

Comment: Using a prettifier on a question where the problem may be incorrect use of syntax, thus potentially obscuring the source of the problem, sounds ike a bad idea.

Comment: I used to have an extension installed that did this pretty well. Got rid of it because i rarely used it.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of "people trash their indenting instead of answering their question."? It is trivial to edit correct MCVE to have reasonable indents... so we may need to educate those commenters on being nicer...

Answer (score 9):

Ideally if you're asking a question about some code, you should not be typing the code into the question to begin with.

You should write the code in your own text editor/IDE, run it on your system and make sure it's doing exactly what you're going to say it does in the question, and then copy *the exact code you are running on your system* from your own editor/IDE (which most likely has the code formatting feature you're asking about) and paste it into the question. At that point, the only thing you might need to do in the question editor is highlight the code you pasted and click the "Code Sample" button (or press Ctrl+K).

If you have too much code to copy/paste into the question, remove irrelevant parts of it until you're left with a smaller code sample that still produces the behavior you want to ask about. Run it one last time right before you copy/paste it to make sure it still does the thing.

This will handle the formatting issue, and also prevent the problem we see in many cases where someone's question can't be answered because their actual problem got lost in translation.

Answer (score 0):

> It's very difficult and time consuming to correctly indent software using the provided HTML GUI.

Don't do this. Select the code in your editor/IDE, tab it once to the right, copy it to your clipboard, undo your change in your editor, and then you'll have something that can be pasted verbatim into a Stack Overflow post.

The Markdown system will pre-format it from there.

Comment: Except that you have to format it as code by adding another indention to it.

Comment: Not sure I understand you @Nicol. One level of indentation to activate Markdown code formatting is not reflected in the code presentation, which remains without indentation. Since I expect you know that, can you re-express what you're saying?

Comment: If all you're doing in the IDE is adding four spaces to every line then you can just do that in the post textbox here by highlighting the code and pressing CTRL+K. What OP is talking about is proper indentation, e.g. elements or function bodies need to be indented from the previous element or the function call, etc.

Comment: @TylerH, ah, do they mean if it is not correctly indented in their own files in the first place? If so, that's not our job to fix, IMO - we'd be encouraging the presentation of code that is different from what they're actually running.

Comment: @halfer that's my guess. Or they are just typing it into the post manually \*shudders\*. And I agree