# Is it possible to search for stack snippets?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, stack-snippets

I want to find all stack snippets for a given language/technology.

Is there a way to query for this?

Comment: If you want to see "cool" things done with Stack Snippets, check out [the Stack Snippets Sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/215552)...

Comment: Language?  Snippets are css/html/javascript.  What languages are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

It seems impossible with the top search bar.

However, you can search for snippets with the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com), using simple pattern matching.

For example, this query finds all answers with a js snippet:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], *
FROM Posts
WHERE
  CreationDate > '2019-01-01'
  AND
  LOWER(Body) LIKE LOWER('%snippet: js%')
```

Some other narrowing of the query is needed, because SEDE is too slow to handle pattern search in all the question bodies. This example query filters for Posts created after 2019-01-01.

Comment: doing a lower on both sides of the expression is pretty expensive. Consider using `Body LIKE '%snippet: js%' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`

Comment: @rene Thanks, it is very useful! Although my experience is that the real bottleneck is that `LIKE` is ... slow.

Comment: Yeah, it needs to do a table scan. I expect using collate will reduce memory pressure  bit. It doesn't reduce the I/O calls which is probably the bulk of the processing. For these type of queries a full text index would be beneficial. On MSE there are FR's for that but given how SEDE is updated adding full text indexes is not feasible. So your approach with limiting the numbers of rows to search is the only one that can work on SEDE

Comment: @rene Utf8 regexp matching is much slower also on Linux, although it shouldn't be so. The DB here is in utf8, but the overwhelming majority of the content is 7-bit ascii, that can make the pattern match maybe much faster.

Comment: It seems like a site about code should spend some time making a code friendly search option.

Comment: @gman They use elasticsearch on the backend, it is very flexible and surely they could do that quite easily. I think if you, as a 80k+ SO user, ask for this on the MSO or on the MSE, you will get above average community support (other question, what the company will do).