# SO markdown editor

Tags: support, editor

Is there somewhere to practise using SO's markdown editor privately, i.e, without putting the result on public view?  The reason I ask is that I sometimes run into layout problems which atm I have to fix by trial and error, and I'd prefer not to do this on a live question or answer.

Comment: Doesn't the preview work properly for your posts?

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer trying things out on something that won't end up as a post.  That's why I was asking about privately ...

Comment: You can mess around [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) or [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here)

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Thanks, I'll give them a try.

Comment: Check [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/editor), docs are saved in the local browser storage

Comment: you can also check https://dillinger.io/