# How do I include code for JSFiddle?

Tags: support, jsfiddle

I tried to submit a post with a link to code on JSFiddle.com and it says:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code...For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

[image]

I didn't see anything about it so I followed the [advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link and did not see anything about it there either. How do I make a link to JSFiddle so Stack Overflow allows me to post?

Comment: when i am including fiddles, I am just copy-pasting the `html` , `Js` code to  answer box in SO

Comment: ok so it can be any code? i thought there was something new on stack overflow that lets you run html code inline. i thought that's what it was referring to. that's what i don't know how to do. if it just wants any code then i can post part or all of the code from the fiddle.

Comment: yes.. it can be that one line of code which gives the answer to that question (or if you want you can write all the code) and for full demo users need to open the link

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow *must* be self-contained. While you can *also* have code on JSFiddle, or another site, the code needed for the question *must* be *in the question itself*. If the question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, you should consider using a [snippet](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not want you to just post a JSFiddle link: you need to put your code in your question too.

I recommend using [the built-in Code Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) rather than JSFiddle because users don't have to navigate away to see the result of your code.

You can create a built in Code Snippet by pressing the Code Snippet button [image] when creating your post.  You can also play around and test them [in the sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here).

Here's what it looks like when you embed the code inline:

```js
alert("You can even do alerts");
```

```css
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">Stack Snippets allow you to make code runnable.</div>
```

---

Alternatively, paste in your code, select all of it, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to format it properly. For example:

```
print('this is what code looks like with formatting')
print(1+2)
print('this looks much better than normal formatting')
```

Then you are allowed to link to it.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/h88sunkv/1/

Comment: Also, I recommend using the built-in Code Snippets rather than JSFiddle because users don't have to navigate away to see the result of your code.

Comment: What if my code does not work on built in Code Snipets??

Comment: Great idea with the code snippet in the post. Unfortunately it is not as powerful as jsfiddle :( For example this fiddle did not work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/pauloco/qhjdwzr5/17/ any ideas why? The console threw an error which I couldn't understand: {
  "message": "SecurityError: The operation is insecure.",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 181,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: When creating a snippet for a front-end framework like `angularjs`, you often need to include lots of boilerplate code for a working example that is not actually necessary for readers to understand your question. Can you select a specific section in the code to preview for readers before they actually open the entire snippet? And perhaps highlight and focus a section of code in the opened snippet?