# Handle infinite loops, etc. in runnable code snippets

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

While putting together a JavaScript example for a question in the snippet editor, I made a programming error that caused the page to become unresponsive. (I think I had an event that just kept firing.) The only option I was given was to close the page. (In Chrome on Mac, if that matters.) Doing so lost about a half hour of work. Is it feasible to put an auto-save, crash detection, or some other mechanism in the editor?

(For now I'm going to use CodePen and paste the results in.)

To clarify, I'm not asking Stack Overflow to solve [the halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). ;) Say the editor displayed a GUID URL with a suggestion of bookmarking that. Even if it only kept the data for a few hours, this would avoid losses. Alternately Stack Overflow could remember that user X was editing a snippet; when X returned to the site and the snippet wasn't pasted, the site could offer to restore it.

Comment: 'For now I'm going to use CodePen and paste the results in' - do that more often.

Comment: Anyway, unresponsive scripts are hardly a problem specific to SO;(

Comment: @MartinJames Yes; however I thought part of the idea of snippets was to eliminate the need to use CodePen, JSFiddle, JS Bin, Plunker, etc. to compose a question. If snippets could preserve state then the other tools wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Seriously, there should be a execution time cap (reasonably high to allow for programs containing timers).

Comment: In my experience the editor *does* auto-save… or is that just the answer editor and not the question editor?

Comment: As for actually handling infinite loops, there aren't many options available in current browsers. Only web workers let the code run without stalling the browser (which also allows things like execution timeouts), and from a web worker you can't interact with the DOM, so it isn't really viable. The only other option I'm aware of is to modify the code before running it to add escape hatches at every branch, which is obviously super complicated.

Comment: @dave if you compose a snippet, you compose it in a separate editor, and that editor only inserts the snippet into the main body when you press exit & save

Comment: Feature Request: Solve the Halting Problem, time frame: 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Firefox pops up a window saying "This script is unresponsive. Do you want to terminate it?"

Comment: Why not just auto-save the snippet to localStorage or indexed DB - whenever possible? I suppose the snippet is not going to take up a lot of space in storage.

Answer (score 10):

Codepen solved this problem (for some definition of solved) by parsing the JavaScript and inserting code into loops to break out of them.

https://codepen.io/quezo/post/improving-infinite-loop-detection

https://blog.codepen.io/2014/12/16/infinite-loop-protection-round-two/

Another solution might be to save the code somewhere (local storage, server) on each click of "run" so that if you come back to the page after killing your frozen tab you get your code back. It might even be nice if SO put up a helpful "You have an unsaved Q or A, click to edit" that would take you back to your Q or A with your edits. JSFiddle has some form of this. Something like "Your fiddle has an unsaved draft".

[image]

NOTE: that I just testing SO by clicking "post your answer", starting a snippet, typing `for(;;) {}` and running it, checking the tab froze, killing the tab, coming back to this question and clicking "post your answer" again and verified that SO just loses the snippet.

also verified that putting an infinite loop into JSFiddle, running, killing the tab, and the coming back gets my infinite loop code back.

Comment: Link to the article is fine, but the article contains a link to *another* article about how they actually *did* it, and that link is broken. [Here's the correct one](https://codepen.io/quezo/post/improving-infinite-loop-detection).

Answer (score 5):

Quoting [my comment from 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here#comment84765_269767), from [Stack Snippets Sandbox - Try It Out Here!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/7586):

> JS Bin does have some protection from infinite loops and bad performance in general: [Protecting you from yourself](http://jsbin.com/blog/protection) , including an open source loop protection module: [GitHub - jsbin/loop-protect](http://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect)
>    .
>   It's easy to say "halting problem" and give up, but it turns out there is a lot you can do to help your users.

For example, this code:

```
for(var i=0;i<100000;i++)
{
    console.log(1);
}
```

Gived the following output on the browser console:

> Exiting potential infinite loop at line 1. To disable loop protection: add "// noprotect" to your code

Working example: http://jsbin.com/tihewikuwe/1/edit?js,console

I still think using one of these libraries is a good idea.