# Snippet no more working for downvoted posts

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets

I discovered something strange but probably intentional. When a post that includes a working snippet gets 3 downvotes, the button to run the snippet or to copy it disappears!

Here is a screenshot of a recent answer:

> [image: Screenshot]

I got many upvote/downvote changes for that answer and it's OK if I have -1 or -2, but it's not when I have -3.

Here is the same answer with -1:

> [image: Screenshot]

I will add an answer to this question with a snippet and please downvote it to see if we are able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is by design. Snippets are no longer executable if the post score is below a certain threshold. It’s the same threshold where a post becomes “transparent”. On the main site it’s -3, on Meta it’s lower.

Answer (score -9):

This is a test snippet to reproduce the issue, we need to have <strike>3 downvotes for it</strike> for the meta site it should be 8 apparently:

```css
div {
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
some content
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to still be working here with 3 downvotes. (Maybe meta requires more downvotes)

Comment: can't reproduce? I see the run snippet buttons, I think?

Comment: But meta is not the main site, the threshold is likely different or even non-existent.

Comment: @Gimby It does exist. It’s just lower. Watch when this answer becomes transparent (apparently at -8), or see the duplicate target to this question. There’s a link to [an answer in the sandbox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270251/4642212) where this threshold is demonstrated.

Comment: Seems to be around -8 on meta.  So yes, feature and not a bug.

Comment: -8 it is! Temani, your dedication to science has been duly noted and will be rewarded in the afterlife.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Can confirm. I gave 1 upvote to take it from -8 to -7 and button appeared! Thank you for helping us help you help us all (those of us who are still alive ♫♪♬♩).