# Is there a problem with code formatting or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: support

I don't ask many questions on the main site, but lately, I noticed that it is kind of difficult to get my code to look clean and proper, most of the time that happens with HTML or CSS. Normally I just click on the brackets and then copy my code like shown in the screenshot below, but most of the time the formatting just discontinues in the middle of the code like seen in the second screenshot (this is just some example CSS code).

Is this a problem on my side? If so, how can I format the code correctly without having to do every single line by hand?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just paste them normally then block your code afterward and `CTRL+K` or press the following [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pdHF.png)

Comment: Laura, also notice that you can use "fenced" code-blocks (start with three backticks, end with three backticks). For me it's much more convenient. ``` code ```

Comment: Also, if you're using HTML and including enough code to reproduce your issue, consider using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269754/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here?r=SearchResults). It allows people to easily run your code, copy it to their answer, has a dialog for pasting HTML/CSS/JS into and formats it for you, and has a Tidy button to fix indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct formatting is one empty line above, one empty line below, and (at least) 4 spaces prefixing each line of code.

The button will enforce this one lines you select and then press, but not if you press, then paste.