# Is there a place to use Stack Snippets without asking/answering a SO question?

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I love the Stack Snippets code sandbox on Stack Overflow, but if I want to just play around with some code and am not asking/answering a question, I have to click through a few screens to open one up. Is there a way to go straight to a Stack Snippets sandbox without clicking on the Ask or Answer Question buttons?

Comment: Right now, the process involves scrolling down to the "Your Answer" section and pressing the `<>` button. If that's too involved for you, I guess you could make a button that does that for you, at the top of the page, or wherever's most convenient

Answer (score 3):

Stack Snippets are mostly just an embedded version of https://jsfiddle.net; how about just using it directly? There are also many other such online JavaScript sandbox services.

Comment: But, <s>we</s> I'd prefer if people used Stack Snippets so that the code is on Stack Overflow from the start, rather than on some other site that might be blocked for some users... Otherwise I get comments like "I've included a MRE on StackBlitz".

Comment: I don’t think this is about anything that would ever end up on SO at all…‽

Comment: Then is the question even on-topic for Meta?

Comment: Yes, it's about a tool that exists on Stack Overflow. That makes it on-topic for Meta. However, it makes no sense as a feature request. @heretic

Answer (score 2):

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) has a [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) question. Since MSE supports stack snippets too, you can add an answer to that question and play around there without worrying too much.

Comment: There's [a Stack Snippets Sandbox question here on Meta SO as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269754/215552).